# Por que não devemos usar Singleton?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, singleton

Você [encontra na internet a afirmação que Singletons são ruins](http://wiki.c2.com/?SingletonsAreEvil). Isto é verdade? Por quê?

O problema seria generalizado para quaisquer objetos com instância única? Ou para qualquer coisa que tenha estado global?

Se é tão ruim, pra que foi inventado? Ou seja, que problema ele queria resolver?

Quais os problemas que terei se usá-lo?

Existe alternativa viável?

Comment: Onde você viu isso?

Comment: Uma simples busca no Google acha tantas fontes que eu não saberia nem por onde começar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020312/are-singletons-really-that-bad, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/634723/Singletons-Why-Are-They-Bad, http://molecularmusings.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/singleton-is-an-anti-pattern/, http://blog.code-cop.org/2012/01/why-singletons-are-evil.html, http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil, http://accu.org/index.php/journals/337, http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-singleton/

Comment: Hum... não sabia desse ódio todo. Acho um pattern tão bom e útil pois o Spring o implementa o tempo todo. Infelizmente tem gente que não sabe usar o pattern, e depois sai afirmando esse monte de coisa. =/

Comment: Por isso a pergunta está aqui para tentar reverter isto o mais objetivamente possível :)

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1437/101

Comment: Honestamente não achei errada a pergunta estar aqui, mas estranhei o ódio ao Singleton. [=

Comment: Ódio ao singleton é que nem ódio à uma chave de fenda. É só mais uma ferramenta. O mau uso faz coisas odiosas, mas a culpa é do usuário.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

## TD;DL

Muito da polêmica ocorre pela falta de uma contextualização. Não vejo nada que desabone o padrão Sigleton quando usado no contexto correto.

Sim, ele pode causar muito mal, assim como qualquer padrão de projeto aplicado indevidamente sem análise do impacto e dos efeitos colaterais.

## Porque não usar

### Acoplamento

Ao usar um Singleton você está acoplando o código a uma implementação estática e específica. Isso torna o seu código dependente dessa classe e impede, por exemplo, criar *mocks* em testes unitários.

Desse ponto de vista a consequência é basicamente a mesma de fazer diretamente um `new MeuObjetoImportante()`, pois é uma dependência direta da classe.

### Escopo

O padrão Singleton aplicado conforme a definição também elimina o conceito de escopo. Isso significa que se você por alguma razão decidir que para determinados componentes da aplicação você precisa de outra implementação terá que alterar manualmente todas as classes.

### Não garantia de uma instância única

Em certos casos o padrão pode levar à falsa segurança de que *existirá apenas uma instância*.

Vamos supor que você projete um sistema web e quer dar acesso a um arquivo ou recurso exclusivo. Um Singleton parece uma boa prática, não é? Mas e se amanhã você fizer o *deploy* da aplicação em um *cluster* com N servidores.

No caso de Java isso também é bem complicado, pois não existe isso de *uma classe por JVM*. O conceito correto é *uma classe por `ClassLoader`*, de forma que num mesmo servidor JEE duas aplicações diferentes podem ter, cada uma, sua própria versão de uma mesma classe. As variáveis estáticas não são compartilhadas entre essas versões da mesma classe, portanto o escopo do Singleton em Java é por `ClassLoader` e não por programa.

## Porque usar

Em algumas situações você sabe que vai ter só uma instância da classe.

Em uma aplicação Desktop, por exemplo, não há porque ter "frescuras" adicionais para obter uma conexão com o banco de dados.

Também não vejo problemas em um objeto encapsulando alguns atributos de configuração globais.

Simplesmente não valeria o esforço de implementar algum mecanismo muito elaborado para algo tão simples.

## Como usar

Quando pensamos em Singleton, logo a implementação clássica do *Gang of Four* nos vêm à mente. Os tópicos anteriores desta resposta consideraram isso.

Porém, com a ascensão do uso de frameworks de Inversão de Controle (IoC) e Injeção de Dependência (DI), existe hoje uma forma muito mais "segura" e flexível de implementar o padrão: **deixe o framework cuidar disso para você!**

## Como evitar o Singleton

Apesar de implementações mais simples poderem usar o padrão Singleton da forma "clássica" sem problemas, em geral seria melhor aplicar a Inversão de Controle simplesmente deixar a instância de suas dependências serem injetadas.

Dessa forma, caso amanhã os requisitos mudem e você preciso injetar diferentes instâncias, ou mesmo queira criar *mocks* de teste, basta configurar seu *container* ou *framework* para tal, sem alterar as implementações existentes.

Answer (score 25):

### Singletons são mentirosos compulsivos

Bom, você acaba de de se juntar a um novo projeto, que já possui um código-base maduro e bem extenso. Seu novo chefe lhe pede para implementar uma nova funcionalidade e, como um bom desenvolvedor, você começa escrevendo um teste. Mas como você é novo no projeto, faz um monte de testes exploratórios do tipo “o que acontece se eu executar este método?”. Você começa escrevendo o seguinte código:

```php
    public function testCreditCardCharge() {

        $cc = new CreditCard( '1234 5678 9012 3456', 5, 2013 );
        
        $cc -> charge( 100 );
    }
```

Este código:

- Só funciona quando você o roda como parte do sistema todo, nunca em isolamento
- Quando tentamos rodar em isolamento, uma exceção é lançada
- Quando você recebe sua fatura do cartão, você percebe que teve que pagar R$ 100,00 para cada execução do teste (TENSO!)

Agora eu quero focar no último item. Como que um simples teste causou uma cobrança real no meu cartão de crédito? Carregar um cartão de crédito não é fácil. O teste precisa falar com um *web-service* do cartão de crédito (de terceiros), precisa saber a URL para o *web-service*, precisa se autenticar, passar as credenciais e identificar em qual estabelecimento comercial eu estou comprando...

Nenhuma dessas informações estava presente no teste. Pior ainda, como eu nem sei onde esta informação se encontra, como eu “enganaria” as dependências externas (através de um Mock Object) para que eu não perca R$ 100,00 toda vez que o teste for executado? Como você é novo no projeto, como você poderia saber que o que o teste executado te deixaria R$ 100,00 mais pobre? Isso parece ser história de fantasma.

Mas por que eu vejo uma exceção ocorrendo quando rodo o programa em isolamento, mas tudo funciona quando testo a classe em conjunto com o sistema? E como eu conserto isso? Cansado de procurar pelas milhares de linhas de código, você decide ir perguntar aos desenvolvedores que estão há mais tempo no projeto. Depois de muito cavar, você aprende que precisa inicializar o *CreditCardProcessor*.

```php
    public function testCreditCardCharge() {

        CreditCardProcessor::init();

        $cc = new CreditCard( '1234 5678 9012 3456', 5, 2013 );
        
        $cc -> charge( 100 );
    }
```

Você roda o teste de novo, ainda sem sucesso e você ainda se depara com um outro tipo de exceção. Novamente, você vai consultar seus colegas. Alguém lhe diz que *CreditCardProcessor* precisa de uma *OfflineQueue* para funcionar.

```php
    public function testCreditCardCharge() {

        OfflineQueue::init();

        CreditCardProcessor::init();

        $cc = new CreditCard( '1234 5678 9012 3456', 5, 2013 );
        
        $cc -> charge( 100 );
    }
```

Animado, você roda o teste de novo. Mais uma outra exceção diferente. Mais um pouco de “escavação” e você descobre que também precisa inicializar a conexão com o banco de dados.

```php
    public function testCreditCardCharge() {

        Database::init();

        OfflineQueue::init();

        CreditCardProcessor::init();

        $cc = new CreditCard( '1234 5678 9012 3456', 5, 2013 );
        
        $cc -> charge( 100 );
    }
```

Finalmente o teste é executado no modo de isolamento, mas novamente, você acabou de perder mais R$ 100,00.

O problema é que as APIs existentes são mentirosas compulsivas. *CreditCard* finge que você pode somente instanciá-lo e chamar o método *CreditCard::charge()*, mas, secretamente, ela colabora com *CreditCardProcessor*.

A API de *CreditCardProcessor* diz que ela pode ser inicializada em isolamento, mas, na verdade, ela precisa de *OfflineQueue*, que, por sua vez, precisa de *Database*.

Para os desenvolvedores que escreveram o código, é óbvio que *CreditCard* precisa de *CreditCardProcessor*, afinal, eles que escreveram o código. Mas para qualquer um novo no projeto, isso é um mistério total e dificulta a curva de aprendizado.

Mas ainda não acabou! Suponha que um colega que entrou junto com você no projeto resolve dar uma olhada na sua implementação. Pelo que ele pode dizer, as três inicializações e a instanciação são independentes, ou seja, podem acontecer em qualquer ondem. Durante alguma refatoração ou limpeza de código, talvez ele rearrange as linhas de código dessa maneira:

```php
    public function testCreditCardCharge() {

        CreditCardProcessor::init();

        OfflineQueue::init();

        $cc = new CreditCard( '1234 5678 9012 3456', 5, 2013 );
        
        $cc -> charge( 100 );

        Database::init();
    }
```

O código simplesmente parou de funcionar, mas meu colega não teria como saber, ou teria?

Neste exemplo simples, até que não é difícil enxergar isso, mas num projeto real, a inicialização normalmente pode ocorre por várias classes e você deve inicializar centenas de objetos. A ordem exata de inicialização se tornará um mistério.

Como corrigimos isso? Com APIs que declaram dependência!

```php
    public  function testCreditCardCharge() {
        
        $db = new Database;

        $queue = new OfflineQueue( $db );

        $processor = new CreditCardProcessor( $queue );

        $cc =  new CreditCard( "1234 5678 9012 3456", 5, 2008 );

        $cc -> charge( $processor, 100 );
    }
```

Uma vez que o método de *CreditCard* declara que ele precisa de um *CreditCardProcessor* que não preciso perguntar a ninguém sobre isso. O código simplesmente não vai executar sem ele.

Eu tenho uma dica bem clara de que eu preciso instanciar *CreditCardProcessor*. Quando eu tento instanciar *CreditCardProcessor* eu me deparo com necessidade de fornecer uma *OfflineQueue*.

Em continuidade, quando eu tentar instanciar a *OfflineQueue*, eu vou precisar de um *Database* para trabalhar.

A ordem de instanciamento é clara! Não só é clara como é impossível de inverter a odem das declarações senão o código não executa.

Eo melhor dos benefícios, claro, é que a cada vez que você rodar o teste não terá $100 cobrados no seu cartão.

Singletons nada mais são do que estados globais. Estado global permite que seus objetos mantenham secretamente coisas que não foram declaradas nas suas APIs e, como resultado, Singletons fazem de suas APIs mentirosos patológicos.

Pense de outra forma. Você pode viver numa sociedade onde todo mundo (todas as classes) declaram quem são seus amigos (colaboradores). Se eu sei que o José conhece a Maria mas que nem a Maria e nem o José conhecem o João, então é seguro eu assumir que se eu disser algo pro José ele até pode comentar com a Maria, mas sob nenhuma circunstância o João ficará sabendo nada.

Agora imagine que todo mundo (todas as classes) declaram alguns de seus amigos (colaboradores), mas outros amigos (colaboradores que são Singletons) são mantidos em sigilo. Agora você fica se perguntando como que o João ficou sabendo daquela informação que você deu ao José.

E aqui a parte interessante. Se você é a pessoa quem originalmente construiu os relacionamentos (código), você sabe as verdadeiras dependências, mas quaisquer outros que venham depois de você ficam perplexos uma vez que os amigos os quais você declarou não são os únicos amigos dos objetos, e as informações fluem por caminhos secretos que não são claros pra você. Você vive numa sociedade de mentirosos.

Artigo Original: [Singleton are Pathological Liars](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)

Tradução Parcial: [Henrique Barcelos](http://henriquebarcelos.in/blog/2012/02/23/singletons-sao-mentirosos-compulsivos/)

Comment: Resumindo, você está dizendo que é verdade que os Singletons são sempre ruins? Não há nenhum tipo de uso adequado deles?

Comment: Muito interessante o artigo. A ideia principal é: ***Singleton é ruim porque ele fica escondido nas classes que usam***. Mas, como eu já mencionei em minha resposta, um simples `new` causa o mesmo efeito. Por outro lado, o encapsulamento é um dos grandes trunfos da OO. O que fazer? Acho que questão toda está na escolha do "arquiteto" do que ou não ocultar do "usuário" em sua API e não no padrão em si. Tudo isso tirando a questão de criar uma documentação adequada.

Comment: @utluiz; Não sei quanto as outras linguagens mas o `new`do PHP cria uma nova instância do objeto e, a menos que as informações deste não sejam definidas em propriedades estáticas, elas serão diferentes entre suas instâncias.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Singleton é bom para perpetuação de instâncias de objetos e, por isso, é a base de um [Registry](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html). É bom também para situações em que realmente só deve haver uma única ocorrência de determinado recurso ou cenário, como por exemplo, Sessões. A "Singletonite", doença causada pelo uso excessivo do Singleton foi quem deu má fama ao padrão pois ele passou a ser usado indiscriminadamente substituindo as variáveis globais ou a globalização de escopo.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Sim, sim. Não deve mudar o conceito de instanciação de objetos. O problema é que um `new` também pode esconder um objeto criado e possíveis valores inicializados. Embora não seja a mesma instância, também está dependendo de algo não declarado. Um exemplo inventado agora: `new Configuracao("/minha/configuracao.conf").getValorConfigurado()`. Isso espalhado em várias classes é equivalente (embora  pior) a um Singleton: `Configuracao.getInstance().getValorConfigurado()`.

Comment: Acho que ainda não entendi seu ponto de vista, talvez pelo exemplo de configuração (que eu acho que não deve permitir reescrita en *runtime*), mas também por diferenças entre as linguagens. Com PHP eu consigo imaginar um cenário próximo do qual você se refere se um objeto "normal" usar vários Singletons, seja no seu construtor ou em algum método invocado.

Comment: A resposta é muito boa e a questão sobre a ordem de execução foi muito bem colocada. Mas, não há um problema conceitual logo de início no exemplo usado? Não me parece fazer sentido ter o *comportamento* (isto é, o método) `charge` na classe do cartão. Esse é um comportamento de outra entidade (talvez banco, que me parece ser o que você chama de *processor*...), e isso é observado pelas próprias dependências. Por isso, mantê-lo na classe cartão *também* induz às confusões mencionadas. Ou seja, seria naturalmente mais intuitivo algo como `banco->charge(cartão, valor)`...

Comment: Assim, ficaria bastante claro pela instanciação de `banco` se você ia ter 100 reais debitados realmente ou não. :)

Comment: Seja você quem foi, obrigado pela negativação sobre um artigo que sequer fui eu quem escreveu <_<

Comment: Percebi que não foi você quem escreveu mas, como você sabe, o que você publica como resposta está sujeito a votos positivos e negativos. Eu votei negativo porque a pergunta é sobre singleton e o artigo fala sobre outra coisa: ele fala sobre alto acoplamento e dependências ocultas, o qual você pode obter mesmo sem singletons e do qual você pode escapar mesmo usando singletons. Não deixei comentário inicialmente porque isso já foi demonstrado pelo @utluiz e pelo LuizVieira.

Answer (score 4):

Em linhas gerais, o padrão Singleton é geralmente não recomendado porque se é usado de maneira **errada**.

Muitos devs acabando usando singletons em classes que são usadas em *vários lugares e/ou muitas vezes*, porque, ao invés de ficar jogando esse objeto pra lá e pra cá, através de construtores e/ou métodos, preferem criar um singleton e chamar ele sempre que precisar. Fazer isso deixa o código mais limpo e facilita a implementação, mas está errado.

Isso vai contra a motivação do padrão, além de alocar memória de forma desnecessária. A motivação do singleton é clara: **fornecer um ponto de acesso global e uma única instância à uma classe**.

As pessoas acabam interpretando isso como: como eu vou usar essa classe muito então eu vou criar um ponto de acesso global. Mas, nesse caso, não é uma **necessidade** ter esse ponto de acesso global, e sim uma **comodidade**. Os devs tem que deixar de serem preguiçosos e passar a instância através dos construtores e métodos, sim.