# Quais problemas um estado global pode acarretar?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação, variáveis-globais

Quais problemas um programa poderá enfrentar com o uso de estados globais?

Onde ele pode ser aceitável? Ou seja, como saber se estou abusando do recurso?

Que alternativas existem para evitar isto?

Eu já passei perto do assunto na pergunta [Por que não devemos usar Singleton?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/101) e de certa forma motivou esta nova pergunta.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Por que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/925/por-que-usar-vari%c3%a1veis-globais-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-uma-boa-pr%c3%a1tica)

Comment: Não é duplicata. Estado global e variáveis globais no JavaScript são coisas diferentes. O problema é muito mais complexo do que o abordado na outra pergunta de forma específica. As respostas aqui se fossem dadas lá não fariam muito sentido e as respostas de lá postadas aqui explicariam parte do problema e de uma forma que não cabe aqui. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/lidando-com-perguntas-duplicadas/609#609

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## TL;DR

O problema com um estado global é que na maioria das vezes você descobre que ele não deveria ser tão global assim.

> Uma variável global é como um beco escuro que você usa como um atalho para chegar a algum lugar mais facilmente, mas nunca se sabe quando será surpreendido por algo inesperado. ;)

## Problemas com variáveis e estados globais

### Usando variáveis para compartilhar dados

Muitos desenvolvedores usam um objeto ou variável global para compartilhar algo entre diferentes componentes de um sistema.

Isso é feito ou por preguiça ou por não conseguirem estruturar adequadamente a relação de dependências entre os componentes de forma que possam limitar mais adequadamente o escopo do que eles querem compartilhar.

Já vi vários casos onde o desenvolvedor decidiu não usar parâmetros, então fez uma lógica assim:

```js
var valorGlobal;
function rotina1() {
    valorGlobal = 1;
    rotina2();
}
function rotina2() {
    alert(valorGlobal);
}
```

O equivalente com o uso de parâmetros é:

```js
function rotina1() {
    rotina2(1);
}
function rotina2(valorLocal) {
    alert(valorLocal);
}
```

Como é possível notar, a chance de ocorrer algum erro por parte do desenvolvedor no primeiro caso é muito maior.

### Código *spaghetti*

Continuando com o exemplo e vários métodos começarem a usar essa variável global, cedo ou tarde o código ficará indecifrável.

Por exemplo:

```js
var valorGlobal;
function rotina1() {
    valorGlobal = 1;
    rotina2();
}
function rotina2() {
    valorGlobal = 2;
    rotina3();
    alert(valorGlobal); //qual o valor aqui?
}
function rotina3() {
    valorGlobal = valorGlobal + 1;
}
```

O abuso de variáveis globais parece causar um efeito similar ao uso indiscriminado de `goto`. Você simplesmente começa a se perder na ordem de execução e no que o código realmente quer fazer.

### Concorrência e desempenho

Pense nos exemplos acima executados em processos paralelos. Seria o *caos na terra*!

Alterações em variáveis globais são problemáticas porque precisam ser sincronizadas. Mas **sincronização custa caro** e pode gerar gargalos num sistema *multithreading*.

Quanto mais o escopo dos estados for limitado, de preferência a um único objeto, mais eficiente será o código.

### Escopo, escopo, escopo

No início de um projeto, quando ainda há poucas classes, código, funcionalidades e, consequentemente, pouca confusão, encapsular dados parece desnecessário. Logo, estados globais são extremamente tentadores por serem mais simples de implementar.

Contudo, no decorrer do projeto, o que geralmente se descobre é que será necessário repetir muito código porque o que já está feito ficou "amarrado" com variáveis globais e novas funcionalidades exigem novas variáveis globais.

Em resumo, descobre-se que o que a princípio parecia ser útil a todo o sistema, na verdade não é. O escopo precisa ser limitado, mas o uso de variáveis globais não permite isso.

Isso está muito perto do que foi [discutido sobre o Singleton](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18863/227). Por exemplo, se temos uma rotina que grava relatórios em uma pasta cuja configuração é global e agora é necessário salvar apenas um dos relatório em outra pasta, teremos alterar a rotina existente ou duplicá-la.

## Quando variáveis globais são úteis e necessárias

Existem casos onde realmente é necessário usar variáveis globais.

O caso mais evidente que consigo pensar é para o desenvolvimento de *frameworks* ou bibliotecas.

Frameworks normalmente quebram várias regras da Orientação a Objetos (*à la Matrix*), tais como alterar atributos privados de objetos e manter muitos estados globais.

Um framework de Injeção de Dependências, por exemplo, *deve* manter um mapa global com as dependências que ele gerencia. A diferença é que esse mecanismo será extremamente bem pensado e testado.

## Conclusão

O uso de estados globais deve ser evitado a todo custo no desenvolvimento considerado "normal", isto é, que tem relação com as funções ordinárias de um sistema.

Entretanto, para funcionalidades não-funcionais, frameworks e bibliotecas, que implementam casos bem específicos de uso, geralmente tem escopo bem definido e são desenvolvidos por pessoas mais experientes, o uso de estados globais é aceitável e às vezes até necessário.

Answer (score 11):

Complementando a resposta do utluiz. Não estou dizendo grandes novidades, apenas uma forma diferente do que já foi dito na outra resposta e adicionando alguma coisa.

## Confusão de *design*

Estado global só pode mudar o seu estado destruindo o estado anterior. Não é possível criar um novo estado. Com instâncias você pode, se desejar, criar novos estados para algo relacionado. Você **quase** nunca sabe quando vai precisar de estados diferentes ao mesmo tempo.

Uma mudança no *design* de uma parte da aplicação pode exigir uma mudança no estado global que pode gerar necessidade de mudança em outras ou até todas partes da aplicação.

E a mudança de estado dificulta o entendimento necessário para fazer as mudanças.

Note que muitos estados podem mudar de forma imprevisível. O estado global só é um pouco pior porque a fonte da mudança pode vir de fontes mais distantes.

Tornar o estado mais local obviamente não resolve todos os problemas de *design*.

## Testes

Apenas dificulta os testes. Alguns dizem que é difícil testar usando estado global porque não dá para mudar a forma de acessar uma informação. Isto não é verdade. É **possível** substituir o estado global (*singleton* ou não) com uma forma testável. O problema parece ser outro e talvez pior.

É claro que o fato do estado global poder eventualmente ter seu estado modificado de forma imprevisível na aplicação rodando em produção pode tornar inúteis os testes em ambiente controlado. Mas este é um problema por si só. Ele não afeta só o teste. Mudanças de estado vindos de qualquer lugar, imprevisíveis, causam *bugs* cujos testes não podem pegar. Fica difícil rastrear um erro até mesmo *debugando* em produção, imagine em um ambiente controlado que fatalmente não reproduzirá o mesmo fluxo.

## Dificuldade para uso

Estado global torna a API um pouco mágica. Você precisa saber de coisas não relacionadas diretamente.

Impede a criação de funções puras quando isto é desejável. Funções puras não podem se valer de estados externos a ela mesma.

Se você prefere ter instâncias, é **possível** eliminar a concorrência. Além do custo de processamento de bloqueio, erros causados por concorrência são bem, bem, bem mais difíceis de achar.

## Há estado inerentemente global

Mas há situações cujo estado é inerentemente global. Você consegue imaginar ter instâncias que guardam a *string* de `PATH` do sistema operacional? Ou o horário do sistema? Isto vale para qualquer configuração que só pode existir um e somente um. Para informações que são universais, que a semântica manda que só tenha um. Para informações que se tornariam inúteis se um dia viesse existir estados diferentes.

Algumas pessoas dirão que é melhor, mesmo nesses casos ter instâncias para facilitar o teste. Eu acho que apenas facilitar é pouco para justificar a criação de instância onde o estado deve ser global. Ser mais difícil não significa que é inviável. E é claro que algumas linguagens menos dogmáticas facilitam mais que outras.

Há de se tomar o cuidado de não começar com uma configuração global do sistema e um dia perceber que aquilo deveria ser uma configuração por usuário. Mas é provável que você tem um problema de *design* mais grave que o problema de ser global ou não. Mesmo que tivesse este estado em uma instância provavelmente sua aplicação não estará preparada para entender o deslocamento da configuração para um outro nível.

Não pode abusar de um recurso, mas se realmente há um benefício, se você tem experiência e certeza de que ele não vai causar problemas futuros, não há solução melhor, use o estado global. É como o [goto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101), não deve usar até que ele seja útil.

## Como evitar problemas com estado global

- Use parâmetros da função.
- Faça [injeção de dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101). Ela nada mais é que a parametrização do objeto ao invés da função.
- Prefira estado global imutável.
- Prefira um *Singleton*, preferencialmente imutável, com os dados globais.

Este último caso é interessante porque você mantém o estado global resolvendo a **maioria** dos problemas, principalmente se os dados forem imutáveis. Não há problemas de concorrência, dá para testar (sim, dá para *mockar*), o *design* pode ser modificado mais facilmente para aceitar uma instância diferente no lugar do *singleton*, basta fazê-lo de forma mais genérica, mas isto é outro assunto.

Aproveito para mostrar que há abuso no *design* da aplicação por causa do teste e dá para [testar usando um padrão de projeto](http://deliberate-software.com/simplemock-unit-test-mocking/) ao invés criar um problema novo na aplicação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

## Onde é aceitável? Talvez necessário?

Blackboard system ([aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_system)) é essencialmente um sistema formado por vários componentes que compartilham uma base de conhecimento comum, ou o que chamou de estado global. Caso venha a implementar um, então terá que fazer uso de estado global, e isto não significa alguma deficiência do *design* do software em questão.

Muitas vezes, quando se fala em "estado global", ou "variável global" como elementos indesejáveis, estamos nos referindo à complexidade acidental, ou seja, aquela introduzida não pelo domínio em questão, mas pela opção de *design* do projetista.

Um comentário adicional encontra-se em [Por que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/925/por-que-usar-vari%C3%A1veis-globais-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-uma-boa-pr%C3%A1tica/404873#404873).