# Como salvar dados em um array global

Tags: php, array, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando PHP, e até o momento desenvolvi um pequeno sistema que "monta" as views do site e etc.

Mas me deparei com um problema extremamente chato que não consigo resolver. Preciso de uma função para mostrar os erros que ocorrerem no sistema.

O problema é que quando uso o `echo` para mostrar as mensagens, ele mostra a mensagem no meio do template (logo no começo da tag `body`), e não onde as mensagens de erro devem aparecer, que é dentro da tag `main`.

A solução que encontrei para isso, foi criar um array `$errors` e salvar dentro dele as mensagens de erro que eu precisar mostrar. E então eu faço uma função dentro da tag `main` para dar o `echo` nessas mensagens de erro.

O problema é que estou trabalhando com classes para fazer o sistema. E não consigo passar esse array entre as classes do sistema. Por exemplo, estou trabalhando numa função na classe `Database` e quero guardar um erro que aconteceu ali mas a função do `echo` só é mostrada na classe `System`.

Vejam meu código até agora:

> system.php

```
new System;

class System {

    public function __construct() {

        define('config', 'config.php');

        if(file_exists(config)) {
            require_once(config);
        }
        else {
            header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
            echo "<title>Painel de administração - Erro</title>";
            die('Arquivo de configuração não localizado. Contate o administrator do sistema.');
        }

        foreach($required_consts as $value){
            if(!defined($value)) {
                header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
                echo "<title>Painel de administração - Erro</title>";
                die('<strong>Uma configuração do sistema está ausente:</strong> ' . $value);
            }
        }

        require_once('database.php');
        new Database;
        (new Database)->setup();

        require_once('views.php');
        new View($menu, $errors);

    }

    public function error($message) {
        foreach($message as $error) {
            echo "<p class='alert alert-danger'>$error</p>";
        }
    }

    public function success($message) {
        foreach($message as $success) {
            return "<p class='alert alert-success'>$success</p>";
        }
    }

}
```

> database.php

```
<?php

class Database extends System {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli(host, db_user, db_pass) or die ('Não foi possível conectar ao MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
    }

    public function setup() {
        $this->createDatabase();
    }

    public function createDatabase() {
//      $this->mysqli->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " . db_name );
        $this->mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . db_name );

        if($this->mysqli->error) {
            return $this->mysqli->error;
        }
        else {
            echo "Banco de dados criado com sucesso.<br>";
            $this->createTables();
        }
    }

    public function createTables() {
        $this->database = new mysqli(host, db_user, db_pass, db_name) or die ('Não foi possível conectar ao Banco de Dados: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
        $database = db_name;
        $table = users_table;
        $this->database->query("
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users 
            (
                id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
                pass CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                active CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
                admin CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
                register_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id),
                UNIQUE(email)
            )
            CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
        ");

        if($this->mysqli->error) {
            echo $this->mysqli->error;
        }
        else {
            //echo "Tabelas criadas com sucesso.";
            $this->success(['Tabelas criadas com sucesso.']);
            $errors[] = 'Tabelas criadas com sucesso.';
            $this->registerAdmin();
        }
    }

    public function registerAdmin() {

        $query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = 1 AND name IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1";
        $result = $this->database->query($query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if(!$row) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO users(name, email, pass, active, admin) VALUES ('Admin', 'example@example.com', md5('adminteste'), 1, 1)";
            $this->database->query($query);
        }
    }


}
```

Tudo funciona perfeito até essa parte de mostrar os erros. Estou fazendo os testes para a função no `else` do arquivo `database.php`.

```
    else {
        //echo "Tabelas criadas com sucesso.";
        $this->success(['Tabelas criadas com sucesso.']);
        $errors[] = 'Tabelas criadas com sucesso.';
        $this->registerAdmin();
    }
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma 'luz'? Ainda sou novo no conceito de `POO`.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil então criar uma função (ou exagerando, uma classe separada) para guardar os erros? E além disso, você pode usar o log de erro do próprio PHP com as suas mensagens personalizadas, em vez de fazer um sistema novo. Clique aqui: [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-log.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que você deseja é feito com [`global`](https://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), então teria que fazer algo assim:

```
global $errors[] = 'Tabelas criadas com sucesso.';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Global.php).

Mas isto é um ideia terrível.

No mínimo poderia criar um classe [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) para armazenar estes dados e pegá-los através desta classe. Ainda assim não é a melhor solução.

Na verdade todo o sistema que você bolou me parece uma ideia ruim de como lidar com o problema. Incluir uma classe dentro da outra, por exemplo, não me parece uma boa ideia. Acho que você não está conseguindo fazer o que precisa e está criando um código mirabolante. Não se apegue a este *design* que ele te trará problemas. Se vai criar um sistema de gerenciamento de erros próprio, tem que pensá-lo muito bem, tem que ser algo limpo.

Tem sintaxe usada que me parece bem esquisita também.

De qualquer a resposta objetiva foi dada e uma alternativa mais viável também. O Bacco deu outra opção no comentário da pergunta.

Comment: Então, como falei. Estou apenas estudando, testando, vendo possibilidades, não entendo muito o funcionamento, nesse começo como no começo de qualquer um vou de embalo no que vejo no código dos outros. Mas agradeço pelas informações, e vou estudar o que me recomendou também.

Comment: Por isto que eu dei informações adicionais. Isso por exemplo é muito estranho pra mim: `new Database;
        (new Database)->setup();` Sugestão de leitura: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101

Comment: Ah não, isso é apenas para testes, não vai ficar no código final. Eu precisava verificar se as funções de setup estavam funcionando corretamente, enquanto não termino a parte responsável por checar se o sistema já está instalado ou não.