# Como declarar uma variável array como global no PHP de forma segura?

Tags: php, funções, variáveis

Na função abaixo recebo uma mensagem de que a forma usada não é segura... e mesmo ignorando não estou conseguindo coletar o conteúdo da variável `$a` após a função

```
$a = array();

function teste1(){
  global $a;
  $a[] = "Ola";
  $a[] = "Passei";
  $a[] = "Por";
  $a[] = "Aqui"; 
}

function teste2(){
  global $a;
  $a[] = "Também";
  $a[] = "Passei";
  $a[] = "Por";
  $a[] = "Aqui"; 
}

var_dump($a); // Aqui esta vindo vazia
```

Esse é um exemplo básico, no mundo real a função envolve varias camadas que por hora seria inviável retornar `$a` como return da função teste.

Eu preciso fazer um log e preciso preencher o array com varias strings ao longo do processo e no final gravar um arquivo texto, mas nesse momento meu problema e declarar uma variável que pode ser usada fora da função, porque ela passar por varias funções.

Comment: A sua pergunta abre um leque de soluções, não adianta a gente responder o que está ai, tudo é suposição, talvez o que você também pretende fazer não seja a melhor solução, acessar uma variável global nem sempre é um bom caminho, tudo depende, tudo depende também de contexto, momento, local e forma. O grande mau dessas perguntas é que elas não retratam o problema real seu e sim sempre suposições e isso vai de contra mão ao site.

Comment: Entendi... mas veja só, tenho uma sistema complexo ja antigo que não posso simplesmente reescreve-lo... por hora eu precisaria de uma variável array global para fazer um debug

Comment: Você agora editou e colocou mais informações, de cara sem ter um estudo lógico passe a variável `$a` por referencia ou retorne no final sobrendo os valores antigos.

Comment: Marcelo você colocando uma variável no inicio do `script` você tem acesso até o fim, então cara depende de como esse sistema está feito é um pagina com tudo, eu realmente pedi mais esclarecimentos na sua pergunta porque não é assim que deve ser feito.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve comunicar os dados com a função. Funções recebem e retornam valores.

Esse código não tem sentido, mas vou mostrar o que faria se ele fizesse:

```
function teste($a) {
    $a[] = "Ola";
    $a[] = "Passei";
    $a[] = "Por";
    $a[] = "Aqui";
    return $a;
}

function teste2($a) {
    $a[] = "Também";
    $a[] = "Passei";
    $a[] = "Por";
    $a[] = "Aqui"; 
    return $a;
}
$a = Array();
$a = teste($a);
$a = teste2($a);
var_dump($a);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nj5kRV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/NoGlobalphp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/NoGlobal.php).

Então eu crio uma variável fora, ela não é global, passo como argumento para a função, modifico seu valor e retorno esse valor, sempre comunicando sem fazer nada ficar global, tudo respeita o escopo e fica organizado.

Note que fica do mesmo tamanho, então nem tem porque fazer do pior jeito, ainda que depois de dar mais contexto o global nem seria tão ruim.

Dá para fazer com referência aí não precisa do retorno, mas isso é mais avançado e não acho interessante fazer no PHP na maioria das situações.

Variáveis possum [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) e é preciso entender isso para conseguir programar de forma correta.

Evite usar variável global sempre que não tiver uma necessidade muito forte e some use se entender muito bem todas as consequências, considere-se proibido de usar sem entender profundamente os problemas que podem ocorrer com seu uso:

- [Como usar variáveis estáticas e globais em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49521/101)
- [Variável global personalizada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102652/101)
- [Como salvar dados em um array global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44953/101)
- [Em PHP todas variáveis declaradas são globais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173543/101)

Comment: Entendi seu exemplo, mas minha necessidade é outra... não posso simplesmente pegar o return da função porque a variável $a será usada dentro de varias funções para coletar dados a serem analisado no final de todo o processo, vou editar a pergunta pra ficar mais claro

Comment: Sua pergunta não fala de outra necessidade, eu só posso responder pelo que foi perguntado. E na verdade quase nunca existe essa necessidade que está dizendo agora, que também não está clara. Com a edição o exemplo faz menos sentido ainda. Mas ainda vale o que eu falei, a única coisa que muda é que passa valor também.

Comment: Achei que eu poderia criar uma variavel global somente para fazer um debug em um script antigo que tenho e depois descarta-la... é mais uma necessidade em tempo de desenvolvimento, não irá para a produção por isso não estou colocando a questão segurança, mas valeu os esclarecimentos

Comment: Se ler os *links* verá que pode, mas depende do que quer fazer.

Comment: Sim li e tentei alguns exemplos, mas a variável continuava em branco, lendo o manual do php mais a fundo vi que a opção foi retirada nas ultimas versões https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.globals.php, vou partir pra outras alternativas

Comment: @Marcelo A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: Honestamente pelo que percebi nas respostas esperava que alguém chegasse e dissesse, isso que você esta querendo não é possível eu iria aceitar tranquilo... mas acho que não fui claro na questão e não sei como colocar para ser mais claro sem causar um problema para a lista acabei fazendo de outra forma como eu disse era só um quebra galho pra fazer um debug  num código antigo, como eu deveria encerrar essa questão?

Comment: Ok, a resposta é esta, você não quer ela, mas é possível fazer e é assim, demonstrei com toda clareza, executando e nem é um código maior. Fica para instruir outras pessoas.