# Como usar variáveis estáticas e globais em PHP?

Tags: php, classes, variáveis, variáveis-globais

Preciso do valor de uma variável em várias funções para poder incrementar e decrementar o valor da variável.

Já tentei usar variável estática iniciada com valor nulo, mas mesmo alterando seu valor, ela fica com valor nulo.

Como faço pra manipulá-la?

Comment: Precisa de mais informações porque dependendo da situação há soluções diferentes. Se, por exemplo, estiver implementando um sistema legado com códigos antigos, fica difícil reescrever tudo, além disso sai mais caro ao cliente.. Nesses casos, usa-se o modo mais prático e grosseiro com o uso de "global", apesar de ser recomendado não utilizar, ainda é útil para esse tipo de situação. Acho todas as respostas abaixo válidas pois o contexto da questão carece de maiores detalhes.

Comment: Especialmente em códigos legados não deve-se usar `global`. Você pode quebrar todo o código fazendo isto. `global`nunca deve ser usado, mas se for ele deve ser muito bem pensado, o seu uso deve ter um controle enorme. É tão complicado controlar isto eficazmente que é mais fácil usar outras soluções. Talvez o mair problema do `global` é que as pessoas acham que é fácil usar ele.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como usar variável global? **Simples, não use.**

Variáveis globais são problemáticas. É difícil garantir que ela não vai se confundir com outras variáveis. É difícil entender quem e quando ela está sendo alterada.

## Variável estática

Basta declarar a variável como estática (`static`). Desta forma ela terá vida por toda a aplicação. Se ela está dentro de uma função sua visibilidade será apenas dentro da função e isto é importante. Mas não impede que ela tenha vida durante toda a execução.

Quando a variável é declarada `static` ela é armazena em uma região diferente da memória que não é [perdida quando a função termina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) como é o caso das variáveis locais dentro de uma função.

Aqui vai um algoritmo possível para seu contador. Certamente dá para melhorá-lo. É possível inclusive fazer o incremento acontecer dentro da função se é só isto que deseja. Dá para usar a criatividade e fazer de diversas formas diferentes. O importante é que agora sabe que é possível estender a vida da variável por toda vida da aplicação sem expô-la para toda aplicação, o que seria uma bela de uma má prática.

```
function contador($valor) {
    static $contador;
    if (isset($valor)) {
        $contador = $valor;
    }
    return $contador;
}

echo contador(1) . "\n";
$contador = contador(null) + 1;
echo contador($contador);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/LCZEEx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/StaticVariable). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/StaticVariable.php).

Isto é [estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101). O ideal é não usar nem isto. Mas dependendo da aplicação ele não causa problema real.

---

A resposta do Rafael Withoeft também dá uma outra solução possível sem usar globais ou estáticas. A única dificuldade dela é que teria que ficar passando a variável de estado por toda a aplicação para usar em outro lugares. A variável não tem tempo de vida estendido para fora da função onde ela foi criada. Isto pode ser ruim mas também pode ser bom. Em alguns casos - não parece ser o caso do AP - isto pode ser a melhor opção. Esta é uma forma parecida com o uso de um objeto. Só que o objeto tem apenas um membro dentro, o próprio valor.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar referência. Exemplo:

```
<?php
function foo (&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a=5;
foo ($a);
// $a é 6 aqui
?>
```

**Fonte:** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.pass.php

**O que as referências fazem?** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: Não entendi o negativo, será porque não falou em global e estático? Porque a solução resolve o problema do AP de uma outra forma boa.

Comment: Acredito que seja por isso, mas sem conhecer o código que ele implementou só restou colocar a forma que achei mais viável para ele implementar...

Comment: Por outro lado antes de positivar eu estava analisando tudo, eu penso que ela não resolve totalmente o problema. A variável que guarda o valor teria que fica sendo passada para outras partes do programa para manter seu estado. Se analisar cuidadosamente a pergunta, isto é indesejável. Mesmo assim acho que um negativo seria exagero. Mas é o critério de cada um.

Comment: Realmente, dependendo do caso seria mais trabalhoso mas você está certo então vou positivar sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo de uso de variáveis globais !!

```
<?php
    $teste = "Variável 1";
    $teste2 = "teste2";
    function teste(){
        global $teste,$teste2;
        echo $teste; // Retorno será Variável 1
    }

    //Chamando a função
    teste();
    //Alterando valor da variável...
    $teste = "valor alterado...";
    teste();
?>
```

Comment: A resposta não está errada mas isto é uma má prática. Mesmo assim não negativei, raramente negativo respostas, especialmente quando concorrem com resposta minha. E neste caso não digo que a resposta está errada, só não se recomenda fazer isto.

Comment: Não recomenda a fazer? Qual a má prática ?

Comment: Declarar variáveis globais de qualquer forma.

Comment: Ah sim entendi, má pratica de programação. Achei que a resposta estava mal escrita.

Comment: Obrigado a atenção, positivei sua resposta...