# Qual a função de um método estático?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, método, métodos-estáticos

É apenas conveniência? Digo, é desnecessário instanciar um objeto para utilizar uma função que não utiliza os dados do mesmo.

Há diferença na execução? Memória, processamento - recursos em geral?

Comment: Método estático não precisa do objeto para ser acessado, é uma das funções se não me engano...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## Instância X tipos

De uma certa forma podemos dizer que é impossível instanciar um objeto para acessar um método estático. Métodos estáticos nunca operam na instância. Se eles estão em classes estáticas realmente nem faria sentido. Se o método estático estiver em uma classe ou estrutura normal, ele não pode acessar membros de instância (pelo menos de forma privilegiada). Porque: ele acessaria qual instância?

Métodos estáticos só podem acessar estado estático já que eles valem para toda a aplicação só podem acessar dados que também valem para toda aplicação. Estados estáticos existem na classe/estrutura. Claro que as instâncias podem acessá-los referenciado o tipo e não a instância.

Então não é necessário instanciar nada para acessar métodos estáticos. E métodos que não usam dados da instância, em geral, deveriam ser estáticos. Os puristas não gostam disto, eles costumam ter chiliques quando encontram um método estático mesmo quando eles fazem todo sentido. As "regras" que eles inventaram ou copiaram dizem que métodos estáticos são coisa do demônio. Ainda bem que eu não sigo as "regras", eu resolvo problemas. O meu *default* é criar métodos estáticos e só crio método de instância quando isto se mostra útil e necessário (o detalhe é que tem poucos *deafults* no meu código, o que é bom, me faz pensar). Mas entendo que isto não funcione para todos.

Ao contrário do Java, não pode-se chamar o método estático usando a instância. Java permite e em vez de acessar a instância o compilador traduz a chamada para uma chamada à classe. Em C# o programador tem que chamar o método estático através do seu tipo e não há meio de chamar através da instância mesmo que ela fosse ignorada. Curiosamente os [métodos de extensão](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method) permitem dar aparência de fazer isto, mesmo que eles ainda funcionem como métodos estáticos.

O método estático quase pode ser considerado uma distorção para quem conhece outras linguagens. No fundo eles são funções comuns e o AP usou bem o termo.

## Função dos métodos estáticos

Para entender sua função (sem trocadilhos) é bom entender a diferença entre ele e o método de instância.

Um método de instância tem um parâmetro extra que é oculto e esse parâmetro dá acesso ao estado do objeto em questão, então ele sempre está trabalhando com um objeto específico. Essencialmente é isto que difere um método do outro. Claro que o método de instância pode ter polimorfismo e outras características que só fazem sentido com instâncias. Este método pode ter acesso privilegiado aos membros.

Esse parâmetro extra determina que o método deve operar diretamente com o objeto, a instância (nada impede que o método de instância acesse algum membro da classe). Há correntes que dizem que isto é preferido porque fica mais orientado a objeto e o método já fica presente no contrato da API. Eu já prefiro tornar estático tudo que não acessa uma instância. Cada um tem seus méritos.

Em um método estático todos os parâmetros são tratados de forma idêntica, não há privilégios de acesso aos membros de um parâmetro. E obviamente ele não pode ter nenhuma característica relacionada às instâncias, como polimorfismo (tem soluções para isto). Podemos entender o método estático como um método utilitário, como algo que não pertence ao objeto e está ali só para ser encapsulado no tipo.

Costuma-se dar preferência para métodos estáticos que não acessem estado estático já que [estado global pode ser do demônio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101). Ou seja, conceitualmente métodos estáticos tendem ser algoritmos e não acessam nada além dos parâmetros - mesmo que seja possível acessar dados estáticos ou, obviamente, criar instâncias locais de tipos diversos.

## Diferenças de implementação interna

Fora essas pequenas diferenças conceituais não há muita coisa que os diferem internamente. Quando eles viram código nativo mal dá para dizer qual é um e outro. Eles executam igualmente, eles por si só em essência consomem a mesma memória, processamento ou qualquer coisa.

Só lembrando que um método de instância tem um parâmetro a mais do que se vê. Mas não dá para dizer que isto consome alguma coisa relevante a mais. E mesmo consumindo, para fazer exatamente a mesma operação o código precisa de um parâmetro explícito a mais no método estático em comparação ao método de instância.

```
public static void metodo1(Conta conta, int valor) { ... }

public void metodo2(int valor) { ... } //pertence à classe Conta, é de instância

public static void metodo3(int valor) { ... }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/StaticVsInstance.cs).

Esses dois primeiros métodos executam e consomem a mesma coisa. O compilador pode até tratá-los inicialmente de forma diferente mas depois não faz muita diferença. O terceiro não é o mesmo que os dois primeiros independente do seu código.

Dados estáticos tendem a consumir ligeiramente menos memória que dados instanciados, além de ter a alocação em área especial, mas é irrisório. Eles não diferem em sua essência.

## Conclusão

Muitas pessoas não sabem mas é possível fazer tudo com métodos estáticos. Este *site* que você está usando agora é feito com muita coisa estática. Porque a maneira como ele é usado pode trazer simplificações e dar alguma vantagem de performance, mas não porque eles são estáticos. O paradigma de orientação a objeto traz algum custo. Alguns programadores conseguem entender todo o modelo melhor com método estáticos. Isto pode soar estranho para alguns programadores, mas é verdade.

As diferenças na sua implementação e uso são conceituais, ajudam facilitar a codificação mas não diferem no funcionamento interno. Se eles forem usados de forma equivalente, não faz diferença usar um ou outro do ponto de vista de implementação. A escolha deve ser feita pela necessidade semântica e não pela forma como eles funcionam internamente.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 27):

## Qual a função de um método estático?

Executar um método sem precisar instanciar uma classe. Uma classe, grosso modo, é um conjunto de variáveis, propriedades e métodos. Quando os dois primeiros não são necessários num contexto de aplicação (ou seja, quando todos os componentes internos como variáveis e propriedades são privados, ou então quando não é necessário conservar um estado de um objeto, com essas variáveis e propriedades com determinados valores), a classe pode ser estática.

## É apenas conveniência? Digo, é desnecessário instanciar um objeto para utilizar uma função que não utiliza os dados do mesmo?

Não apenas conveniência. Tem certa economia de memória da aplicação também.

## Há diferença na execução? Memória, processamento - recursos em geral?

Sim, o método estático é levemente mais eficiente, mas a diferença é quase imperceptível. [Há mais detalhes nesta ótima resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12279898/1314276).

Answer (score 8):

Tem diferença, pois a execução deste método não participa exclusivamente do contexto de quem esta chamando o método e sim de aplicação ou melhor AppDomain. Os métodos estáticos são muito uteis para algorítimos que não precisa de recursos compartilhados como propriedades de instancia.