# Erro ao mudar valor da propriedade estática

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho minha classe `DadosConexao`, esta classe é responsável por guardar a *string de conexão* do banco de dados, ela contem as seguintes propriedades:

*Uma propriedade estatística* `StringConexao`.

`isServ` *indica se é servidor ou cliente.*

`servidor` *guarda o nome da maquina*.

O problema é que eu não consigo mudar a propriedade `StringConexao`, que no caso e o `"Data Source="` uma parte da string que seria o nome da maquina que contem o *banco de dados*.

Minha classe **DadosConexao**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class DadosConexao
    {

        private String servidor;
        private Boolean isServ;       

        public DadosConexao(bool isServ, string servidor)
        {
            this.isServ = isServ;
            this.servidor = servidor;
        }

        public static string StringConexao 
        {
            get 
            {
                if (!isServ)//Da erro aqui
                    servidor = Environment.MachineName.ToString();//Caso isServ for true pega o nome da maquina local.

                return "Data Source=" + servidor + 
                       "\\MINHAINSTANCIA;" + 
                       "Initial Catalog=MINHABASE;" + 
                       "Persist Security Info=True;" + 
                       "User ID=sa;" + 
                       "Password=123456";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Erro apresentado pelo Visual Studio:

```
Error 1 An object reference is required 
for the non-static field, method, 
or property 'DAL.DadosConexao.isServ'
```

O sistema funciona como cliente ou servidor, se for cliente a propriedade `servidor` é definida nas configurações pelo usuário.

Comment: já tentou usar `if (isServ == false)` ?

Comment: Sim, ja foi resolvido o problema desta classe, e estou usando `if (isServ)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode resolver isto de duas formas. Uma é tirar `static` da propriedade. [Veja mais sobre o `static`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101).

```
using System;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var con = new DAL.DadosConexao(true, null);
    }
}

namespace DAL {
    public class DadosConexao {

        private string servidor;
        private bool isServ;       

        public DadosConexao(bool isServ, string servidor) {
            this.isServ = isServ;
            this.servidor = servidor;
        }

        public string StringConexao {
            get {
                if (!isServ)
                    servidor = Environment.MachineName.ToString();

                return "Data Source=" + servidor + 
                       "\\MINHAINSTANCIA;" + 
                       "Initial Catalog=MINHABASE;" + 
                       "Persist Security Info=True;" + 
                       "User ID=sa;" + 
                       "Password=123456";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LZWnSk). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gaFgIX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/Proper.cs).

Mas isto vai exigir criar uma instância da classe e ficar passando ela como parâmetro, ou ficar criando uma nova toda vez que precisa, que no caso do cliente que envolve uma lógica adicional para determinar o servidor. Isto não é ideal. Mais ainda. Se vai fazer isto, seria melhor aplicar o [*padrão Singleton*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) nela.

Pra falar a verdade acho que a lógica que determina o que usar se for cliente deveria estar dentro desta classe também e não vir de fora.

A outra solução é transformar tudo em `static` onde precisa *setar* os dados de `isServ` e eventualmente de `servidor` uma vez e pegar o `StringConexao` quantas vezes quiser, como era esperado:

```
using System;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        DAL.DadosConexao.isServ = true;
        var con = DAL.DadosConexao.StringConexao;
    }
}

namespace DAL {
    public static class DadosConexao {
        public static string servidor { get; set; }
        public static bool isServ { get; set; }

        public static string StringConexao {
            get {
                if (!isServ) servidor = Environment.MachineName.ToString();
                return "Data Source=" + servidor + 
                       "\\MINHAINSTANCIA;" + 
                       "Initial Catalog=MINHABASE;" + 
                       "Persist Security Info=True;" + 
                       "User ID=sa;" + 
                       "Password=123456";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/e2Dtz7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o4uskk). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/ProperStatic.cs).

Provavelmente tem como melhorar isto, mas esta é a base.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, a segunda sugestão e ótima.

Comment: Como você determina qual é o servidor quando roda no cliente?

Comment: O servidor vai ser determinado no momento da implementação do sistema, uma flag.

Comment: Sim, mas como é implementado?

Comment: A fase da implementação ainda falta algumas regras de negócio para serem definidas, para eu ver qual vai ser a forma mais viável e mais simples.

Comment: Eu ia te ajudar mais, mas sem saber isto, não tem jeito.

Comment: Dentro do sistema terá um modulo que criara o banco de dados, caso for servido ele ira executar a chamada que cria o banco de dados na maquina que esta sendo instalado, caso contrario, será solicitado o nome da maquina servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando acessar uma propriedade não-estática dentro de uma propriedade estática.

Pelo que consegui entender da sua regra de negócio, essa propriedade não precisa ser estático. Então, você só precisa trocar a assinatura dela de

```
public static string StringConexao { ... }
```

para

```
public string StringConexao { ... }
```

Você só vai precisar de um método/propriedade `static` quando a sua classe não precisa ser instanciada para chama-lo.

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda.