# Por que está dando esse erro de variável static?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método

Por que está dando esse erro de compilação e como posso resolver isso?

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field service

<kbd>[image: Pq dá esse erro?]</kbd>

Comment: Dê uma lida nisto: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/101

Comment: Já que `service` é não estático,você não pode chamar o `service` através de um método estático.

Comment: Opa, corrigi aqui haha. Estou rindo, é que eu escrevi mas com intenção de testar para ver se dava certo mesmo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Porque o [método é estático e a variável sendo usada é de instância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101). Não há relação entre eles. Membros estáticos têm como "dono" a classe. Só existe **um** em toda a aplicação. Membros de instância têm como "dono" a instância corrente, ou seja, cada objeto criado a partir dessa classe é dono de seus membros. Pode ter tantos quantos quiser. Como os donos são diferentes não dá para um membro acessar o membro de outro dono.

A solução é tirar o `static` do método. Pode ser que a solução seja colocar um `static` na variável. Não tenho como saber pelo que tem na pergunta.