# Porque a chamada a um método simples em uma classe dá erro de referência?

Tags: c#, .net, método

Estou começando a estudar C# e estou com o seguinte erro:

> CODE: CS0120
>  DESCRIPTION: An object reference is required for
>   the non-static field, method, or property
>   'Program.SomarNumeroes(int,int)'
>  CODE: CS0120
>  DESCRIPTION:
>   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Program.dizOla()'

```
namespace metodo_e_funcao
{
    class Program
    {
        public int SomarNumeros(int a, int b)
        {
            int resultado = a + b;
            if (resultado > 10)
            {
                return resultado;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public void dizOla()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ola");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int resultado = SomarNumeros(10,11);
            Console.WriteLine(resultado);
            dizOla();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece acessar os métodos de forma direta sem instanciar um objeto é necessário que o método seja estático.

Obviamente métodos estáticos também não podem acessar diretamente membros de instância. O fato do `Main()` ser estático já impediria o acesso de membros de instância dessa classe se fosse feito.

```
using System;

namespace metodo_e_funcao {
    public class Program {
        public static int SomarNumeros(int a, int b) {
            int resultado = a + b;
            if (resultado > 10) {
                return resultado;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public static void dizOla() {
            Console.WriteLine("Ola");
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            int resultado = SomarNumeros(10, 11);
            Console.WriteLine(resultado);
            dizOla();
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YkWbny) de forma mais simplificada. E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rphZGF). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Static.cs).

[Leia mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101).

Comment: Entendi entendi, Obrigado :D deu certo, daqui 6 min aceito a resposta