# Como usar métodos repetidos?

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos, método

Tenho alguns métodos que uso em diversos pontos dos aplicativos e acabo tendo de copiar em cada classe.

Por exemplo:

```
String getStringOrEmpty(EditText editText) {
    String mString = editText.getText().toString();
    mString = (mString.isEmpty() ? "" : mString);
    return mString;
}
```

Apenas para informar: este método retorna uma String com o texto que o EditText, se houver algum, ou uma String vazia.

Eu não queria ter de ficar copiando ele em cada classe que irá usa-lo, mas gostaria de acessar este e outros métodos por todo o projeto.

Isso seria similar a uma biblioteca de funções em outras linguagens. Por exemplo, no php, eu faria um arquivo com uma lista de funções e usaria um comando include para importar a lista para a página.

Como se faz isso em Java (com enfase para Android)?

Comment: Se precisa usar em várias classes, das duas uma, ou ele não pertence a estas classes e sim a outra que tem uma responsabilidade específica, ou é pertence a uma classe mãe que será usada para derivar para as filhas que precisam dela e mas parece ser mais esse última caso, mas não posso afirmar só com o que foi colocado na pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade, de três uma: ... ou você põe ele numa classe Mixin, e usa herança múltipla.

O problema é que a linguagem em questão não suporta herança múltipla  - então tem que forçar o negócio a ser  arrumado de outra forma - possivelmente com uma classe base artificial - de qualquer forma , a pergunta é bem pertinente.

Comment: E..na verdade, além de heranças múltiplas, outra coisa que resoveria bem seria poder ter funções - sem depender de uma "classe estática" artificial.

Espero que o Karma todo das pessoas que escolheram usar Java para o Android traga algum benefício pra suas almas no futuro.

Comment: Entendi os comentários, mas a solução tem que estar dentro dos limites da linguagem. A solução de uma classe `utils` com métodos estáticos me parece a mais indicada para o efeito desejado. Tanto por facilidade como economia de recursos, já que os métodos são instanciados apenas uma vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode criar uma classe com **[métodos estáticos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54021/35406)**. Só pelo nome, já dá pra desconfiar que é algo relacionado com constante, algo 'parado' (estático).

Quando definimos uma classe e criamos vários objetos dela, já sabemos que cada objeto irá ser uma cópia fiel da classe, porém com suas próprias variáveis e métodos em lugares distintos da memória. Ou seja, o objeto 'fusca' tem suas variáveis próprias, diferentes do objeto 'ferrari', embora ambos tenham o mesmo 'modelo', que é a classe 'Carro'.

Quando definimos variáveis com a palavra *static* em uma classe ela terá um comportamento especial: ela será a mesma para todos os objetos daquela classe. Ou seja, não haverá um tipo dela em cada objeto. Todos os objetos, ao acessarem e modificarem essa variável, acessarão a mesma variável, o **mesmo espaço da memória**, e a mudança poderá ser vista em todos os objetos.

Podes criar uma classe chamada `Utils` contendo todos os métodos que queria usar em diversas classes. Veja:

```
public classe Utils{

   public Utils(){
   }

    public static String returnDate(){
        // Aqui o código para retornar data atual
        return date;
    }

    public void String returnHour(){
        // Aqui o código para retornar a hora atual
        return hour;
    }

    public static String getStringOrEmpty1(EditText editText){ 
        String mString = editText.getText().toString();
        mString = (mString.isEmpty() ? "" : mString); 
        return mString; 
    }

    public String getStringOrEmpty2(EditText editText){ 
        String mString = editText.getText().toString();
        mString = (mString.isEmpty() ? "" : mString); 
        return mString; 
    }
}
```

O acesso a esses método é feito desta forma:

**Estático**

```
String date = Utils.returnDate();
String value = Utils.getStringOrEmpty1(editText);
```

**Não estático**

```
String hour = new Utils().returnDate();
String value = new Utils().getStringOrEmpty2(editText);
```

#### Quando usar variáveis static?

Principalmente quando você quiser ter um controle sobre os objetos ou quando todos os objetos devem partilhar uma informação (evitar ter que fazer Composição ou chamar métodos de outros objetos).

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que a melhor maneira de fazer isso é criando um pacote utilitário. Dentro do pacote você cria uma classe que poderá ser importada sempre que necessite e utilize esse método. No caso desse método que está apresentando, poderia ser estático, dessa maneira nem seria necessário instanciar o objeto da classe. Seria algo como:

Cria um pacote de nome util. Ex: `br.com.seuprojeto.util`

Em seguida cria a classe de utilitária. Chame como achar melhor. Aqui chamo de **StringUtil**

```
//imports aqui
public class StringUtil {

    public static String getStringOrEmpty(EditText editText) {
        String mString = editText.getText().toString();
        mString = (mString.isEmpty() ? "" : mString);
        return mString; 
    }

}
```

Para utilizá-la em seu projeto bastaria chamar:

```
//código da classe
String mNome = StringUtil.getStringOrEmpty(mEditText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra opção, além das já citadas/respondidas, é você utilizar uma prática chamada **custom view**.

Basicamente, você cria uma classe que herda do tipo de `View` que você quer modificar e faz suas próprias implementações.

No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public String getStringOrEmpty() {
        String mString = getText().toString();
        mString = (mString.isEmpty() ? "" : mString);
        return mString;
    }
}
```

Para utilizar essa sua **custom view**, você precisa alterar no seu xml (layout):

**Antes:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/seu_id"
    style="@style/AlgumStyle" />
```

**Depois:**

```
<br.com.seupacote.view.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/seu_id"
    style="@style/AlgumStyle" />
```

Agora para acessar o método `getStringOrEmpty()` é bem fácil:

```
public class AlgumaActivity extends Activity {

    private CustomEditText customEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        customEditText = (customEditText) findViewById(R.id.seu_id);
        String algumTexto = customEditText.getStringOrEmpty();
    }

}
```

Essa prática é interessante pois você evita criar métodos e classes estáticas sem necessidade.

Comment: Esta técnica é interessante, sem dúvida. Mas, se duas views diferentes (editText e TextView, por exemplo), tiverem necessidade de um mesmo método, teria de copiar nas duas classes customizadas, correto? Se for, caio de volta no problema que motivou a questão.