# Qual diferença entre Show(), ShowDialog() e Application.Run()?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal, dialog

Li algo sobre modal mas não entendi, alguém poderia explicar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos começar pelo começo, [`Application.Run()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Windows_Forms_Application_Run). Este é o [método estático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101) que começa funcionar todo o sistema de janelas da aplicação. É aqui que [o *framework* toma conta da aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) e começa chamar o seu código conforme é necessário.

É comum passar o primeiro formulário que dev ser aberto. Só o chama sem passar um formulário se o formulário ou formulários foram criados antes.

O [`Show()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.show?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Show) só pode ser usado em um objeto de formulário, e ele fará o formulário ser mostrado. Quando quer que ele não seja mostrado na tela precisa usar o [`Hide()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Windows_Forms_Application_Run), ou o [`Close()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_Close) que fecha o formulário, e obviamente ele não será mais mostrado.

Um formulário normal é um componente cooperativo com a aplicação, você pode clicar em qualquer outro ponto dela, pode continuar tendo interação.

[`ShowDialog()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ShowDialog) é um formulário especial que é aberto e bloqueia a interação do usuário com a aplicação a não ser nele próprio, até que o formulário seja fechado. Só deve ser usado em circunstâncias especiais, onde realmente não pode deixar o usuário fazer outras coisa até ele resolver o que está neste formulário. Ele só pode ser chamado de dentro de um formulário normal.

Note que a aplicação pode continuar rodando normal sem a interação do usuário através de assincronismo ou *threads*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Os loops param quando um formulário é aberto com `ShowDialog()`?

Comment: @Francisco não para, tudo pode continuar funcionando, mas não deixa o usuário agir fora do modal. Só não entenda que o *loop* é um `while` que ficar rodando sem parar. Se fala em *loop* porque ele acaba repetindo as mesmas operações gerais. De uma certa forma se não tem nenhuma interação da tela como um todo pelo usuário ou por outros elementos que influenciam na aplicação o *loop* pode ser considerado parado. Esse *loop* é o que se chama de *event driven*, então ele só funciona quando requerido. Mais que isto só em uma pergunta específica pra não ficar longo aqui.

Comment: Muito bom, algum dia você poderia fazer um thread falando desse event driven...

Comment: Se tiver uma pergunta sobre isto eu respondo.