# Dúvida na declaração de método

Tags: c#

Observem o seguinte código:

```
 class Program
{
    int marks;
    static int maxmarx = 50;
    void CalcularPorcentagem()
    {
        int porcento = (this.marks * 100) / Program.maxmarx;

        Console.WriteLine(porcento);

    }
```

Depois de testar dos dois jeitos a seguir, notei que o programa retorna o mesmo valor quando a classe é instanciada. Portanto, gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre usar:

```
     int porcento = (this.marks * 100) / Program.maxmarx;
```

ou

```
     int porcento = (this.marks * 100) / maxmarx;
```

Comment: Aqui sua resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54012/qual-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-m%C3%A9todo-est%C3%A1tico

Comment: Acredito que para este exemplo não há diferença, mas o primeiro modo te permite diferenciar o atributo de classe de uma variável local, caso haja conflito de nomes no escopo. Por exemplo, se neste método existir a variável local `int maxmarx = 1`, o primeiro modo funcionará perfeitamente, enquanto o segundo produzirá um resultado "inesperado".

Comment: A segunda resposta trata especificamente do assunto abordado nesta pergunta. Se achar que não, me avise.

Comment: Eu escreveria `var porcento = marks * 100 / maxmarx;`, se a variável fosse usada em outro lugar, senão, nem ela existiria.

Comment: Então, Anderson, ela faz menção ao valor declarado na variável local da classe Program. Caso eu precise referenciar o valor 50, determinado na criação da classe, eu utilizo o Program. Entretanto, se eu desejo utilizar um valor diferente de 50, eu devo chamá-la sem o Program., devido ao valor com o qual eu quero trabalhar ser diferente?

Answer (score 1):

Você está dentro da classe `Program` referenciando a variável estática `maxmarx`; ou seja, dentro da classe ele enxerga a variável sem precisar referenciar a classe.

Então tanto `Program.maxmarx` quanto `maxmarx` têm o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 1):

> Portanto, gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre usar

Da forma que está apresentado, dentro de um bloco de código (método) onde não se tem nenhuma outra variável chamada `maxmarx`, nenhuma.

Agora, se tivesse uma variável local chamada `maxmarx`, aí sim, para referenciar a variável estática é obrigatório referenciar utilizando o nome da classe (`Program.maxmarx`).

---

Fora desse cenário (variável local com o mesmo nome), referenciar da forma aprensetada ou não fica a critério do desenvolvedor/time de desenvolvimento.

É a mesma discussão entre referenciar uma varivável de instância com `this` ou não. Por exemplo: `this.marks * 100` ou `marks * 100`? O resultado é o mesmo.

Normalmente, esse "tipo de codagem" é abordada/discutida no inicio do projeto pelo time de desenvolvimento, para que todos desenvolvedores trabalhem da mesma maneira.

Comment: O correto é "não se tem" no lugar de "não tem-se", pois o "não" é classificado como fator de próclise e possui força atrativa sobre o pronome. :x

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss caraca, valeu. Vou arrumar :P