# É errado eu usar um método estático para retonar uma coleção de objetos?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Antes de tudo, sei que não devo sair fazendo classes com vários métodos estáticos mas nesse caso que trago aqui, não entendo por que pode ser considerado má prática.

Digamos que eu tenha uma estrutura MVC, no meu model, eu tenho todos os respectivos métodos do meu CRUD, criar, ler, atualizar e deletar. Porem, eu sempre faço um método estático chamado listar, esse por sua vez, pode retornar uma collection (array mesmo no caso no php) com vários objetos do model especifico e ai, para cada objeto, eu tenho os seus métodos do CRUD. Não vejo problema no listar ser estático, uma vez que ele não vai interagir diretamente com nada mais da minha classe.

Pesquisei bastante sobre o assunto e não achei nada que me fizesse mudar de ideia, por isso, queria trazer essa discussão aqui.

Comment: A não ser que tenha entendido errado... Qual motivo de o método listar retornar vários objetos? Qual aplicação que você faz disso?

Comment: Por exemplo, eu tenho uma Classe Pessoa. Eu posso nela, inserir, ler, atualizar e deletar. Mas e quando eu quero listar  por exemplo, todas as Pessoas que tenho. Apresentar uma lista para o usuário. Nesse caso, eu tenho a prática de usar um método estático, pois não vou interagir diretamente com outros métodos ou atributos da classe Pessoa, mas ainda sim, estou fazendo algo relacionado a Pessoa, logo, Por que não, usar um método estático, esse, instanciando uma pessoa para cada linha que minha query retornar e eu retorno essa lista

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a função de um método estático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54012/qual-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-m%C3%A9todo-est%C3%A1tico)

Comment: Não vi problema nessa abordagem, pode inclusive ser prático. Posso até está enganado, mas o framework Laravel (laravel.com) faz algo parecido para alguns métodos.

Comment: Ao pensarmos que um método estático seria um "método da classe" e que seria executado sem precisar de uma instância dela para se listar objetos, acho que não vejo nenhum problema nessa abordagem. Inclusive faz um certo sentido pra mim analisando pelos conceitos em si. Só surgiu uma dúvida que é relativa a conexão com o Banco de Dados nesse método estático: como é feita esta conexão? Toda programada no método estático? Imagino que sim por ser estático.

Comment: Acredito que não há erro em usar métodos estáticos para isso, porém me parece que sua classe está com mais responsabilidades do que simplesmente um model. Isso é comum quando se usa algum ORM do tipo ActiveRecord como o Eloquent do Laravel. Para fugir desse tipo de abordagem, é comum a implementação do pattern Repository, e desacoplar o modelo da integração com o BD.

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que, seu motivo seja controlar vários cadastros em instancias diferentes, isso faz sentido, que inclusive é aplicado no **Laravel** com o método **Route** , que é usado para receber instancias de outras classes, e pode ter várias responsabilidades, como neste exemplo:

Caminho: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/produtos/1

```
Route::get('produtos/{id}/', function (Request $request, Produtos $produtos) {
   //
});
```

No exemplo o método **Route** chama de forma estática ou método **Get**, manipulando as instancias de **Request** e de **Produtos**, essas classes poderiam possuir diversas outras responsabilidades dentro delas como os proprios **Controllers** do padrão MVC, mas isso se mal aplicado, pode acarretar num problema que é o encapsulamento do seu código, fazendo com que a manutenção fique custosa.

Prosseguindo na resposta ainda usando o Laravel como exemplo, nesse caso ele se encaixa no padrão de projeto **'[Fachada](https://www.devmedia.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-facade-em-java/26476)'**  (Facade), onde uma 'fachada' (a Route) é responsável por toda cadeia de subclasses posteriores.

Referencias:

[Laravel Facades](http://laravel-docs-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/facades/)
[Laravel Routing](http://laravel-docs-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/routing/)

[Padrão Facade](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/facade_pattern.htm)

[Relacionado](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#request-path-and-method):

Answer (score 0):

Hoje o desenvolvimento se baseia em vários padrões de projetos, e alguns desses padrões(ou todos, não sei) utiliza-se injeções de dependência ou seja, injetar uma classe.

Sugiro também implementar `interfaces` em suas aplicações pois ajudam a melhorar o código e juntando tudo fica mais fácil uma possível manutenção depois.

Recomendo você dar uma estudada sobre *design Patterns* vai ajudar você a evoluir muito como desenvolvedor.