# Public Static Void não funciona corretamente - NETBEANS

Tags: java

Escrevi um código retirado de um livro mas entendi que é o primeiro método a ser colocado, porém como não havia no exemplo dado, tentei inseri-lo diversas vezes em pontos diferentes. Como neste exemplo tenho classes privadas e públicas quero saber como deixa-lo rodando:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Pessoa {

    private int idade;
    private String nome;

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
            }
    public void setIdade(int idade)  {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    public int getIdade(){
        return(this.idade);
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return(this.nome);
    }
    public static void ShowInfo(int idade, String nome) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Nome:  "+nome +"\nIdade:"+idade, "\nOK", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Existe um dado que eu deveria arrumar, porque continua dizendo que não possui método principal.

Answer (score 2):

É necessário chamar o seu código dentro do método main, pois é com base nele que a sua aplicação começará a rodar seu programa, exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Pessoa.ShowInfo(22, "João");
}
```

Perceba que como o seu método ShowInfo é estático, não precisamos instanciar a classe pessoa.

Veja esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54012/qual-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-m%C3%A9todo-est%C3%A1tico) detalhando métodos estáticos.

Answer (score 1):

O método principal deve se chamar `main` e ter a seguinte assinatura (isto é, obedecer o seguinte padrão):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Certo mas como ficaria o código completamente?

Answer (score 0):

O método main é por onde sua aplicação irá começar a rodar, o ponto de partida, sem este método sua aplicação não ira saber por onde começar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*Seu código vai aqui, todas as instâncias e chamadas de outros métodos são buscadas apartir do método main*/

}
```

é dentro dele que sua aplicação poderá chamar todas as outras funcionalidades, caso não exista é necessário implantar este método

Answer (score 0):

Ao tentar executar um método, tem que colocar ele dentro de um 'main'. Como você definiu a função como 'static', não é necessário instanciar a classe para utilizá-la:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Pessoa.ShowInfo(46, "Rick"); //assim que deve chamá-la
}
```

Talvez seu problema seja ao tentar executar a CLASSE Pessoa (já tive esse problema ao migrar do Python pra o Java). Nesse caso, tente não executar classes sem 'main' (até porque não vai funcionar).