# Como criar/manter "variavel global" para login

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, login, aplicação-desktop

Estou fazendo uma aplicação desktop em Java. Esta aplicação tem uma tela de login (`JLogin`) e uma com a aplicação principal (`JPrincipal`) e tenho uma classe Login com métodos para consulta ao banco e validação dos dados do login. Meu problema é: preciso manter em algum lugar o usuário *logado* (afim de obter o perfil e controlar o acesso: telas, execuções etc) e poder acessa-lo em diferentes telas. Pensei em algumas maneiras:

- Criar um atributo `static` e `public` no `JLogin` ou Login para guardar o usuário e poder acessa-lo fora da `Jlogin` (que instanciou um objeto `Login` para validação). Vi que é uma péssima pratica "variáveis globais"
- Criar uma classe interna `Sessao` `static` dentro da classe `JLogin` ou Login (dai ainda tenho o problema do acesso "global" pois a classe `Login` será instanciada) de onde consulto o tal usuário.
- Acessar a classe `Login` instanciada na classe `JLogin` na classe `JPrincipal` ou qual quer outra necessária (não sei se é possível)
- A classe `JLogin` eu conseguiria acessar a partir da `JPrincipal` mas a `Login` não... ou teria?

Não sei como é a melhor forma de fazer isso: trabalhar com "sessões" em Java.

Lembrando que é uma aplicação *desktop*.

Comment: Uma sugestão seria o uso do padrão de projeto *singleton*. Ele envolve a criação de um único objeto de uma classe, e esse objeto é acessado de forma estática pelas classes da aplicação.

Comment: Você está usando algum padrão? MVC por exemplo?

Comment: Pode controlar pelo próprio objeto Usuário se ele está logando ou não, setando suas permissões.

Comment: Nossa @mutlei gostei da sua sugestão cara, bastante interessante vou testar e ver se funcionará como o esperado!

Comment: @LeoCBS Não estou usando nenhum padrão mas estou (tentando e estou conseguindo por enquanto) manter a interface separada do resto da aplicação por isso não queria criar nada na JLogin e sim nas classes! Deixar talvez uma classe Sessao gerenciar isso ai ;)

Comment: Pois é @LuisHenrique, eu não sei se consigo acessar a instancia da classe Login criada na JLogin em outras classes como JPrincipal... Se der fica simples: crio uma classeSsessao só com o usuário, perfil e get/set para consulta e deixo a Login só para validação e consulta dos dados do login no banco e seto por ai (Login) a classe Sessao? Q achas?

Comment: Acho que a melhor ideia é criar a classe `Sessao` aplicando o _design pattern singleton_ mesmo, assim você instancia ela na hora em que raliza o login e faz as devidas consultas nas suas classes internas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilizando o *design pattern **singleton***.

> Este padrão garante a existência de apenas uma instância de uma
>   classe, mantendo um ponto global de acesso ao seu objeto.

Pode criar a classe `Sessao`:

```
public class Sessao {
    // Variável estática que conterá a instancia da classe
    private static Sessao instance;

    // Construtor privado (suprime o construtor público padrão).
    private Sessao() {}

    // Método público estático de acesso único ao objeto!
    public static Sessao getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Sessao();
        return instance;
    }

    /*
    Pode criar outros métodos que precise aqui, como getters e setters.
    */
}
```

Então na sua classe `JLogin`, você instancia o objeto Sessão:

```
Sessao sessao = Sessao.getInstance();
// Aqui popula os atributos da sessão que você irá utilizar
```

E posteriormente nas classes internas, quando você instanciar o objeto Sessão irá receber o que foi criado previamente no login.

Comment: Adorei todas as respostas, mas a tua é boa para quem tem preguiça de procurar no google (eu procurei, alias!! (E em livros)). E design patterns são 'lindos'!

Comment: Adorei que já tenham postado, tinha achado isso, [aqui](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/defining-global-variables-in-android/). Também estava com problemas e isso me ajudou. +1

Answer (score 12):

A forma mais fácil você já sabe, que é a sua primeira opção:

*"Criar um atributo static e public no JLogin ou Login para guardar o usuário e poder acessa-lo fora da Jlogin."*

Embora você tenha visto "que é uma péssima pratica usar variáveis globais", acredite, tem muito sistema desenvolvido mais ou menos assim e faturando milhões por ano.

Por outro lado, as pessoas que fizeram este código agora se arrependem disso e vêem nesse tipo de prática (*"forte acoplamento"*) uma restrição para ganhar ainda mais milhões, então elas gastam alguns dos milhões que ganham desenvolvendo uma nova geração dos seus sistemas onde estes problemas não existirão mais, e assim caminha a humanidade.

Já que você veio buscar uma solução que não recaia em erros históricos, aqui está uma linha de raciocínio que vai te ajudar com isso e com todo o resto.

## Pense seu sistema como camadas

Isso não precisa ser tão complexo quanto algumas vezes fazem parecer! Continue lendo.

As camadas do mais simples design seriam as seguintes:

```
    Aplicativo ------> Negócios
        |
        |------------> Banco de dados
```

O diagrama acima demonstra três camadas, sendo que **Aplicativo** depende de **Banco de dados** e aplicativo depende de **Negócios**, que não depende de ninguém.

Estas camadas são conceituais, não físicas. Você não precisa necessariamente de interfaces, nem de mapeamentos objetos/relacional, nem de frameworks de injeção de dependências, nem de MVC, nem de conhecimento avançado de arquitetura de software, nem de blá-blá-blá...

Em primeira instância, você só precisa manter em mente as responsabilidades de cada camada e programar de acordo. Manter esta separação de conceitos vai ajudar mesmo nos aplicativos mais simples.

### Camada Aplicativo

O código nesta camada conhece a mecânica do sistema: a navegação entre as telas, as permissões do usuário (quais telas e botões ele tem acesso), os detalhes de conexão com o banco de dados, etc.

Esta camada sabe o que o sistema faz e como o usuário deve interagir com o sistema; então quando o usuário dá uma ordem (clica num botão, por exemplo), esta camada sabe qual objeto de negócio invocar e quais informações passar para ele fazer o seu trabalho. Mas ela não sabe **como** o objeto de negócio faz o que tem que fazer. Quem sabe disso é a camada de *Negócios*.

### Camada Negócios

A lógica de negócio é implementada pelas classes nesta camada.

Nesta camada pode haver um objeto que, ao alterar informações, registre o usuário que alterou, mas este objeto não sabe onde obter este nome ou Id de usuário - isso precisa ser informado para ele.

### Camada Banco de Dados

Quanto menos a camada *Negócios* conhecer do banco de dados, melhor. Mas este é um conceito um tanto complexo e se a camada *Negócios* pelo menos não precisar conhecer os detalhes de conexão já é um grande começo.

## Criando uma restrição física para evitar que as camadas se misturem

Isso é muito simples de fazer: distribua seu código em *packages* onde um dos nomes próximos à raiz identifique a camada. Por exemplo:

```
com.padaria.aplicativo.estoque
com.padaria.negócio.estoque
```

As telas de estoque da padaria estão no primeiro package e as regras de negócio de estoque estão no segundo. E todos os packages do sistema terão o nome ou começando com *com.padaria.aplicativo* ou começando com *com.padaria.negócio*.

Então, se você tentar referenciar um package *com.padaria.aplicativo* a partir de um package *com.padaria.negócio*, você sabe que estará quebrando seu design de camadas uma vez que uma referência nesta direção não é permitida. Veja o diagrama: a camada *Aplicativo* pode referenciar a si mesma e pode referenciar também a camada *Negócios*. Já a camada *Negócios* pode referenciar apenas a si mesma.

A camada *Banco de Dados* é responsabilidade do servidor de banco, então não tem package.

Eventualmente, no futuro, você não conseguirá mais enquadrar todos os seus artefatos nesses packages, então deve nascer outros como *com.padaria.infra*, *com.padaria.relatorios*, etc., e então você precisará evoluir o design para além do que estou propondo aqui. Mas será uma evolução e não uma revolução e haverá no máximo *refactoring* e não retrabalho.

## Enquadrando o problema do usuário nesta solução de camadas

O objeto principal da camada *Aplicativo* obtém e detém uma instância do usuário, e passa esta instância como referência para os objetos da camada de *Negócios* ou para outros formulários que precisarem dele.

Veja este pseudocódigo como exemplo:

```
public class FormPrincipal {
    
    private String nomeUsuario;
    
    public void main() {
        FormLogin formLogin = new FormLogin();
        formLogin.Show();
        if (formLogin.usuarioCancelou()) {
            return;
        }
        ArgumentosConexao argumentosDb = ArgumentosConexao.fromConfiguracoes("config.properties");
        ConexaoDb conexao = ConexaoDb.get(argumentosDb);
        if (!AutenticacaoUsuario.loginValido(formLogin.nomeUsuario(), formLogin.senha(), conexao)){
            Mensagens.show("Usuário ou senha inválidos.");
            return;
        }
        nomeUsuario = formLogin.nomeUsuario();
        Show(); // libera o usuário para interagir com este formulário principal
    }
    public void botaoProcessa_click() {
        Processamento processamento = new Processamento();
        processamento.processaTudo(nomeUsuario, conexao);
    }
}
```

Neste código, a classe `Processamento` (pouco provável que alguém tenha uma classe com este nome, mas você pegou a idéia) reside na camada de *Negócios* e as demais classes residem na camada *Aplicativo*.

Eu gosto deste código também porque **as dependências estão explícitas** - cada classe expõe os recursos que precisa para fazer o seu trabalho. Isso facilita  a reutilização de objetos em diferentes contextos, os testes automatizados e a manutenção do sistema.

Answer (score 8):

Sim, manter [estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101) não é muito recomendável mas eu não diria que é uma prática terrível. Em quase tudo você vai achar um motivo para usar.

Primeiro precisa ver se tem alguma forma de eliminar esse estado global, se há uma forma de não precisar desta informação de alguma forma. Talvez tenha que reestruturar a aplicação mas não dá para dizer só com as informações fornecidas e acho que não é o foco da pergunta.

Se você precisa do estado global, não tem solução, você terá que armazenar o estado global. Não importa como vai encapsulá-lo ou como vai acessá-lo.

As duas primeiras opções são bastante viáveis. O ideal é não acessar o atributo diretamente. Talvez não seja importante para sua aplicação mas pode ser que no futuro tenha que modificar um pouco a forma de acessar esse atributo, aí complicaria. O método de acesso, um *getter* seria útil.

Os fanáticos por testabilidade vão dizer que não pode fazer isto. Mas é bem provável que você nem saiba do que eles estão falando. Ou seja, isso é ruim para quem faz *unit test* em tudo, mesmo assim ainda tem solução, apesar de um pouco mais complicada.

Você pode até usar uma classe normal e instanciá-la para acessar o estado global, mas não faz muito sentido a não ser que tenha um bom motivo para isto. Um exemplo onde seria útil é se você faz testes, porque aí há a facilidade da substituição da classe por uma outra só para executar o teste. Pode ser que nem precise. Mas esta classe ainda terá que acessar o estado global, você não poderá instanciar a classe e ter acesso a um estado a não ser que ele seja estático de alguma forma. Sem o atributo estático o valor se perde quando a instância sai de escopo.

Uma solução para isto é manter esta instância viva o tempo todo e passar ela como parâmetro para todos os métodos que precisam dela. Esta técnica chama-se [inversão de controle](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invers%C3%A3o_de_controle). Isto dá trabalho mas é uma possibilidade. Tem a vantagem de ser mais flexível - pode ser que você não precise desta flexibilidade - e deixa mais testável - que talvez não te interesse.

Eventualmente esta classe pode ser um [Singleton](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton). Há vantagens e desvantagens em fazer isto, no seu caso pode ser mais vantajoso. Desta forma você pode ter um estado que oficialmente não é global, mas na prática é.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Evitar variáveis globais ou manter um estado global para armazenar informações como usuário logado é bom por vários motivos, mas exige um cuidado com a arquitetura da aplicação.

Uma grande vantagem é facilitar testes automatizados, evitando gambiarras. Outra vantagem é permitir alterações no sistema de forma independente, sem que uma tela possa eventualmente afetar todas as demais ao acessar o dado compartilhado.

Uma forma de fazer atingir isso é com inversão de controle. Ao invés de cada tela acessar um objeto global de login, as telas devem receber esse objeto pronto. Com duas telas isso parece até bobo, mas se o sistema crescer isso vai facilitar muito as coisas.

O design das classes fica mais ou menos assim:

```java
public class Principal {
   public static void main() {
       Login login = JLogin.efetuarLogin();
       if (login.isAutenticado()) {
           JPrincipal principal = new JPrincipal(login);
           principal.show();
       }
   }
}

public class JLogin extends JFrame {
    public static Login efetuarLogin() {
        //mostra modal solicitando usuário e senha
        //valida dados
        return new Login(dadosDoUsuario);
    }
}

public class JPrincipal extends JFrame {
    public JPrincipal(Login login) {
        String mensagem = "Bem-vindo(a) " + login.getNomeCompleto();
        List<Permissao> permissoes = login.getPermissoes();
        ...
    }
}
```

A arquitetura proposta acima permite que cada tela seja independente das demais. Seria possível até duas telas receberem usuários diferentes. Isso permitiria, por exemplo, que um usuário administrador "personificasse" um outro usuário numa determinada tela, ou seja, usasse uma tela como se fosse outro usuário.