# Principal objetivo de classes utilitárias

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes

Qual a real função das classes utilitárias? Seria só reduzir manutenção e repetição de código ou iria além dessas funções?

Teria alguma maneira (convenção) para utilizar essas classes corretamente?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O termo pode ser usado de forma ampla.

Até onde eu sei não tem nada muito definido de como usar. Algumas pessoas dizem para nunca fazer isto, pelo menos não da forma tradicional como se costuma fazer. Elas costumam receber o nome **auxiliares**, **secundárias** ou **ajudadoras** (*helpers*).

## Classe estática

Classes utilitárias costumam ser estáticas.

Algumas pessoas acham que isso nunca deveria existir. Tem quem ache que elas ferem o *design* orientado a objeto, e isto seria um crime mortal.

Realmente existe um problema com este tipo de classe quando há [estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101). Mesmo assim, não significa que não deva existir de fato. Mas é **preferível** classes utilitárias sem estado global. Em geral as utilitárias não possuem estado.

Outro problema: é mais difícil testar código com estas classes. Fica difícil substituí-la. Tem técnicas para isso mas complica um pouco. Por outro lado eu não acho que toda regra deva ser seguida, especialmente se for exclusivamente para facilitar o teste. O código principal é que deve ser fácil, o teste é secundário.

Outro motivo que se costuma reclamar é que ela tende juntar métodos que tem pouca ou nenhuma relação em uma classe. Isto, em tese, diminuiria a coesão. Mas aí o problema não é a classe ser utilitária, mas sim ela ser mal projetada. De qualquer forma mesmo quando isto acontece, se bem pensado, não costuma causar problema real algum. Só um purista, acadêmico, dogmático defende isto. Olhe para os dois lados e escolha qual acha que vai te trazer melhores resultados. Se preferir a coesão a qualquer custo, faça classes utilitárias de um método apenas. Ou mais se ainda puder manter a [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) (leia atentamente lá para não exagerar na tentativa de coesão sem motivo algum).

É utópico achar que a responsabilidade sempre é clara. E se for no "na dúvida eu fiz" acaba tendo um *design* complexo demais.

Se classes estáticas não fossem úteis elas não existiriam na linguagem. Não dá para ser dogmático.

Mas classes utilitárias podem ser instanciadas também. Até onde eu sei o termo não exige que a classe seja estática. Quando isto ocorre elas são chamadas de *helper classes*, mas os termos costumam ser usados de forma intercambiáveis. Não vou entrar em detalhes porque não sei se a pergunta abrange isto.

## Por que usar

Um dos maiores motivos para se fazer isto é evitar a repetição de código. E isto facilita a manutenção.

Os mais experientes e pragmáticos programadores do mundo usam nos mais complexos e mais usados projetos no mundo. Isto não causa problemas reais, quando se sabe o que está fazendo. De fato, você encontra uma quantidade ínfima de projetos, a maioria inexpressivos, que evitam estas classes.

Deixar de usar só para dizer que atendeu um paradigma não resolve problemas. Mas pode trazer outros. Se não vai criar uma classe utilitária, vai por onde um método naturalmente isolado que precisa ser usado em vários lugares? Como vai separar o que é o fundamental de uma classe para o que é apenas acessório? Como permitirá estender funcionalidade de uma classe sem precisar fazer herança? Como vai eliminar a dependência disto sem repetir código?

É claro que quem não sabe fazer cometerá erros. Mas o problema não é da ferramenta é do usuário dela. Como toda ferramenta não há perfeição nela, não atende tudo. Há *designs* que ficam complexos demais quando se descarta a ferramenta certa para a situação.

## Design orientado a objeto

A classe utilitária pode aumentar a coesão das classes que a usam. As classes "principais" fazem apenas o mínimo que ela precisa fazer deixando para a classe utilitária fazer o que é acessório a ela.

Por outro lado ela pode violar o encapsulamento. O OOD costuma dizer que tudo que está relacionado ao objeto deve estar junto dele. A prática mostra que isto fere outros princípios, mas enfim... E hoje muitas pessoas admitem que buscar cegamente o OOD não é a melhor opção. Outras ainda acham isto. Hoje se prefere composição sobre a herança, a maior [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) que o encapsulamento extremo, etc.

Em geral estas classes precisam ser capazes de ser mais genéricas. Se ela atenderá apenas uma classe provavelmente está fazendo algo errado mesmo. Mas há quem ache que mesmo isto é interessante. Há uma corrente de pensamento que diz que só deveria existir métodos na classe principal que acessam os membros privados. Todo o resto deveria vir em classe(s) auxiliar(es). Isto dá mais coesão e facilita a manutenção por dar mais flexibilidade. Linguagens mais modernas incentivam isto - curiosamente voltando ao que era antes, era bom e ideologia deturpou.

Em alguns casos vincular os métodos destas classes com interfaces pode ser uma boa ideia. Assim você pode dizer quem deve usar estas classes. Veja [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101). Facilita o [princípio da segregação da interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) sem duplicar código.

Vários *design patterns* ficam mais complicados quando se opta por evitar este tipo de classe. Na verdade alguns destes padrões ficam quase automáticos quando se separa as responsabilidades corretamente. Os proponentes do OOD puro costumam inchar as classes para obter o tal do encapsulamento. Claro que sempre é feito por programadores ruins. Os bons sabem quando evitar isto.

Pesquise aqui ou em outros lugares os problemas que as pessoas têm em desenvolvimento de software e verá que não são porque existem classes utilitárias. E olha que muitas são mal feitas, mesmo assim, não causam os reais problemas no seu código.

## Conclusão

Muitas vezes se gasta um tempo enorme para resolver um improvável problema futuro que economizará pouco tempo.

Use a ferramenta no lugar e momento certo. Aprenda usá-la. Saiba tudo que ela pode lhe ajudar ou prejudicar. E se tiver dúvidas específicas, pergunte aqui.

Classes utilitárias organizam código, separam responsabilidades, reduzem repetição de código, simplificam a manutenção.

Classes utilitárias não são ruins, programadores ruins criam e usam classes utilitárias de forma ruim.

Você pode facilitar ou dificultar seu projeto criando uma classe utilitária. A maioria dos projetos se beneficiará delas mesmo quando não tão bem pensadas assim. E só a experiência e mente aberta vai te dar a dosagem certa.

Faça uma das coisas básicas para todas as classes: documente bem elas, aprenda com as que fizeram para você usar e ensine os outros sobre as que você criou.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, ficaria mais simples se eu criar uma Classe utilitária para cada função, por exemplo: ConversaoDataUtil, nessa classe coloco apenas métodos que fazem o parse das datas recebidas?

Comment: Dizer que classes utilitárias não causam problemas reais é uma anti-informação. O Java teve e tem muitos problemas por causa de APIs que ignoravam princípios da OOP que ele se propõe a suportar (leia o artigo indicado pelo rray). Por exemplo, no Java precisamos de bibliotecas externas para fazer coisas que que já estão disponíveis no próprio Java porque foram mal disponibilizadas (log e data são exemplos clássicos). A API de arquivos também era uma lástima e precisou ser revolucionada nas últimas versões.

Comment: @Techies Não é questão de ficar mais simples, é questão de deixar mais organizado. Sem dúvida não deve criar classes utilitárias que fazem muita coisa. Então uma classe dessas que mexe em coais além da data é quase certo que faz muita coisa. Pode ser que mesmo esta classe faça coisas demais. Mas em geral isto não acontece. Aí vai da experiência. Como eu disse, se estiver em dúvida em caso específico faça uma pergunta específica e detalhada.

Comment: @Caffé aquele artigo foi discutido e rechaçado em vários lugares. O que está lá tem fundamento? Tem. Mas há um exagero nas consequências. Você acabou de dizer que o problema é que foi mal feito. Este é outro problema. Não é porque usou classe utilitária é que ficou uma lástima.

Answer (score 8):

## O que é uma classe utilitária

Seria bacana se a pergunta oferecesse uma definição de "classe utilitária" para garantir que estamos falando da mesma coisa.

Vou supor que classe utilitária seja aquela que publique recursos genéricos utilizado por toda parte na aplicação.

Por exemplo, ela retorna o usuário corrente, o nome do host, metadados do sistema, tem funções de formatação de informações de negócio, eventualmente dados de conexão com o banco de dados...

## Por que você não deveria usar classes utilitárias

> Classes utilitárias não são coesas.

Ela recebe o nome de "utilitária" justamente para que o seu objetivo não precise ser bem definido, de modo que você pode pôr qualquer coisa lá dentro. "Isso será usado em vários lugares e eu não sei onde publicar" - joga na classe utilitária.

Se você está falando de classe, você deve estar falando de orientação a objetos. Se você está interessado em orientação a objetos, não existe espaço para classes utilitárias.

> Ferir princípios bem estabelecidos de um paradigma não é simplesmente falta de etiqueta - o princípio existe para resolver um problema e quando você fere o princípio você abre as portas para o problema que ele visa resolver.

Em OOP, cada objeto deve ter uma única responsabilidade. A classe utilitária recebe o nome de *"útil"* justamente para que possa ter infinitas responsabilidades.

<sub>Parando pra pensar, podemos lançar a questão: se está é a classe útil, as demais classes do sistema são o que? Inúteis?</sub>

Você acaba com todo o teu sistema acoplado a uma gigantesca classe, muitas vezes custosa para ser criada quando ela publica o estado de muita coisa, então você acaba precisando também usar singletons, incluindo complexidade acidental no sistema.

Como muita coisa depende da classe, é difícil avaliar o impacto de uma mudança nela, então você evita mudá-la e, ao invés, "só por segurança", escreve novos métodos fazendo quase a mesma coisa que outros métodos já existentes, **levando à duplicação de código em vez de evitá-la**.

Se "classe utilitária" é isso que eu descrevi no começo, existem N problemas em utilizá-la (posso listar outros problemas se for do interesse) e nenhum benefício real.

## Teria alguma maneira (convenção) para utilizar essas classes corretamente?

O certo é não utilizá-las e sim elaborar um pouco melhor o design, encontrando o lugar certo para publicar cada recurso. Sempre haverá o nome certo e o lugar certo para um recurso, e se estiver difícil de encontrá-lo é porque o design pode ser melhorado.

## Agora, no campo da opinião:

Em outra resposta está escrito "o teste é secundário". Por favor, tome isso como sendo uma expressão de opinião, e é uma idéia já bastante ultrapassada inclusive.

A minha porção de opinião nesta reposta é: se não está testado, está quebrado.

Em havendo oportunidade no projeto, nenhum código deveria estar descoberto de testes automatizados.

O teste automatizado em plataformas modernas não exige um design específico para permitir o teste, ele exige apenas um bom design, e bom design é sempre desejável mesmo que você não quisesse automatizar os testes.

Comment: Algumas dessas classes utilitarias são repositorios de funções. O problema do `utils` é só mudar o nome do pacote/namespace para commons, o que estiver fora dele é especializado :P hehe. Já olhou [isso](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html)

Comment: Sim, é minha opinião e de muita gente. Não é o de outras tantas. O teste é secundário não significa que ele não deva existir mas sim que não se deve complicar a aplicação só para facilitar o teste. O *design* correto sempre é fundamental e se isto for feito, o teste não será complicado. Mas se tiver que escolher entre complicar a aplicação ou o que é necessário para fazer o teste, eu prefiro complica o segundo. O que não quer dizer que a verificação em si seja complicada. Concordo que se a pessoa fizer errado, acaba criando uma situação que dificulta muito e aí está errado mesmo.

Comment: @rray Não conhecia o artigo e achei muito bacana, inclusive minha resposta e o artigo estão completamente de acordo. Acho que seria relevante você sugerir o artigo na outra resposta, que defende o uso de classes utilitárias. bigown, eu só complicava a aplicação para garantir o teste quando eu sabia ainda menos do que sei hoje. Hoje em dia é o inverso: os testes me ajudam a descomplicar a aplicação.

Comment: Estava acabando de ler sua resposta, e vi que as duas respostas são excelentes e bem esclarecedoras, no meu ponto de vista uma chega a complementar o que falta na outra. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Afirmar que o "certo é não usar" eu acho meio complicado. Caberia melhor se você passasse pro campo de "opinião" sua, logo abaixo, pois pra quem sabe o que está fazendo, é uma mão na roda, e não dá problema nenhum. Como opinião pessoal pode até ser. Como verdade absoluta, entendo como um ponto falho na resposta.

Comment: @Bacco Eu expliquei na primeira parte da resposta, baseado em princípios amplamente aceitos da orientação a objetos e descrevendo problemas reais, por quê o certo é não usar. E descrevi também de que tipo de classe utilitária eu estou falando. Ou seja, eu delimitei um contexto e apresentei evidências. A conclusão de que o certo é não usar, portanto, não é meramente opinativa. E naturalmente não se trata de uma verdade absoluta (existe isso?). Nada do que eu escrevo é para ser lido como uma tentativa de apresentar uma verdade absoluta.

Comment: @Caffé até entendo o seu ponto de vista, mas sem ler o seu comentário, a impressão que dá é de ser uma afirmação absoluta, por isso comentei.