# Em MVC, se eu tiver classes de utilitários, elas farão parte dos models?

Tags: mvc

Para exemplificar, vamos supor que possuo uma classe de manipulação de strings chamada `strman` que irei utilizar para armazenar operações para trabalhar com strings, já na pasta models eu possuo `usuario` e `usuarioDAO`, no caso da classe `strman`, ela pode ficar junto com as classes que possuo nos models?

E caso ela seja mesmo um model e possa ficar nesta pasta, como posso organizar para que não misture com a lógica da aplicação? *(digo a lógica principal que são as classes que contém as regras do negócio, e não utilitários como manipuladores de strings)*

Comment: Relacionada: [Principal objetivo de classes utilitárias](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se isso são mesmo utilitários, você deveria organizar sob uma estrutura dessa categoria, geralmente um diretório/namespace chamdo `Helpers`, `Utils`, `Services`, depende de qual nomenclatura seu ambiente ou framework usa.

Elas não deveriam fazer parte do seu model porque suas operações são mais genéricas e principalmente porque não são vinculadas diretamente com fluxo de operações de suas regras de negócio. Como você mesmo disse, são apenas utilitários.

**Um exemplo prático:**
Uma determinada aplicação ao cadastrar um blog post precisa gerar um [slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) para esse registro. Embora você pudesse gerar esse slug na própria função ou método que persiste o registro na base de dados, seria muito melhor você extrair essa operação para uma categoria da aplicação mais apropriada, como um `service` ou `helper`, ou mesmo `stringutils`. Agora você pode usar esse gerador de slug não somente no método onde a persistência do blog post ocorre, mas também em qualquer lugar que precise criar um slug de uma string.

Comment: Sua edição matou a charada da minha pergunta, porém tenho uma segunda dúvida que talvez até mereça uma pergunta, tenho receio de criar dependência, tanto de usar essa classe `strman` com métodos estáticos ou de ter uma instância injetada no model. Seria muito prejudicial eu usar essas funções dentro do model e criar uma dependência?

Comment: @RenanCavalieri Se sua classe depende de outra, ora,tudo bem. O problema é como essa dependência é vinculada ao seu objeto principal. Use Dependency Injection tanto para explicitar as dependências do objeto quanto para facilitar a troca para outro classe de que implemente a mesma interface que `Srtman` implementa (StrmanInterface). Quanto aos métodos estáticos, é outra questão. Não há problemas se há uma motivação para eles serem estáticos, mas questões sobre isso no stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Não é *bacana* essas classes de utilitários.

No seu caso, crie uma pasta chamada `Extensions` e crie então uma classe `StringExtensions` e dentro dela ponha todos os métodos que sejam para tratar strings.

Exemplo, se vc for colocar um método para contar palavras:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int WordCount(this String string)
    {
        return string.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    }
}
```

E depois para consumir:

```
var nome = "Renan Cavalieri";
var totalPalavras = nome.WordCount();
```

Comment: Concordo com a visão de que não é legal. Ser específico quanto ao nome de namespaces e de classes é sempre uma boa coisa. Criar uma classe e fazer um cinto de utilidades do Batman é uma péssima ideia. Eu já ouvi um comentário zueira que se você tem um namespace chamado Util, então você diz que todo o resto do projeto é inútil :D

Comment: Foi uma má expressão minha, não sabia como dizer, no meu projeto estava usando com o namespace \app\componentes\strings\ e a classe com o nome `strman`, no caso, será que componente seria um termo correto?

Comment: @RenanCavalieri, componente tem metadados mais complexos. Vc apenas quer agrupar métodos de tratar string, então Extensions é mais adequado.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi, disso eu não sabia, achei o assunto interessante, farei uma pergunta a respeito das diferenças de componente e extensões.