# Qual a diferença entre os termos "extensão" e "componente"?

Tags: terminologia

Eu recebi um [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106924/em-mvc-se-eu-tiver-classes-de-utilit%C3%A1rios-elas-far%C3%A3o-parte-dos-models/106925?noredirect=1#comment220279_106925) em uma de minhas perguntas e achei o tema interessante, pois eu não sei diferenciar um `componente` de uma `extensão` em um sistema.

**O que são componentes e o que são extensões, e qual a diferença entre eles?**

Comment: Desconfio que o `extensions` naquele contexto se refere aos [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) do C#, é uma funcionalidade que permite adicionar métodos a tipos já existentes(como se fosse uma método nativo), veja no exemplo da resposta que a classe não é chamada, o `WordCount()` foi aplicado direto na variável(provavelmente do tipo string).

Comment: Renan, pelo comentário também desconfio que isso seja específico do C#. Por favor revise se é disso que se trata a pergunta e atualize-a conforme necessário.

Comment: Tem, [Qual é a diferença de API, biblioteca e Framework?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/91) que bate na trave.

Comment: @utluiz, irei tentar confirmar se é isso, eu encontre no SO em inglês, achei que se tratava de uma terminologia geral e não específica, por isso perguntei, e também porque não achei nada em português. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139519/what-is-the-difference-between-component-extension-module-in-yii - Porém esse parece ser específico sobre uma framework, mas aparentemente PHP.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri Extensão e Componente são termos extremamente sobrecarregados, isto é, existe uma terminologia geral que explica o que são, assim como existem milhares e diferentes tipos de componentes e extensões específicos de linguagens, sistemas e até componentes de hardware, mas acho que apenas saber dos termos gerais não vai satisfazer o que você quer saber de acordo com aquele comentário. Enfim, você deve decidir se quer saber o que são, genericamente falando, componentes e extensões, ou se quer saber o que são componentes e extensions do C#.

Comment: @utluiz entendi, queria saber dos termos gerais mesmo, citei o comentário pois achei que seria relevante para a pergunta, mas desconhecia a existência tantas variações dos termos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Componente de Software

**Componente** de software é uma entidade lógica que agrupa um conjunto de funcionalidades relacionadas. É geralmente composto por uma ou mais interfaces que definem quais serviços (métodos) são providos pelo componente e classes que implementam as funcionalidades.

Numa aplicação financeira, por exemplo, você pode ter um componente para tratar de contas bancárias, outro relacionado a clientes e outro a cobrança de boletos. Todos esses componentes são integrados através de suas *interfaces* e cooperam para o objeto global da aplicação.

A componentização, quando corretamente implementada, traz vários benefícios. Por exemplo:

- Permite a divisão coerente do trabalho, onde pessoas ou equipes podem trabalhar em diferentes componentes, enquanto a forma como a interação entre eles ocorre é bem definida por meio de interfaces.
- Permite a evolução independente da implementação dos componentes, pois já que cada componente é acessado pela interfaces.
- Permite a realização de testes individuais em cada componente antes da integração do sistema, permitindo assim antecipar problemas.

## Extensão

**Extensão** de um software é uma entidade, geralmente um *componente* de software, que adiciona funcionalidades a um software existente.

Em geral podemos dizer que uma *extensão* é um tipo especializado de *componente* que é comumente distribuído separadamente do sistema principal.

Um software é extensível quando ele possui mecanismos para que novos componentes, ou extensões, adicionem funcionalidades que não são previstas ou requeridas pelo código principal.

Um software pode ser composto de componentes, mas não ser extensível, isto é, não permitir que novos componentes sejam adicionados.

Mecanismos de extensão incluem:

- DLL (Windows) / SO (Linux), que são bibliotecas executáveis que podem ser carregadas dinamicamente.
- Classes ou arquivos com código que são detectados automaticamente pelo sistema e podem, por exemplo, adicionar menus ou componentes ao sistema principal.
- Hooks / WebHooks / Observer Pattern, que são mecanismos onde uma aplicação qualquer pode registar na aplicação alvo para receber notificações de eventos e realizar ações diversas.

Enfim, em geral, haverá algum tipo de API com *pontos de extensão* que possibilitem contribuir com componentes e executar alguma coisa lógica em determinados eventos do sistema.

Alguns tipos de extensão podem ser *plugadas* em tempo de execução, outras precisam ser carregadas durante a inicialização do programa principal.

## Considerações

Componentes e extensões existem em diferentes níveis de abstração e possuem variadas aplicações. Por exemplo:

- Para um ERP, cada subsistema pode ser visto como um componente, enquanto terceiros podem estender o ERP implementando novos subsistemas ou novos módulos para os subsistemas existente.
- Para um sistema, cada módulo pode ser visto como um componente.
- Para um módulo, determinadas classes podem funcionar como componentes.
- Para uma aplicação que aceita plugins, cada plugin é visto como uma extensão.
- Um plugin, que funciona como uma extensão, pode ser composto de vários subcomponentes.

Enfim, o termo é bastante sobrecarregado e na maior parte do tempo, o entendimento de que parte de um software é um componente ou uma extensão depende do contexto e do ponto de vista de que você está tratando.

Answer (score 0):

De um modo resumido, um componente agrega mais funcionalidade a algo já existente.

Uma extensão agrega funcionalidades novas que não existem ou mesmo que já existam, tais funcionalidades são como uma entidade independente. Normalmente chamadas de libraries (bibliotecas).

Na prática, existe ambiguidade no emprego de ambos os termos. Por vezes você encontrará softwares que definem uma "extensão" como "componente" ou vice-versa. Também verá termos como "plugin". Afinal, um plugin é uma extensão ou um componente?

Não há uma normal universal para definição exata pois depende do contexto.

Na linguagem ASP (asp clássico), por exemplo, não tem recurso nativo para envio de email. Para isso existem os componentes como o CDONT. Mas por quê é tratado como componente e não com uma extensão já que o CDONT agrega uma funcinalidade de forma independente? O CDONT deveria ser tratado como uma extensão. O mesmo no caso de upload de arquivo. Pela falta de recurso nativo, há componentes como o "DUNDAS Upload".

Mas se analisarmos bem, o termo "extensão" pode ser interepretado como uma extensão de funcionalidades, o que dá no mesmo contexto de "componente".

Como pode ver, é confuso e ambíguo definir o quê é o quê. Dependerá da interpretação do desenvolvedor do aplicativo caso já não exista um consenso dentro do contexto das ferramentas usadas.