# Como converter uma string em data ou date?

Tags: java

Tenho aqui as declaracoes que preciso converter de string para date, podem me ajudar?

```
ObjAl.setDataEmissao(TxtDataEmissao.getText());
ObjAl.setDataNascimento(TxtDataNascimento.getText());
```

Answer (score 5):

Existe o [**`DateTimeFormatter`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Utilizando ele é possível converter uma string em um objeto [**`LocalDate`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), que faz parte da nova API de datas do Java, um exemplo:

```
String data = "13 Janeiro 2016";

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(data, format);
```

Os padrões aceitos podem ser encontrados no [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), embora eles não sejam nenhuma novidade para quem trabalha com datas em Java.

Tendo o `localDate`, podemos manipular o objeto para, por exemplo, obter o dia da semana:

```
String diaDaSemana = localDate.getDayOfWeek()
                              .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()); 

System.out.println(diaDaSemana); // Quarta-feira
```

A nova API de datas do Java é inspirada no [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) e seu principal objetivo é trabalhar com datas e tempos.

Diferentemente de um objeto [**`Date`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) que representa um instante na linha do tempo, armazenado em um `long` que contabiliza os milissegundos desde a meia-noite de 1970.

Se você realmente precisa trabalhar com milissegundos, vá de **`Date`** ou **`Instant`**. Mas se quer trabalhar de forma simples com objetos de tempo, seja legal e use a nova api.

- O [**`LocalDate`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) está aí para manipular datas exclusivamente.
- Se quiser trabalhar somente com o tempo/horário, existe o [**`LocalTime`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html).
- Se precisar da data e horário, há o [**`LocalDateTime`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns).

Para finalizar, dá para transformar o `LocalDateTime` em um objeto `Date` por meio da classe [**`Timestamp`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
String data = "13 Janeiro 2016, 16:22";

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy, HH:mm");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(data, format); 

Date d = Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);
System.out.println(d); // 2016-01-13 16:22:00.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.sql.Date data = new java.sql.Date(format.parse(dataStr).getTime());
```

Lembra de adaptar para sua necessidade.

Comment: Mto obrigado pela resposta Otto, mas como implemento esse codigo nesta minha questao? porq se fosse para converter uma string para Inteiro, eu colocava simplesmente o Integer.parseInt();

Comment: @yoly  dataStr seria seu TxtDataEmissao.getText() simlpes assim

Comment: Hamm! Agora sim, peguei. Valeu :)

Answer (score 4):

O `SimpleDateFormat` tem a finalidade de converter as `java.util.Date` em `String` e vice-versa.

Ao construir este objeto é possível informar qual o padrão de data que você deseja transformar ou recuperar.

Caso este padrão não seja informado, será utilizado o prado pelo `Locale` do Usuário.

[Segue a documentação da classe.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Exemplo de utilização:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date dataAtual = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

        String DateToStr = format.format(dataAtual);
        System.out.println(DateToStr);

        format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        DateToStr = format.format(dataAtual);
        System.out.println(DateToStr);

        format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy zzzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateToStr = format.format(dataAtual);
        System.out.println(DateToStr);

        format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        DateToStr = format.format(dataAtual);
        System.out.println(DateToStr);

        try {
            Date strToDate = format.parse(DateToStr);
            System.out.println(strToDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

No seu caso, deve se atentar o formato em que o `TxtDataEmissao` está exibindo para instanciar o seu `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
// Verifique o formato!

    try {       
               ObjAl.setDataEmissao(format.parse(TxtDataEmissao.getText()));
       } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: muito boa resposta mestre parabéns.

Comment: Muito boa resposta sim, foi bem claro e resolveu meu problema...Valeu :)

Comment: não esqueça de [aceitar uma das respostas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Answer (score 4):

Uma Alternativa seria criar uma Classe [utilitária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90047/principal-objetivo-de-classes-utilit%C3%A1rias) com os métodos que convertem as datas, caso você precise fazer conversões em mais lugares. Ou então pode criar os métodos na própria Classe, Exemplo:

```
    public static Date parseDate(String data) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        return sdf.parse(data);
    }

    public static String parseDate(Date data) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        return sdf.format(data);
    }

    public static java.sql.Date getSqlDate(Date data) {
        return new java.sql.Date(data.getTime());
    }
```

Depois é só chamar esses métodos passando uma String ou Date, dessa forma:

```
//Converte String pra Date
ObjAl.setDataEmissao(parseDate(TxtDataEmissao.getText()));
```

Comment: Essa é uma boa forma de evitar reescrever o mesmo código em todo lugar! GO DRY CODE!