# O que é Feature Envy?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, engenharia-de-software

O que é Feature Envy?

Por que ela é considerada um mau cheiro de código (*code smell*)?

Quais as vantagens de evitá-la?

Ela deve ser evitada sempre?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Um método pode acessar dados de outro tipo para fazer alguma operação. Quando isso se torna algo comum significa que o próprio objeto deveria executar essa operação e entregar o resultado. Então diz-se que um método ficou com **inveja de um tipo** e quis fazer por conta própria.

Não tem como evitá-la sempre porque depende de alterar o tipo original que você não tem acesso ou não pode alterá-lo por algum motivo. Tem casos é o comportamento precisa ficar separado propositalmente.

A ideia é que isso viola o encapsulamento e não é tão orientado a objeto. Como nem tudo precisa disso, mesmo quando pode, não é algo que precisa ser evitado sempre. Tanto que esse é um dos casos que você tem que escolher qual veneno vai tomar, porque encher um tipo de métodos para tentar resolver tudo o que pode aparecer ou deixar o tipo aberto para alteração pode ser um problema maior ainda. É comum ter outro *smell* que diz que a correção é fazer exatamente o que este diz que não pode.

Tem tipos que existem apenas para fornecer dados. Isto causa arrepios em muita gente, mas usado na coisa certa é uma boa solução. Assim como é melhor ter [classes utilitárias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/101) ou alguns padrões de projeto famosos que fazem composição para realizar certas tarefas que não devem ser tratadas pelo tipo.

Depende muito do caso quanto tem vantagem, em alguns casos a vantagem é no mínimo discutível.

Eu tenho a opinião que esse é um dos clássicos exemplos de alguém definir alguma coisa olhando pro detalhe e esquece do todo. É mais uma das coisas criadas por teóricos.

Sim, tudo isso não é OO, que bom.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).