# Em linguagens como Java, como distribuir métodos estáticos entre classes?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, engenharia-de-software, métodos-estáticos

Estava vendo uma resposta de [Qual a função de um método estático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54021/357) e no ponto:

> Podemos entender o método estático como um método utilitário, como algo que não pertence ao objeto e está ali só para ser encapsulado no tipo

Me ocorreu de perguntar: existe alguma recomendação quanto à maneira de distribuir métodos estáticos entre classes em linguagens como Java, que não permitem funções fora de classes?

Por exemplo:

- Se o método acessa somente seus parâmetros, talvez seja melhor colocar na classe em que será chamado, se for apenas uma;
- Se o método acessa variáveis estáticas (isso leva a perguntar, como deve ser distribuída uma variável estática?), talvez seja melhor colocar junto à classe onde essa variável está declarada.
- Outros princípios podem ser aplicados, com o objetivo de reduzir eventuais acoplamentos.

Infelizmente não tenho um exemplo à mão para tornar a pergunta mais específica, se encontrar acrescento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Se o método acessa somente seus parâmetros, talvez seja melhor colocar na classe em que será chamado, se for apenas uma;

Não acessa o `this`, certo? Isso é a definição de método estático, não ajuda determinar como colocar em uma classe ou não.

> Se o método acessa variáveis estáticas (isso leva a perguntar, como deve ser distribuída uma variável estática?), talvez seja melhor colocar junto à classe onde essa variável está declarada.

A única forma correta de fazer é assim, se acessa uma variável estática, que deveria ser evitada, obrigatoriamente deve estar na classe que a variável está.

## Definição básica

Geralmente você coloca na classe que faz sentido, e isso é bem subjetivo, depende do domínio.

Uma regrinha que pode usar, mas ela pode ser facilmente usada errada é que se recebe como parâmetro principal o objeto da classe, mas o acessa sem privilégios do `this` pode ser uma boa que ela esteja na classe desse objeto. Mas tem muitas exceções.

Ao contrário da crença popular que alguns ensinam, o método estático é o mais restrito e por isso ele deve ser a escolha padrão nas classes, você só adota um método de instância se depende de privilégios no acesso ao objeto, e por isso o `this` se faz necessário.

Em alguns casos não é trágico e é aceitável usar método de instância sem precisar se tiver um bom motivo, talvez porque sabe que no futuro precisará com quase certeza de acesso privilegiado.

Mais polêmico seria fazer isso só por estética, já que o método estático é mais verboso de chamar quando o objeto da classe será usado (tem classes que usam [UFCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax), e Java permite chamar método estático pelo objeto, o que pode ser considerado uma aberração se não é UFCS).

## Exemplos

#### Construção

Muitos métodos estáticos recebem outros parâmetros, e quem sabe retorne um objeto da classe. De fato métodos de construção que não são os construtores oficiais tendem ser exatamente isto, recebem outros dados e geram um objeto daquela classe. Tem linguagem que só os possui para construir objetos. E o construtor da linguagem não deixa de ser um método estático, com uma característica especial. Disparado é o maior uso de estáticos em Java.

Uma boa dica para aprender é ver códigos de bons programadores para ir treinando. Mas cuidado porque todo mundo pode errar, e se treinar o erro é ele que fará a vida todo. Tem que ter uma certa criticidade. Vamos analisar a biblioteca padrão de Java. Começando pela [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html):

[image: Lista de métodos estáticos de String]

Todos retornam o objeto da classe, eles são uma forma alternativa de construção dele.

#### Relação direta com o objeto

Vamos para o [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) (não vou colocar a imagem porque é muito grande, vê lá na bas de estáticos. Retorna os mais variados tipos. Boa parte dele recebe um objeto do tipo ou até um *array* com esse objeto para manipulá-lo, conforme eu citei antes.

Alguns não tem relação com `char` ou `Character`, mas tem relação com o assunto, pode ver que todos "falam" de *codepoint*, completamente relacionado com um caractere, exemplo:

[image: descrição do charCount()]

Vamos na [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html):

[image: Lista dos estáticos da classe]

Não parece ser difícil perceber que elas se ligam com a linha de execução de *thread* (não é do processo todo, só ocorre no fio de execução atual). Note que ele está acessando algo estático, mesmo que não pareça, é na *thread* atual, que só pode ter uma.

#### Classe estática

Precisa pegar um exemplo que todos os métodos são estáticos? Então é [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html). Há controvérsias e algumas pessoas acham que todos eles deveriam estar em outras classes. E eu não acho uma defesa absurda não, mas consigo enxergar mérito nessa escolha também. è algo que espero um dia pensar com mais afinco. Mas só faz sentido gastar "pestana" se eu for fazer a biblioteca padrão de uma linguagem. Pode ser um erro que quase todas linguagens escolheram.

Poderia falar de muitas outras, como [`System`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html), mas aí caímos na discussão de [classes utilitárias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/101) (mais), que devem existir, mas não pode ser um balaio de gato, como vemos na última.

[Mais um exemplo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) de classe "pau para toda obra" que até faz sentido ser estática, mas não como tudo isso, e quem sabe junto com [outras classes já existentes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) ([outra](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html)). Mas eu admito que nem sempre é fácil colocar em uma classe, porque ela caberia em mais de uma classe por um critério, por exemplo ao mesmo tempo o método é uma forma de construção para um tipo (retornando-o) e uma manipulação de um outro tipo (parâmetro principal). Na dúvida de onde colocar, coloca em um local neutro.

[`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) cai em uma situação especial por ser utilitária para um mecanismo da linguagem.

## Conclusão

Aceito sugestões de classes com casos diferentes.

Lembrando que Java começou considerando que método estático era coisa do capeta, então tem melhores exemplos, e erros, em C#, C++, etc.

[Sugestão de leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) que pode ajudar, sem entregar o ouro, já que isso só com experiência mesmo, até errando, e aprendendo com o erro.

Quer saber mais detalhes sobre o assunto ou algo correlato? Faça perguntas específicas (se já não tem, pesquise antes) e me avise para responder. Responderei o que der e me motivar.

Comment: _"Não acessa o this, certo? Isso é a definição de método estático, não ajuda determinar como colocar em uma classe ou não."_ Pensei em uma classe cujas instâncias precisam tratar parâmetros quaisquer vindos da instância mas não `this`, e para isso chamam um método estático, aí esse método poderia ser colocado na classe. Ou isso que falei não faz sentido? Talvez não, né? Poderia muito bem então acessar diretamente os parâmetros com `this` dentro do método e omiti-los da lista de parâmetros. Ok.

Comment: Por exemplo, em um _assembler_ que implementei era preciso gerar um caminho de arquivo de saída com extensão diferente do arquivo de entrada, para isso eu criei um método, que achei que poderia ser estático e ficar dentro da classe, que recebia o caminho original e a nova extensão como parâmetros e retornava o caminho alterado. Poderia muito bem ter omitido os parâmetros, usado no método o caminho original que era variável de instância do objeto, e deixado a extensão _hard-coded_, visto que era um uso pontual. Nem havia necessidade de ser estático. Aí a questão da distribuição perde o sentido.

Comment: "Pensei em uma classe cujas instâncias precisam tratar parâmetros quaisquer vindos da instância mas não this" não sei o q isso quer dizer.

Comment: Quis dizer o método estático fazer um processamento somente baseado nos parâmetros, que por acaso podem vir de uma instância. O próprio exemplo que dei seria um caso assim, mas já vi que não faz muito sentido para uso pontual. Ou, se fosse um método reutilizável, então o critério de colocar junto da classe que chama deixaria de valer porque haveria mais de uma chamando, teria que procurar colocar em alguma classe utilitária (uma `PathUtils` ou `StringUtils` no caso, a meu ver).