# Esse código gera algum problema de memória?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, memória, static

Segue o código original:

```
class Table{
    private static $table;

    public static function draw( stdData $data ){
        self::$table = new self;
        return self::$table->_draw( $data );
    }
    ...
```

Fiz esta modificação abaixo para tentar driblar um possível problema com memória:

```
class Table{
    private static $table;

    public static function draw( stdData $data ){
        self::$table = new self;
        $html = self::$table->_draw( $data );
        unset(self::$table);
        return $html;
    ...
```

Mas gerou problema:

```
Fatal error: Attempt to unset static property Table::$table in Table.php on line 8
```

O código original causa algum problema de memória? Como seria a forma correta de sair do problema?

Ou seja, ela ocupa espaço na memória desnecessariamente?

O objetivo é usar em outro momento `echo Table::draw($data);` para imprimir uma tabela e que após o uso não ter nada na memória por conta disso.

Comment: Que tipo de problema de memória estamos falando? Eu não sei se esse código faz algum sentido, já que não tem um contexto maior.

Comment: Quero minimizar o uso de memória o máximo possível, no caso liberar a memória que estaria em `self::$table`. A class apenas gera um html de uma table de acordo com o que estiver em `$data`.

Comment: você chegou a medir o consumo de memoria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP é uma linguagem de *script* por isso s programas rodam por um período muito curto. Em geral mesmo que exista vazamentos de memória não costuma ser muito relevante.

O código não tem muito contexto mas vou dizer que provavelmente não deveria ser assim. Normalmente a classe deveria ser normal e não estática, se se é para ser estática mesmo, talvez não deveria ser uma classe. Parece muita complicação para nada.

Se acha que o fato do valor ser estático está segurando dados na memória, a solução é simples, não deixe ela estática, assim no momento que a instância não estiver mais sendo usada, ela será removida da memória.

Você deve ser perguntar porque esta classe é estática com [estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101) ou se isto deveria ser uma classe. Até existem exceções, mas a regra básica é que se tem estado evite que seja estático. Claro que se você souber muito o que está fazendo não tem problema, não parece ser o caso. Vai no simples.

Posso estar enganado, mas esta linha `self::$table = new self;` não parece fazer sentido algum.

Se quiser insistir em tentar reduzir o consumo de memória atribua um nulo para o membro estático:

```
$table = null;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/DoNull.php).

Quando você precisa fazer isto tem algo errado no código. Duvido que precise desta variável, o código nem mostra onde ela está sendo usada, talvez em lugar algum, e se estiver parece estar usada do jeito errado.

Se o código está confuso demais, tem algo errado nele, este é o maior problema. Se você não entende 100% o que está acontecendo nele, é melhor fazer de um jeito que entenda. Simplifique. Eu ajudaria mais se tivesse mais contexto.

Comment: Não compreendo que contexto a mais seria necessário. Do jeito 'normal' em outro momento faria esse uso: `$table = new Table();echo $table->draw($data);` e ficaria esta $table ocupando espaço de instância desnecessariamente (apesar de mínimo) até o final.

Mas no caso que apresentei seria possível fazer esse uso `echo Table::draw($data);` e que gostaria que não fizesse mais uso de memória dessa instância criada dentro dessa função estática. Creio que o null já ajude em enxugar.

Comment: Você está muito preocupado com coisas que não deveria gerar preocupação. Mas principalmente você está tentando fazer "mágica" para resolver problemas, que provavelmente nem existem. E que talvez não mude nada. Provavelmente esta classe toda está errada, mas só vi um trecho dela. Eu dei a dica de atribuir um nulo. Mas quase sempre que se faz isto, está fazendo algo errado em algum lugar. Eu tenho sérias dúvidas se deveria ter essa variável estática. Eu te falei o que precisa fazer, se você não quer seguir, fique a vontade, o prejuízo será só seu.

Comment: ... Em nenhum momento me coloco em "não quero seguir o que você fala". O que quero é entender seu motivo. Estou com você quanto liberar essa memória seja algo irrelevante e eu estar procurando pelo em ovo. Mas gostaria de fazer mesmo assim, a menos que, como você diz, haja problema. Mas me parece que o problema que diz é 'apenas possivelmente no restante', não nisso mostrado, certo? Estando perfeito no restante isso mostrado é apenas desnecessário ou algo ruim? Por quê?

Comment: O meu motivo é ser pragmático. Achei curioso como a sua 3a. frase contradiz a 1a. :) O problema maior está no que eu digo no último parágrafo e pincelo nos anteriores. Todo o código está esquisito. Vou repetir, eu não posso ajudar mais só olhando este trecho. Embora ajudar mais que isto não caberia mais nesta pergunta. E só poderia dizer como eu faria. Mas aí você vai falar que prefere fazer assim mesmo. Você está fazendo uma suposição que não condiz com a realidade. Programação não é olhar um trecho de código e dizer se está certo ou errado.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas otimize os gargalos e não onde não precisa. Esse código ai tenta 'destruir' um pedaço da classe. O correto é atribuir `null` nessa propriedade.

No lugar de:

```
unset(self::$table);
```

mude para:

```
self::$table = null;
```