# Como passar a resposta recebida pelo volley para uma variável Global?

Tags: java, android, volley

Boa tarde, queria saber como posso passar um `JSONObject` recebido no volley para uma variável global:

```
public class ReceberObjeto {
    private JSONObject res;

    public ReceberObjeto(String URL, Context context, Map<String,String> params) {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        CustomJsonObjectRequest request = new CustomJsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    res = response; //AQUI ESTA O PROBLEMA
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    volleyError.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a razão para querer usar uma variável global?

Comment: Este dado que vou receber será retornado no método getRes para outra classe. Porém não estou conseguindo, quando faço o retorno, o valor está nulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julgo que o que você quer é que essa classe comunique o resultado à classe que a utiliza.

A utilização de variáveis globais não é [recomendado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/2541), existem outras formas de conseguir o que pretende.

Uma forma usual é essa classe receber/registar um *Listener* que tem um método que será chamado quando o resultado for obtido.
Repare que a própria classe *CustomJsonObjectRequest* utiliza esse sistema para informar o código cliente quando obtém a *Response* ou existe algum erro(métodos `onResponse()` e `onErrorResponse()` da interface *Response.Listener*).

Comece por declarar uma interface que o *Listener* deve implementar:

```
public interface ResultListener {
      public void onResult(JSONObject resultado);
}
```

Crie um método para receber/registar o *Listener*:

```
public void setResultListener(ResultListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Quando o resultado for obtido chame o método da interface, passando o resultado:

```
listener.onResult(response);
```

Todo aquele código que está no construtor deve ser passado para um método próprio.
O construtor só deve ter código se este se destinar a definir o estado da instância.
A criação de um método que faça a leitura permitirá ler novos objectos sem a necessidade de criar uma nova instância da classe.

Também não "gosto" do nome da classe, talvez *ObjectLoader* seja melhor.

Fazendo as alterações ficará assim:

```
public class ObjectLoader {

    public interface ResultListener {
          public void onResult(JSONObject result);
    }  

    private ResultListener listener;

    public void Load(String URL, Context context, Map<String,String> params) {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        CustomJsonObjectRequest request = new CustomJsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //O resultado foi obtido
                    //Informe o listener
                    listener.onResult(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    volleyError.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    public void setResultListener(ResultListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Para utilizar a classe faça assim:

```
ObjectLoader objectLoader = new ObjectLoader();

objectLoader.setResultListener(new ResultListener(){
    @Override
    public void onResult(JSONObject result) {

        //Utilize aqui o resultado
    }
});
objectLoader.load(URL, context, params);
```

Comment: ótima explicação, era exatamente isso que eu precisava, implementei e funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, basta tornar o Objeto estático, e será "global".

```
private static JSONObject res;
```

Comment: O use de variáveis globais não é [recomendado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/2541)