# Android - Fragment Abre antes dos dados estarem prontos

Tags: android, web-service, api

Estou com problema de uma lista de objetos que vem em um JSON, eu consigo pegar os dados, ele chagam, eles devem ser apresentados num Fragment que possui um RecyclerView, o app abre e não mostra nada. Ao analisar os logs percebi que o Fragment abre antes dos dados estarem prontos.

Não sei como resolver isso.

Comment: Eu acredito que vc deveria pegar os dados já dentro do Fragment, posta o seu código que fica melhor

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/128515/2541) a uma situação idêntica.

Comment: Leia isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5510/132