# Funções estáticas em C

Tags: c, c++

Reparei que algumas bibliotecas utilizam funções e variáveis estáticas, como por exemplo `static int sum(lua_State *state)`.

Essa função pertence a uma biblioteca que será compilado para a linguagem *Lua*.

Mas também bibliotecas com chamadas por `dlsym` também possuem funções estáticas.

O que o uso de funções estáticas em bibliotecas proporciona de diferente com as funções não estáticas?

Comment: C tem métodos? Acredito que já deve haver uma questão sobre isso. Se estamos falando de OO, o que for declarado com o modificador estático executa no contexto da classe, e não do objeto.

Comment: Foi um pequeno erro de sintaxe, já fiz as correções

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C não possui métodos, só funções (a pergunta original falava em métodos). Apesar de C++ possuir métodos, só as funções são estáticas. O que se conhece por método estático em Java e C#, por exemplo é apenas uma função nessas linguagens.

Em C o `static` em função na verdade é uma forma parecida com `private`. Como não há classes, isso vale para o arquivo em que ela foi declarada, portanto só pode ser chamada ali naquele arquivo.

Variáveis estáticas significam que possuem estado global. Quando uma variável é declarada com `static` ela não é colocada nem na [*stack*, nem no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), e sim em uma área estática, portanto já fica reservada pelo compilador no executável. O [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101), claro, é por toda duração da aplicação. Isso é considerado [estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101) e pode trazer problemas se a aplicação tiver acesso concorrente, ou mesmo se não tomar certos cuidados.

Existem duas visibilidades possíveis quando a variável é estática.

Se ela estiver dentro da função só será visível ali. Toda vez que chamar a função essa variável terá o último valor que ela tinha na última chamada, ela não é destruída no final da sua execução.

Se estiver fora da função só será visível no arquivo, igual ao que acontece com a função.

Em C é raro usar variáveis estáticas. Funções são bem úteis para diminuir a visibilidade. Em C++ recomenda-se evitar ambos já que ela possui mecanismos melhores.

Não há utilidade especial para bibliotecas. Na verdade é o oposto, como torna aquilo privado, quem consumir a biblioteca nunca o acessará em condições normais. O máximo que dá para dizer é que ele impede o acesso, mas isso não é exclusivo para bibliotecas.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int externa = 1;

static void teste() {
    int x = 0;
    static int estatica = 0;
    x++;
    estatica++;
    printf("x = %d, estatica = %d, externa = %d\n", x, estatica, externa);
}
int main() {
    printf("externa = %d\n", externa);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) teste();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DwUmvJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/upmmjdok-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Static.c).

Experimente criar outro arquivo, e chamar a função `teste()` ou a variável `externa`. Não compilará. Obviamente precisaria de um *header*. Se incluir esse arquivo, aí ele fará parte do outro arquivo e compilará.