# Para que serve uma função static?

Tags: c, c++, funções, static

Para que serve uma função com a *keyword* `static`? Sei que declarar uma variável local como `static` dentro de uma função ela vai funcionar como se fosse uma variável global, e uma função `static` como funciona? E quando deve utilizar uma função `static`?

Achei que uma função como `static` se tiver dentro de um *loop* ela iria ser chamada apenas uma vez, porém não é isso que acontece no exemplo abaixo:

```
static void MostrarMensagem()
{
    printf("Mostrando uma mensagem de uma funcao static!\n");
}

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        MostrarMensagem();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `static` tem muitos significados dependendo de onde é utilizado, mas numa função global como esse exemplo funciona como se fosse invisível ao linker, e apenas local ao ficheiro.

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Funções estáticas em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/171417/3635)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Conhece linguagens classificadas como orientadas a objeto? Conhece o `private`?

É isso, quando se coloca o `static` na função está dizendo que ela só pode ser acessada dentro do próprio arquivo de código fonte dela, ela fica privada a esse código e não pode ser chamada por outras partes da aplicação. Em C++ não é recomendado usar.

Ela não tem a mesma semântica de Java ou C#. Quando usada em classe até tem comportamento semelhante, mas não idêntico. A semântica é igual ao C, a restrição de acesso é no arquivo e não na classe. A única diferença é que por estar na classe o nome completo da função inclui o nome da classe.

E `static` não é uma função como descrito na pergunta, é só um modificador de escopo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: E no caso em uma função que não faz parte de uma classe? Uma função global como o exemplo.

Comment: @cYeR é exatamente isto, conforme o que você colocou na pergunta.

Comment: Ah sim desculpe, eu li nas pressas, agora ficou claro. Obrigado

Comment: `static` é bastante usado em C++ para deixar o linkamento de declarações interno e não povoar o binário final com símbolos inutilizados. Tanto que existe `namespace {}` (namespace anônimo) para outros tipos de declarações/definições, como structs/classes. Temo que sua afirmação "Em C++ não é recomendado usar" esteja equivocada.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi veja o contexto da pergunta. E não sei o que `namespace` tem a ver com isto.

Comment: @Maniero O contexto da pergunta é claro, mas meu comentário refere-se a sua frase "Em C++ não é recomendado usar", sendo que tal afirmação não tem fundamentos. Sobre o namespace, [namespaces anônimos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces) dão linkagem interna para nomes declarados/definidos dentro de um. Tem o mesmo efeito de `static`, com o adicional de poder ser aplicado a mais nomes além de funções e variáveis globais. Apenas citei como um exemplo de que tal estratégia é usada e tem até mais suporte, o que nega sua afirmação.

Comment: Bom, você negou a sua afirmação no próprio parágrafo. Se tem um mecanismo melhor, se o mecanismo existente por compatibilidade com C não é necessário, você ainda acha que é recomendado usar? (a pergunta é retórica)

Comment: Bom, com MSVC, nomes têm linkagem interna por padrão caso não forem usados fora da sua unidade de tradução. É comum preferir linkagem interna pra coisas que serão usadas apenas dentro de uma UT, dá até mais oportunidades pro otimizador do compilador e mantém a funcionalidade encapsulada. Você pode manter boa parte do código com internal linkage e expor a funcionalidade através de algumas poucas funções com external linkage e manter a compatibilidade com C (não sei de onde veio a motivação da questão, mas aí está o contra-argumento em todo caso.)

Comment: Acredito que errei sobre o MSVC, isso é um caso diferente para nomes exportados pra DLL. Mas continuo na mesma posição com o resto do comentário.

Answer (score 7):

> Para que serve uma função com a keyword `static`?

`static` tem efeitos diferentes dependendo do seu uso e contexto. Ela pode ser encontrada em: definição de funções, variáveis globais e locais, membros de dado e funções membro. Como a pergunta trata do uso de `static` em funções, o escopo da resposta mantém-se no mesmo.

**Nota**: Estou levando em conta apenas [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) para elaborar a resposta. Alguns dos conceitos fundamentais continuam o mesmo em [c](/questions/tagged/c) (como a ligação dos nomes), porém aconselho que busque as diferenças.

> uma função `static` como funciona?

Pra entender isso, precisamos saber o que significa **ligação** (*linkage* em Inglês) em [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Um **nome** que refere-se a um objeto, referência, função, tipo, template, namespace, valor, ou qualquer outro nome encontrado em [[dcl.dcl]/declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:declaration), pode ter *ligação*.

Se um nome tem ligação, então ele refere-se a mesma entidade que o nome introduz em uma definição em algum outro escopo.

Por exemplo, em uma definição de função qualquer, como a seguir:

```
void foo() {
   // ...
}
```

O identificador `foo` é o nome, e a função toda é a entidade a qual o nome `foo` refere-se.

Se uma entidade (função, variável etc) é definida em vários escopos com o mesmo nome, mas não tendo uma ligação suficiente entre esses nomes, então várias instâncias da mesma entidade são geradas. Isto é, qual entidade é referenciada pelo nome dependerá do escopo no qual o nome foi usado.

Existem alguns tipos de ligação, sendo eles:

- Nenhuma ligação (*no linkage*)
- Ligação interna (*internal linkage*)
- Ligação externa (*external linkage*)

Segundo [[basic.link]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#2):

- Quando um nome tem **ligação externa**, a entidade denotada pelo nome pode ser acessada em outras Unidades de Tradução (UT) (lê-se informalmente como outros arquivos *.cpp*). Funções definidas em uma UT e usadas em outras UTs são um exemplo de tal nome (nome da função) e entidade (função em si).
- Quando um nome tem **ligação interna**, a entidade denotada pelo nome não pode ser acessada por outras UTs, mas pode ser acessada por outros escopos dentro da UT em que o nome foi declarado. Lembre-se desse em especial, pois esse caso está envolvido com o efeito do `static` em uma declaração de função.
- Quando um nome não tem ligação alguma, ou **nenhuma ligação**, a entidade denotada pelo nome não pode ser acessada nem fora do escopo onde ela está declarada. Variáveis locais são um exemplo, onde escopos mais fundos podem acessá-la, porém escopos de fora não.

Se você continuar lendo até [[basic.link]/3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3.1), encontrará o seguinte:

> 3. A **name** having namespace scope **has internal linkage if** it is the name of
>
> 3.1 a variable, function or function template that is **explicitly declared `static`**; or, […]

Ênfases minhas.

Traduzindo livremente, temos que qualquer nome com um escopo de namespace terá ligação interna se o nome de uma variável, função ou template de função é explicitamente declarada com `static`.

Finalmente, respondendo a pergunta, uma função declarada com `static` faz com que seu nome tenha ligação interna. Ou seja, a função só pode ser acessada por seu nome dentro da UT em que ela está declarada (isto é, informalmente, apenas dentro do arquivo *.cpp* onde ela reside). Alguns efeitos disso são:

- Garante que a função só pode ser usada dentro da UT em que a mesma reside;
- Consequentemente, seu nome não entrará em conflito com nomes de escopos fora da UT;
- Como isso tem a ver com ligação, o linker (programa final que calcula os símbolos de binários e liga-os) terá menos trabalho, pois o nome da função não é exportado;
- Dá mais possibilidades de otimização para compiladores, já que a função não pode ser usada fora da UT, ela pode ser totalmente otimizada.

Podemos ver um exemplo dos dois últimos itens [aqui](https://godbolt.org/g/5Zw9tm).

> quando deve utilizar uma função `static`?

Um de seus usos é manter a encapsulação de uma funcionalidade que uma UT oferece, onde os detalhes de como a funcionalidade é implementada não interessa ao usuário da interface. Apenas as funções expostas para uso teriam ligação externa, ao passo que os detalhes da implementação mantêm-se com ligação interna.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de uma definição de classe, a palavra-chave `static` declara membros que não estão vinculados a instâncias de classe.

Fora da definição de uma classe, ela tem um significado diferente: veja a [duração do armazenamento](http://devdocs.io/cpp/language/storage_duration).

---

Referência:

<sub>[DevDocs - C++ / static members](http://devdocs.io/cpp/language/static). Disponível em: http://devdocs.io/cpp/language/static. Acesso em: 01/12/2017.</sub>

Comment: Pelo código apresentado parece que o autor se refere a funções estáticas globais e não associadas a classes

Comment: Isac disse tudo, estou me referindo a uma função global estática não a classes.

Answer (score 1):

Opa!! vi várias respostas mais, inconsistentes com o que pergunta a pessoa inicial. A grande maioria aqui falou ou se referiu muito à POO - Progração Orientada o Objetos, nisto, todos estão certos. mas não foi isto que o iniciante da perguntar quis saber.
É o seguinte: em C (C puro), quando usamos uma função static, ela é chamada por outra função, assim: a "main" chama uma função1 e esta função1 chama outra função, a função 2. Esta outra função2, se declarada como "static", somente a função1 poderá chamar a função2, ela ficará restrita à função1. Exemplo: a 'Main" chama uma função para fazer uma soma, mas esta soma deverá ser feita com uns valores trocados (permutados), então a função de soma, antes de somar, chamará a função (static) de permutação e somente após retornar o resultado da função "static" é que ela efetuará a soma e entregará o resultado para a "main".