# Como criar uma variável acessível em todos os forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, singleton

No meu aplicativo terá um sistema de Login. Quero criar uma variável para armazenar o id do usuário que está logado, e que a mesma possa ser acessada em todos os outros formulários.

Preciso disso pois no meu banco de dados, cada tabela tem um campo chamado `usuario` que irá armazenar o nome do usuário que salvou o registro no banco.

Sempre que quero usar a variável em outro form, faço assim:

```
form meuLogin = new form();
meuLogin.idUsuario = tabela.id;
```

Então sempre crio um novo objeto do `formLogin` (que é onde a variável `idUsuario` fica armazenada) pra poder pegar a variável. Estou fazendo certo ou tem uma forma de fazer uma variável "global"?

Comment: Transformar ela em estática talvez? `public static string exemplo { get; set;}`. Contando que não haja concorrência por essa variável acredito que fique tudo bem. Só não sei se é melhor forma de se fazer isso.

Comment: Não deve criar variáveis globais. É possível fazer o que diz o comentário acima, mas pode ter problemas em ambientes concorrentes. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101. Falta mais contexto na pergunta para oferecer uma solução adequada, ou pelo menos dizer onde criar essa variável estática. Mas se entendi, isso não é nada certo.

Comment: alterei a pergunta

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Uma forma de resolver é usando um Singleton.

Com um [Singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) você pode criar uma classe estática que funcionaria como uma espécie de "Sessão do Usuário" e ali guardaria e recuperaria informações que o usuário precisa durante a vida da aplicação. Provavelmente você alimentaria os dados iniciais da sessão durante o *Login*.

```
    public sealed class Session
    {

        private static volatile Session instance;
        private static object sync = new Object();

        private Session() { }

        public static Session Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (sync)
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                        {
                            instance = new Session();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return instance;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Propriedade para o ID do usuario
        /// </summary>
        public int UserID { get; set; }

    }
```

Para ajustar o ID do usuário, bastaria fazer algo do tipo:

```
Session.Instance.UserID = 10;
```

Pare recuperar:

```
int ID = Session.Instance.UserID;
```

Você pode incrementar a classe adicionando novas propriedades que achar necessário.

Comment: muito bom ^^. me diz uma coisa: eu adiciono uma nova classe ao meu projeto ou coloco esse código em um form?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo adicione sempre as classes em arquivos separados no seu projeto. Isso facilita a manutenção junto ao seu controle de fontes.