# Por que utilizar extern?

Tags: c, declaração-de-variável, extern

De acordo com [o que pesquisei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keyword-in-c), a palavra reservada `extern` em C é usada para informar que a variável declarada está em algum outro local do programa. Uma variável `extern` é útil pela economia de memória, pois variáveis `extern`, embora declaradas, não são inicializadas. Porém, tenho visto em diversos lugares os dizeres de que "memória não é mais um problema nos dias atuais", e isso me faz indagar o porquê da utilização de `extern`. De modo geral, gostaria de saber se, entre os dois exemplos abaixo, há alguma forte razão para usar um ou outro.

**Código 1:**

*example.h*

```
extern int foo;
```

*example.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include "example.h"

int foo = 10;
void main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", foo);
}
```

**Código 2:**

*example.h*

```
int foo;
```

*example.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "example.h"

void main(void) {
    foo = 10;
    printf("%d\n", foo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "memória não é mais um problema nos dias atuais"

Isso é uma falácia. Se fosse verdade nunca fecharíamos um programa na vida.

Mesmo se não for exagerar ainda tem muitos motivos para economizar memória. Memória é lenta, por isso existem níveis de cache nos processadores. Cada nível é mais rápido, mas também tem menor capacidade. O cache mais rápido possui algo como 64KB e isso não muda faz muito tempo. Isso é memória suficiente? Quanto mais memória desperdiça mais chance de algo não estar no cache e portanto haverá perda de performance.

Uma coisa que eu sempre falo é que as pessoas soltam frases sem explicar o porquê. Normalmente dizem que isso é "boa prática", que é uma ótima forma de "vender uma ideia" que não faz sentido ou que a pessoa não domina.

Então toda vez que alguém afirmar algo e não dizer o porquê daquilo, ignore, pergunta o porquê e vá pesquisar outras fontes pra ver se aquilo faz sentido. Mas é preciso escolher as fontes e não é comum as pessoas saberem como fazer isso porque [quando ela sabe ela não precisa mais pesquisar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Esse caso é trágico porque você encontra muita, mas muita gente mesmo dizendo isso. E muita gente experiente. Só que não contam a estória toda e deixam as pessoas menos experientes acreditando em uma mentira ou pelo menos em uma semi verdade.

Nos dois exemplos já há um problema que está usando uma [variável global e isto deve ser evitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101). Pior, pelo menos nestes exemplo não há razão alguma para ter esta variável global. Então se resolver esse problema não há necessidade do `extern`. Mas se insistir nisso não é só questão de economizar memória, é questão dizer que é a mesma variável. Se é a mesma, você não está colocando ambas declarações no mesmo local de armazenamento de memória para economizar memória, está fazendo isso porque é a mesma coisa, não pode existir dois.

Hoje o `extern` é usado mais para funções que estão em outra unidade de compilação.

Tem quase um livro sobre o assunto em [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/221800). O resumo ali é: se você não é uma fera em programação não use `extern` em variáveis, ou globais em geral.

Comment: Aparentemente, faltou detalhar melhor os códigos de exemplo que coloquei. Entendo que as variáveis globais são usadas em projetos maiores, precisamente quando vários fontes precisam acessá-las - e foi isso que quis dizer com os códigos. Minha dúvida era se, em projetos grandes, quando vários fontes precisam acessar uma variável, haveria alguma razão por optar entre o código 1 ou o código 2. Mas sua menção ao cache L1 me fez repensar sobre o aproveitamento de memória, e a referência do "livro em resposta" está clareando um pouco mais as ideias. Grato.

Answer (score 1):

O uso da palavra `extern` é utilizada quando se deseja utilizar uma variável compartilhada em diversos arquivos.
Um uso muito conhecido é `stdin`.
Se colocar o não `extern` no arquivo `.h` pode ocorrer um erro quando for feita a link-edição ou pode haver a duplicação da variável, perdendo, assim, o proposito de ser uma variável compartilhada entre módulos.
No exemplo citado não faz diferença, porque é apenas um arquivo `.h` e um arquivo `.c`.