# Vantagem em dar null em uma variável no Android

Tags: java, android, null, declaração-de-variável, garbage-collector

Atribuir o valor de `null` em uma variável no Android pode melhorar o desempenho do aplicativo?

Até onde sei, em Java temos o Garbage Collector, e no Android, o ciclo de atividade das Activities e Fragments.

#### Problema:

- Em uma classe uma variável local será limpa quando? Se der `null` nela, pode ajudar na questão do desempenho do aplicativo?
- Em uma variável global, se der `null` nela, sabendo que ela não será mais útil, irá ajudar no desempenho do aplicativo?
- Em variáveis de classe, dar `null` sempre que não for mais usar, pode melhorar no desempenho do aplicativo?

Pesquisando, encontrei isto sobre variáveis e métodos estáticos:

> Use métodos estáticos
>
> Você criou um método e ele é totalmente independente da classe onde ele está, o que você está esperando para tornar seu método estático?
>
> **Tornando um método estático você está dizendo para o compilador, ou interpretador, que o conteúdo do método só precisa estar na memória durante sua execução, não enquanto a classe estiver instanciada, ou seja, você libera a memória das variáveis locais após a execução do método**. Além dessa maravilha, você não necessita de uma instância para executar um método estático, você invoca o método direto de sua classe, livrando sua memória de ter que armazenar atributos da classe que você não irá utilizar.
>
> Use com moderação, não troque todos seus métodos para estático só para ganhar performance, senão o feitiço pode virar contra o feiticeiro. Métodos não estáticos tem o privilégio de compartilhar atributos, evitando de armazenar mais de uma vez a mesma informação."

- No Android, seguir a mesma prática também é sinônimo de performance? Fazendo isso, eu não estaria "guardando" memória sem usar?
- Fonte: http://www.brunonardini.com.br/desenv-back-end/5-boas-praticas-para-deixar-o-codigo-otimizado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então

> Em uma classe, uma variável local será limpa quando?

Quer dizer em um método? Não precisa a não ser que ele tenha seríssimos problemas.

> Em uma variável global, se der null nela, sabendo que ela não será mais útil, irá ajudar no desempenho do aplicativo?

Sim, ajuda, mas, se possível, mude esse padrão para não precisar fazer isso.

> Em variáveis de classe, dar null sempre que não for mais usar, pode melhorar no desempenho do aplicativo?

Talvez, mas também deveria mudar o padrão.

> No Android, seguir a mesma prática também é sinônimo de performance? Fazendo isso, eu não estaria "guardando" memória sem usar?

Ser estático nada tem a ver com performance, pelo menos não diretamente. Até pode ter um ganho ínfimo na chamada, mas não é relevante.

Métodos estáticos não guardam memória sem usar. Variáveis estáticas podem **ajudar** fazer isso eventualmente.

## Explicações

De forma geral a vantagem é zero, pelo menos se o código é bem feito.

De fato anular uma variável pode fazer com que uma referência deixe de existir e um objeto que está ano [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) pode ser coletado pelo GC a qualquer momento liberando memória.

Isso não é garantido porque o objeto pode ter outras referências que ainda o segure vivo na memória. Mas anulando a variável já está fazendo sua parte.

Anular uma variável local em um método não faz sentido, porque todas elas são automaticamente anuladas no fim do método. Faria sentido se o método fica pendurado em uma *thread* por alguma razão e por uma péssima razão fica segurando referências que não deveria. Isso na verdade é erro de programação, conserte o erro em vez de fazer gambiarra tentando librar a referência. Não importa se o método é estático ou não, eles em si não são problemáticos.

Em uma classe um membro pode segurar uma referência quando na verdade não deveria. Na verdade em instâncias é menos comum porque em determinado momento a instância irá morrer e todas suas variáveis são automaticamente anuladas nesse momento. O que pode ocorrer é um objeto sobreviver mais do que o esperado e isso provavelmente é um erro de programação também e deveria ser solucionado.

Mas se o objeto dura muito mesmo então deveria repensar a estrutura do objeto. Talvez ele tenha uma variável segurando uma referência para outro objeto que não deveria estar ali.

Isto pode ocorrer com membros estáticos de uma classe que tem durabilidade de toda a aplicação. Se uma variável estática deve ter seu valor anulado, deveria repensar se a variável deveria ser estática ou até existir.

Membros estáticos podem ser [problema por causa do estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101), mas eles podem ser úteis se souber o que está fazendo. Quase sempre que está precisando anulá-lo não sabe o que está fazendo. O fato da variável estática ficar lá o tempo todo não é um problema porque ela tem um pequeno valor sempre, ou é um tipo por valor ou é uma referência. O problema dela pode ser a concorrência ou o fato de segurar uma referência por mais tempo do que deveria. Mas há casos para seu uso. Quem entende o funcionamento das coisas e não segue "boas práticas" cegamente sabe disso. Sempre estude antes de usar algo.

Note que anular uma variável é diferente de trocar o seu valor. Quando colocamos outra referência para uma variável o objeto que antes era pontado por esta variável perde esse apontamento e possivelmente poderá ser coletado.

Até existem alguns raros casos onde anular a variável pode ser útil, mas é raro, quase sempre tem forma melhor de fazer isso e deveria corrigir o problema certo.

Mesmo que anule uma variável e o objeto referenciado não tenha outras referências nada garante que o GC colete o objeto em algum momento. Não que o GC seja imprevisível, só não se sabe quando ele rodará. Só o tempo não é determinístico e a aplicação pode encerrar antes de uma coleta ocorrer. Mas se uma coleta for disparada e o objeto não tiver referências ele será coletado com certeza, não é uma coisa louca que ninguém sabe se ocorrerá ou não.

Falou em boa prática eu torço o nariz. Em geral a pessoa está reproduzindo o que leu sem entender aquilo ou está vendendo uma ideia sem querer instruir o leitor.

O texto citado tem vários erros, alguns graves e é o oposto da realidade, a citação em negrito na pergunta por exemplo, não confiaria nele. Ocorre na maioria do conteúdo da internet.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O mesmo vale para os métodos estáticos? (fugindo um pouco)

Comment: Eu estava justamente editando isso.

Comment: Eu achei muito bom e claro aquilo que você escreveu. Só não ficou claro pra mim a parte dos métodos estáticos. Então métodos estáticos não são tão bons pra serem escritos, correto? Porém, isso não tem a ver com memória. As variáveis são limpas também, assim que se é usado um método estático? Pois de certa forma, fica mais "eficiente" não instanciar uma classe e chamar o método estático, do que instanciar ela e chamar o método, não?

Comment: São sim, desde que saiba o que está fazendo. Achei que ficou claro quando eu disse que sempre prefiro eles. Só que em muitos casos eles não fazem sentido, métodos que precisam operar na instância não podem ser estáticos. Todos os métodos limpam as variáveis quando terminam, isto tudo está na resposta. Limpar a variável não é limpar o objeto automaticamente, isto é trabalho do GC. Certamente é mais eficiente não instanciar uma classe, mas nem sempre podemos fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Em poucas palavras: não, não vai resolver.

Em todo tempo de experiência que eu tenho, a JVM (Dalvik/Art), e o Garbage collector do android são totalmente independentes e você não controla sua execução. Trocando em miúdos, são "cachorro louco" (independentes e imprevisíveis)

Passar null para uma variável, independe se ela é da classe, global ou local, vai indicar que ela deve ser limpa pelo Garbage Collectork, mas não indica que vai ocorrer naquele exato momento.

Além do que o próprio sistema vai limpar os recursos do aplicativo quando ele precisar de memória (estando em background).

Um ponto sobre métodos estáticos é que eles não são os melhores, variaveis então nem se fala. Pelo meu conhecimento, as variáveis estáticas são alocadas na memória e ficam lá disponíveis até serem explicitamente removidas, seja pelo sistema operacional ou pela execução do programa.

A melhor forma de se otimizar um aplicativo no android, é entender o ciclo de vida, e como o mesmo armazena as informações entre transferências de intent, e salvamento de estado. Além de diminuir operações custosas para threads principais e uso de tarefas/services em background para operações mais demoradas.