# Por que usamos parâmetros/argumentos nas funções?

Tags: python, funções, parâmetros

Se uma função, consegue enxergar variáveis de ambiente, ou seja, consegue enxergar variáveis definidas no corpo do programa principal. Por que passamos parâmetros e argumentos para essa função?

No exemplo abaixo, escrevi um exemplo em Python, na primeira, uso a função sem parâmetros e na segunda, com parâmetros, e ambas apresentam o mesmo resultado.

```
def calculadora ():
    return n1 + n2 
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
print(calculadora())

def calculadora (n10,n20):
    return n10 + n20 
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
print(calculadora(n1,n2))
```

Comment: Não existe apenas o escopo global da aplicação, você logo verá que existem dieferentes escopos como de pacotes, classes, funções,etc, vai depender da linguagem que você irá utilizar. Outro ponto é que função serve para reaproveitar código então, se você utilizar da primeira forma que você fez, você sempre terá que usar as variáveis n1 e n2 como entrada desta função, o que é ruim  pois você terá que ficar sobreescrevendo essas variáveis e assim correndo o risco de sobreescrever algum dado importante.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 7):

## Funções e parâmetros

Funções não são invenções de programação. Ao contrário do que percebo que as pessoas acham, funções existem na matemática, não sei porque razão as pessoas não se lembram disso.

Funções em matemática possuem parâmetros para permitir a comunicação com quem precisa da função. Não teria porque em programação se adotar o mecanismo da função e fazer diferente.

Lembrando que em matemática, em problemas simples a função poderia pegar um dado fora dela, até porque o papel aceita tudo.

Mas claro que não é assim na programação só porque resolveram fazer igual, é extremamente útil que seja assim.

Imagine se não tivesse parâmetros, a função teria pouca utilidade, ela só poderia fazer algo muito simples, não poderia fazer algo baseado em uma situação diferente em cada chamada. A não ser que pegue informação solta no papel.

Aí você mostra que funciona sem parâmetros. Mas isso é uma anomalia, é errado. É algo que só linguagens que gostam de efeitos colaterais, que foram pensadas para escrever pequenos *scripts*, permitem fazer. Funções não deveriam permitir esse tipo de coisa e a linguagem que permite deturpa isso. Em programação séria, se a linguagem permite a pessoa pode fazer duas coisas: a) não usar a anomalia; b) mudar de linguagem que seja mais criteriosa.

Nenhum problema e abusar disso em *scripts* simples, mas quando a pessoa começa fazer sistemas sérios ela não pode nem cogitar usar algo assim, vira uma bagunça.

Também não é problema capturar uma variável em um mecanismo de [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101), mas aí o escopo é muito mais contido e tem uma motivação, não é gambiarra.

Em sistemas importantes você começa ter muitas variáveis, vários caminhos a executar e precisa ter o controle de tudo de forma bem organizada, e para isso quanto mais as cosias forem divididas e contidas, melhor.

Se quer saber mais pode estudar:

- [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101)
- [Diferença entre escopo global e local](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/450218/101)
- [Quais problemas um estado global pode acarretar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101)
- [Como mudar o valor de uma variável por meio de função no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226738/101)

## Aprender o certo

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Então aprenda os conceitos corretos, não acredite no que funciona, porque pode ser coincidência ou pode ser até aceitável em certo cenário, mas não em outros. Aprender se baseando na tentativa e visão do resultado é aprender errado.

Se comunique apenas pelo parâmetro e retorno, a não ser em códigos muitos simples, e mesmo assim só depois de dominar a programação, porque se fizer isso enquanto está aprendendo se acostumará fazer assim, já que parece mais fácil (e o preço vem depois, programadores inexperientes não conseguem ver isso), as pessoas gostam do que parece mais fácil e sempre se metem em encrencas por causa disto.

## Variável global dominui a legibilidade

É muito fácil se perder o aproveitamento de variáveis globais, então, não é só usar parâmetros, nunca as use, mesmo que possa. Faça de conta que a linguagem não permite isso.

```
n1 = 10
n2 = 20
def calculadora (n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2 
n1 = 10
n2 = 20
print(calculadora(1, 2))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MbNdpO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yvabeuel-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/GlobalScope.py).

O que isto imprime? Olhando por cima é intuitivo? Imagine em um código maior...

Answer (score -4):

Bom, na menor resposta possível, os parâmetros captam informações de escopo local, aquela situação em que você chama ela dentro de uma outra função