# Quando posso usar static na classe?

Tags: java, arraylist, static

Sei que o uso de métodos `static` deve ser evitado, por isto estou com uma duvida  e não sei se é certo implementar uma `ArrayList` como `static`, ela é acessada por varias classes e contem dados de todo programa (só desejo uma onica lista), neste caso tudo bem em usar `static`?

Os métodos desta classe (fazem manipulação e leitura da `ArrayList`) também devem ser `static` ou devo instanciar o objeto quando usar?

Um trecho do código:

```
public class DadosSalvos {

    static private ArrayList <Dados> dados = new ArrayList <>();

    public static void setDados(ArrayList dados) {
        DadosSalvos.dados = dados;
    }

    public static ArrayList getDados() {
        return dados;
    }

}
```

Comment: Existe uma lista sincronizada em Java, que deve ser melhor pra isso do que arraylist, só não me lembro o nome agora.

Comment: java.util.Vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Sei que o uso de métodos `static` devem ser evitados

Por que? Regrinha boba dita por alguém? Se tem motivo para usar não tem motivo algum para não usar. Na verdade ele é preferível por programadores pragmáticos sempre que ele pode ser usado sem problemas.

> implementar uma `ArrayList` como static, ela é acessada por varias classes e contem dados de todo programa

Se a aplicação envolve concorrência tem que tratar adequadamente. Se não envolve e só deve ter uma lista dessa para toda aplicação não tem grande problema não. Claro que em aplicação complexa pode ser um problema. De fato [estado global é um problema e deve ser evitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101), mas em aplicações complexas.

> Os métodos desta classe (fazem manipulação e leitura da `ArrayList`) também devem ser static ou devo instanciar o objeto quando usar?

Geralmente métodos que acessam estado estático deves ser estáticos, só não vi utilidade para eles neste caso.

Em aplicações simples um monte de coisa que dizem que não pode na verdade pode, por exemplo acessar campos ([que as pessoas chamam erroneamente de atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)) sem *getters* e *setters*.

Não se pode decorar regras e tentar aplicar, tem que entender o motivo de tudo o que vai usar e saber quando usar e quando não usar. Se só souber a regra nunca conseguirá decidir quando usar.

Dependendo do contexto eu faria completamente diferente, mas assim simples eu faria só isto:

```
public class DadosSalvos {
    static ArrayList <Dados> dados = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/StaticMember.java).

Talvez nem inicializasse nada, talvez eu arquitetasse de forma bem diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que precisa de uma classe controladora. Procure sobre o padrão de projeto *Singleton*. Entretanto, Singleton é considerado um antipadrão, justamente por utilizar *static* e aumentar a dependência de classes que não estão associadas. Então, se quiser utilizar algo um pouco mais elegante, recomendo estudar sobre *Injeção de Dependência*, inclusive presente em vários frameworks para diversas LP's