# Condição no "if" do PHP para saber se o comando MySQL enviado deu certo ou não

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, if

Eu gostaria de saber qual condição colocar dentro do `if` usando o PHP com banco de dados MySQL para que seja possível saber se o comando retornou algum erro ou não.

Como visto no código abaixo, eu quero deletar um usuário do banco de dados. No entanto, não sei qual condição colocar no `if` de modo que ele saiba se o comando deu certo ou não.

```
Class Usuario
{
    private $pdo;
    public $msgErro="";
    public function conectar($nome,$host,$usuario,$senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        try 
        {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$nome.";host=".$host,$usuario,$senha);
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            $msgErro = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function deletar($email,$senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE $email = :e AND $senha = :s");
        $sql->bindValue(":e",$email);
        $sql->bindValue(":s",md5($senha));
        $sql->execute();
        if ()
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Apenas coloquei a Classe e a função conectar para complementar o código, mas o problema é no método `deletar()`. Note que depois de mandar executar o comando com o `$sql->execute();` há no código um `if` vazio. Gostaria de saber qual condição colocar lá dentro.

Comment: if ($sql->execute()) { //true }

Comment: $value = $sql->execute(); if($value){//true}else{//false}

Comment: referencia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661863/pdo-mysql-how-to-know-if-insert-was-successful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algumas observações antes de responder o que quer. Então algumas pessoas podem pular para a solução lá embaixo, essa primeira parte é só para quem quer fazer certo e não apenas funcionar.

Não faz o menor sentido usar esse `global $pdo`. [Evite global tanto quanto pode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101), e só use se souber bem o que está fazendo. Nesse caso específico é pior porque está fazendo algo que não é global ser e não tem necessidade. Na verdade não use qualquer mecanismo sem antes dominar como ele funciona, vai evitar muita dor de cabeça. Isso é especialmente importante porque esse código tem vários problemas por usar o que não conhece.

Seu código provavelmente sofre de [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/101). Pode ser que o dado foi sanitizado antes, mas duvido, essa não é a forma correta de fazer. Sua aplicação ficará vulnerável.

Não sei se minimizo dizendo para não se preocupar, a gente vê uns 80% dos códigos assim, porque isso é terrível, está quase todo mundo fazendo errado. Não é totalmente culpa das pessoas que fazem, mas é um pouco. Quase todo lugar na internet está ensinando errado. Aqui mesmo no nosso site que classificamos conteúdo acontece muito isso. No começo não acontecia, não deixávamos passar nada que ensinasse errado. Agora passa muita, em geral a maioria das respostas ensinam isso errado e a quantidade de problema é tão grande quem nem conseguimos mais lidar com todos, até porque a maioria dos usuários não liga se estão ensinando errado. É um pouco culpa da pessoa que pega a informação errada porque ela não deveria em confiar em informações na internet, essa atitude fará ela cometer erros a vida inteira induzidas por pessoas bem ou mal intencionadas. Eu sei que isso ficou um pouco longo, fora do tópico, mas é o melhor que posso te ensinar para tudo na vida.

[A esmagadora maioria das pessoas adotam PDO por motivos errados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401729/101). Não sei se deveria adotar, ainda que não seja o fim do mundo.

Não sei se deveria adotar classes, é pouco código para eu afirmar, mas parece que essa classe está mal estruturada, então usar um mecanismo do jeito errado não é muito bom, e se está treinando, acostumará fazer errado pro resto da vida. Conexão misturando com os casos do que seria o usuário, parece muito errado. Pelo menos não fez herança pra piorar mais ainda, a solução talvez não seja ficar sem.

Não é sobre o código, mas quase sempre deletar algo do banco de dados é algo errado a se fazer. Inativar costuma ser melhor. Em códigos reais isso tem vasta consequência.

Enfim, eu gosto de ajudar de verdade as pessoas, mas essa pergunta não é sobre isso não é o caso de ir a fundo. A solução é sempre não usar o que não sabe fazer certo.

Algumas pessoas não gostam deste tipo de resposta porque não foquei só no que foi perguntado, mas deixar a pessoa aprender errado é muito pior. O SOpt seria muito mais útil para as pessoas se todas respostas fizessem esses alertas e teríamos códigos melhores, menos perguntas precisariam ser fechadas.

## A solução

Por fim, sem falar de problemas menores, a solução mais óbvia para fazer o que deseja é colocar pelo menos o `execute()` dentro de um `try catch` para pegar o erro já que essa opção está ligada e já usou em outro ponto do código. Porém tem um jeito mais fácil:

```
return $sql->execute();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/Executed.php).

Só isso. [Se você olhar a documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), e só deveria usar algo depois de ler a documentação daquilo e entender por completo, diz que essa função retorna se a operação foi bem sucedida ou não, que é exatamente o que deseja.

Só que isso não funciona bem se optar por receber os erros como exceções.

Mesmo que quisesse verificar alguma coisa não faz sentido usar um `if` para entregar um valor `true` ou `false`, o `if` já é esse valor, é um código redundante.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu estou bem no começo, haja vista que é a primeira vez que conecto algum arquivo php com um banco de dados. Tenho certeza que deve estar totalmente fora dos padrões ou normas. Apenas estou tentando aprender. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 1):

O método execute da classe `PDOStatement` retorna um boleano, logo você pode checar o resultado desse método no if. Segue o código:

```
 $execute = $sql->execute();
    
 if ($execute){
      return true;
 }
 
 return false;
```

Comment: isso não vai dar erro no php7? Acho que tem de usar ``if (isset($foo)){}``

Comment: @BRABO Que `$foo`?

Comment: ``if (isset($execute)){}``