# Como fazer uma conexão com banco de dados utilizando o padrão de projeto Singleton

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, design-pattern

Bom eu faço muitas aplicações web, onde todas elas eu utilizo banco de dados, e toda vez que vou  fazer um novo projeto, eu crio um arquivo responsável por fazer as consultas com o banco de dados(CRUD).

Só que eu quero mudar isso, quero fazer um arquivo onde tenho todas essa consultas com o banco de dados, e queria utilizar o padrão de projetos Singleton.

E queria uma ajuda de como montar esse arquivo.

Comment: Recomendo esta questão como leitura adicional: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18860/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-singleton/18933#18933

Comment: Vídeo falando sobre Singleton em PHP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHKOLn0Lx7A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O pattern `Singleton` consiste em sempre retornar a mesma instância de determinada classe a qualquer ponto da aplicação.

Isso é feito limitado o acesso ao método construtor e retornando a instância através de um método estático, ou seja, um método que você pode chamar sem instanciar a classe.

Segue uma implementação rápida:

```
class BancoDeDados
{
    // Instância da classe
    private static $instance = null;
    private $conn;

    // Construtor privado: só a própria classe pode invocá-lo
    private function __construct()
    {
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pswd = "root";
        $db = "banco";

        try {
            $this->conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pswd, $db);
            $this->conn->set_charset('utf8');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die("Erro na conexão com MySQL! " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    // método estático
    static function getInstance()
    {
        // Já existe uma instância?
        if (self::$instance == NULL)
            self::$instance = new BancoDeDados();   // Não existe, cria a instância 
        return self::$instance;                     // Já existe, simplesmente retorna
    }

    // Previne o uso de clone
    private function __clone() {}
}

// Usando a classe
$db = BancoDeDados::getInstance();

// Você não poderá fazer isso por causa do construtor privado:
$db = new BancoDeDados();
```

A partir dai, desenvolva os métodos para acesso a sua classe de banco.

Comment: Esse código me ajudou bastante, mas como mencionei, quero fazer operações CRUD. Eu devo fazer essas funções estáticas também? Ex: static function updateDb().....

Comment: Não, essas operações você cria normalmente em métodos públicos.

Answer (score 4):

> **Singleton**
>
> Intenção:
>
> Garantir uma única instância e prover um ponto de acesso global
>   a ela durante todo o ciclo de uso da aplicação

Primeiro, singleton não é para uso de banco de dados. Se precisar usar múltiplas bases de dados, o que acontece? Singleton se torna um problema. Se precisa de um `pattern` para `database`, procure por `DAO` *(por exemplo)*. E caso não use ainda, procure trabalhar com `PDO` no `PHP`, pois é muito mais seguro, flexível e atende bem.

Segundo, singleton no `PHP` é inviável. O motivo? A cada requisição `http` feita o `PHP` destrói automaticamente todas as instâncias. Seja qual for a linguagem ou tecnologia usada, qualquer situação em que a resposta destrua a instância o `singleton` deixa de fazer sentido, pois é gerada uma nova instância a cada requisição.

Ao usar um `pattern` você precisa entender bem a qual problema ele se propõe a resolver, se ele se encaixa na resolução do seu problema e se o ambiente em que você irá aplicá-lo permitirá que esse propósito seja cumprido. Qualquer coisa diferente disso você deve evitar o uso, pois ao invés de solucionar o seu problema ele acabará criando muitos outros.

Comment: Dalton, singleton realmente não é o melhor pattern para isso. Porém não esqueça que cada caso é um caso e cabe ao expertise do programador avaliar o seu uso.  Como você disse, o objetivo do pattern é eliminar o problema de múltiplas instâncias. se você tem esse problema numa aplicação (criação de varias instâncias de um mesmo objeto, mesmo numa mesma requisição php) seu uso é sim benéfico.

Comment: Um caso de uso que ocorreu comigo. Tenho um código legado que estou trabalhando. Sua migração completa demorará alguns meses e o ambiente de prod estava sofrendo com grande consumo de memoria entre as requisições. Precisava fazer algo. Analisando alguns trechos de código descobri que a classe do banco era instanciada até 8 vezes por requisição! Nesse caso o singleton foi minha solução. O apliquei na classe do banco, dei um replace all nas instancias da classe e resolvi o problema do consumo de memoria em menos de 15 minutos. Fiz algo de errado em aplicar singleton ?

Comment: É benéfico quando bem aplicado. Singleton na maioria das vezes não é usado corretamente. Em PHP seria viável com o uso de um web socket onde a instância não seria destruída, assim você teria de fato uma única instância durante todo o ciclo de uso da aplicação. Singleton perde o sentido se a instância for destruída. É importante frisar que escrever um singleton corretamente é totalmente diferente de implementá-lo corretamente, por isso é muito importante que se conheça bem a motivação dos patterns e seus casos de uso.

Comment: Sobre o seu caso de uso, acredito que o pattern Registry seria o ideal.

Comment: http://avedo.net/101/the-registry-pattern-and-php/ - pelo que entendi o resgistry é uma coleção de instancias, que retorna sempre a mesma instancia de um objeto. Você está sugerindo que eu crie mais uma classe em um código legado para garantir que eu vá receber sempre a mesma instancia de um único objeto?

Comment: Registry é como uma caixa que guarda instâncias e usa a instância específica que você guardou quando requisitada. Lembre-se que fazer funcionar é diferente de usar corretamente, singleton funcionou e sabemos que não é a melhor solução para esse caso de uso. O que sugiro é refatorar o código legado e usar os patterns corretamente. Se não for possível, ainda que ache que terá um pouco mais de trabalho com o Registry, é o que recomendo, afinal quanto mais bed smells forem adicionados, pior a aplicação ficará, ainda que pareça uma solução eficiente no momento.

Comment: Já estou migrando o código legado em outro projeto. Irei utilizar data mapper para abstração com banco. Devo perder mais tempo com o código legado se o singleton resolve o problema?

Comment: A decisão é sua, se você precisar utilizar mais um banco no código legado você terá mais uma dor de cabeça com a utilização do singleton.

Comment: Não é o caso. O código legado não sofrerá novas melhorias.

Comment: Ok, outra coisa: Sem o private function __clone() você não garantirá que o seu singleton possua uma única instância durante a execução do fluxo, pois ele poderá ser clonado.

Comment: Realmente esqueci do clone. Editei a resposta, Obrigado!

Comment: Dalton, por favor, confira o guia [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201), pois seu uso da formatação de código é equivocado. Valeu!