# Crud generico com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

A parte da conexão está pronta:

```
<?php

/*
* O padrão Singleton
*/

abstract class Conexao {

const USER = "root";
const PASS = "";

private static $instance = null;

private static function conectar() {

    try {   ##Tenta conectar ao banco se não funcionar cai no catch
        if (self::$instance == null): ##se não existir conexão com PDO receber a new   PDO() | a conexão
            $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phpoo";
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, self::USER, self::PASS);
        endif;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage(); #
    }
    return self::$instance; ## se ja exixtir uma conexão ele retorna a conexão
}

protected static function getDB() {
    return self::conectar();
} 

}
```

criar uma classe Abstrata.php(fazer o CRUD Generico aqui) com:

```
<?php

abstract class Abstrata extends Conexao {

protected function listar($where) {
    //implemente aqui seu código padrão para fazer update
    $db = parent::getDB();
}

protected function alterar($id, $data) {
     //implemente aqui seu código padrão para fazer update
    $db = parent::getDB();
}

protected function deletar($id) {
    //implemente aqui seu código padrão para fazer delete
    $db = parent::getDB();
}

protected function cadastrar($data) {
    //implemente aqui seu código padrão para fazer insert
    $db = parent::getDB();
    //outros códigos
}

}
```

E deposi só chamar os métodos externos para as demais classes.
Será que jeito de implementar assim ?

Comment: Poderia colocar seu código e descrever a dificuldade/problema que está enfrentando? aproveite e veja como funciona o site na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Como eu faça pra inserir codigo aqui?

Comment: Ok. codigo na tela

Comment: Sinceridade, qual é a pergunta @kall.max? não entendi, se puder explicar?

Comment: Esse CRUD que estou desenvolvendo está Orietado a Objeto gostaria de fazer algumas modificações nele pra ficar mais seguro usando PDO, ou seja emplementando PDO nele.
Isso que não to conseguindo.

Comment: Eu acho que isso é um código pronto ao qual está pedindo para alguém modificá-lo conforme suas necessidades. Queira seguir o conselho de @perdeu e formular de forma que possamos te ajudar em cima do que você tentou fazer.

Comment: Eu não to pedindo pra modificar,
e sim pra me auxiliarem em convertê-lo pra PDO.
Um melhoramento,
Quanto ao codigo acima é de usuabilidade minha, 
O fiz, mas fazendo um curso na internet vi os beneficios do PDO e lendo a documentação do http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php, obeservei seu grau de benefico e usuabilidade decidir migrar para tal por esse motivo pedid ajuda aqui.

Comment: É complicado adaptar sem saber como você vai usar a classe... Ponha um exemplo de uso que você usa.

Comment: estou escrenvendo aqui e tentando desenvolver.
Vou colocar sim. So concluir umas coisas aqui.
Pois o que estou tentando desenvolver é um CRUD generico com PDO em cima desse OO já exixtente, estou tentando adaptar. Eu consigo!! eu acredito.

Comment: [Dê um olhada nessa questão pois pode servir](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28178/13412)

Comment: Agora vou fazer a classe onde tera as classes CRUD. E posterior apenas fazer as chamadas onde eu quiser fazendo a instâncias.
Poderiam me dar um exemplo de um insert ou select generico com PDO, quem souber.

Comment: Você quer criar um Model Persistence Genérico, aonde o mesmo grava altera exclui lista conforme  passagem de uma configuração?

Comment: @kall.max na minha opinião esse é o tipo de código que não devemos perder tempo programando! Qual valor de negócio isso está trazendo para o seu sistema? Recomendo a utilização de pacotes prontos para esse tipo de situação, na minha resposta tentei ensinar como utilizar um DBAL pronto, caso tenha dificuldades e interesse deixe um comentário

Answer (score 3):

Muito sensato o que você está querendo fazer, mas a minha primeira dica é: só faça isso por motivos didáticos. Calma, já explico porque, exitem pacotes prontos que fazem o que você quer e de uma maneira muito boa e testada e com suporte da comunidade, para DBA Layer eu utilizo o [Doctrine DBAL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/) que vou ensinar a utilizar aqui.

## Instalação

Essa é a instalação utilizando [composer](https://getcomposer.org) (recomendo). Adicione a seguinte dependência em seu composer.json e atualize suas dependências.

```
"require": {
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.4"
    },
```

O Doctrine DBAL já está configurado para funcionar com o autoloader do composer, então você não precisa fazer NADA além disso para instalar. Fácil não ?

## Utilizando

Agora você está com um DBA Layer instalado, você só precisar configurar os dados da conexão para poder sair utilizando.

### Configurando conexão

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;

$config = new Configuration();

$connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'mydb',
    'user' => 'user',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
);

$conn = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
```

### Realizando updates

```
$conn->delete('user', array('id' => 1));
// DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ? (1)

$conn->insert('user', array('username' => 'jwage'));
// INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?) (jwage)

$conn->update('user', array('username' => 'jwage'), array('id' => 1));
// UPDATE user (username) VALUES (?) WHERE id = ? (jwage, 1)
```

### Realizando consultas

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM user');
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();
```

### Realizando consultas com query builder

O [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) é um recurso muito bom, ele QUASE que abstrai o SQL, isso torna seu muito mais fácil de trocar de base caso haja tal necessidade. Segue alguns exemplos:

```
$queryBuilder = $conn->createQueryBuilder();

$queryBuilder
    ->select('id', 'name')
    ->from('users')
    ->where('email = ?')
    ->setParameter(0, $userInputEmail)
;
//SELECT


$queryBuilder
    ->insert('users')
;
//INSERT

$queryBuilder
    ->update('users')
;
//UPDATE

$queryBuilder
    ->delete('users')
;
//DELETE
```

Tudo o que está aqui se encontra na [documentação oficial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/index.html) que é muito boa!

Comment: +1 pelo conteúdo, mas acho que é valida a vontade do autor em criar algo próprio e pode servir como base didática.

Comment: Muito bom.
Vou procurar fazer a instalação, pelo que você falou parece ser muito simples e facil trabalhar com ele.
Quanto a criação eu gostaria de fazer pra entender o processos de um CRUD para uso continuo em meus futuros sistemas PHP.
Estou fortemente analizando agora o que será mais ultil e agil pra eu hoje, em questão de agilidade.
Acredito que está classe será uma mão na roda.

Comment: Legal, é importante fazer para entender aprender, se bem que, você pode aprender utilizando pacotes de terceiro também. Eu criei um micro framework que me ajudou bastante a entender padrões e OO, mas para uso profissional recomendo fortemente não reinventar a roda.

Comment: Deixa eu só entender uma coisa, composer é uma dependecia para o php. O pacote Doctrine deve ser baixado e jogado no projeto para ser chamado certo, assim como o QueryBuilder. Ou seja coloco todos no projeto e faça a chamada normalmente. Que eu puder entender na explicação. Está correto ?

Comment: Primeira coisa que tens que fazer é instalar o composer. Para isso vá até a raiz do seu site e execute o seguinte comando $php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php

Comment: Como trabalho com maquinas destintas, (na empresa uso windows e em casa uso linux). Como funciona a instalação no windows ?
Então trabalho portatil -> USBSERVER[link]www.usbwebserver.net/

Comment: Fiz a instalação do composer para windows buscando o endereço na Raiz php.exe dentro do do USBServer.

Comment: @kall.max acho interessante você abrir uma nova pergunta para isso

Comment: Valeu decobrir como fazer a instalação.
Qualquer duvida relacionada ao codigo, volto a postar aqui.

Comment: Aberto a pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31369/doctrine-dbal-opera%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-bando-db

Answer (score 1):

<s>Se você esta querendo utilizar PDO porque é mais seguro, então pare agora.</s>

Os benefícios de usar PDO são:

- Interface orientada a objetos para se interagir com o banco de dados (em  contra ponto as funções)
- Interface unificada para se trabalhar com banco de dados (ao invés de  usar funções especificas para  cada  banco de dados, você  usa sempre as mesmas classes com o PDO)

Caso você não tenha a necessidade de interagir com mais de um tipo de banco de dados nessas classes, não  a porque mexer nelas. Tanto no PDO quanto nas  funções existem mecanismos que você vai ter que usar para escapar os valores dos campos.

FONTE: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pdo.php

O que você esta tentando implementar é um TableDataGateway([fonte 1](http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/padroes-tabledatagateway-e-tablerowgateway-teoria-e-pratica/), [fonte 2](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html)).

Existem varias implementações que você pode se basear.

Mas vamos seguir  com a sua implementação.

Um jeito é, deixe sua classe de conexão como concreta(não abstrata) e o método getDb como público.

Depois:

```
<?php

 //include classe Conexao    

class TableDataGateway
{

    protected $_table;  

    protected function getDb()
    {
        return Conexao::getDb();
    }

    public function __construct($table)
    {
        $this->_table = $table;
    }

    public function insert($data)
    {
       //implemente aqui seu código padrão para fazer insert
       $db = $this->getDb();
       //outros códigos
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
       //implemente aqui seu código padrão para fazer delete
    }

    public function update($id, $data)
    {
        //implemente aqui seu código padrão para fazer update
    }

    public  function select($where)
    {
        //implemente aqui seu código padrão para fazer update
    }
}
```

Caso você só precise do básico, instanciar um TableDataGateway('nome_da_table') deve ser o suficiente para maioria dos casos. Caso você queira atrelar mais métodos de select ou insert diferentes, você pode estender a classe.

Seria bom você pesquisar sobre autoloaders e injeção de dependencia pra deixar seu código um pouco mais moderno.

Comment: Porque parar de usar o PDO se o motivo for segurança?

Comment: Ele não está usando PDO, ele quer mudar para PDO pelo motivo de adicionar mais segurança para a aplicação, se esse for o único motivo, sinto informar que as funções tem o mesmo nível de  segurança do PDO, se você  mandar strings sem escapar, elas vão ser executadas do mesmo jeito, com ou sem PDO.

Comment: Concordando com a resposta eu coloco essa mudança como necessária, embora que ao nível de segurança imediato nada resolva como referido... Os métodos mysql_... Não serão no futuro mantidos pelo Php e daí irao se tornar "decrepated" pelo que a mudança é aconselhável... um problema de segurança a partir da versão 5.5.X.

Comment: então gostaria por motivo de usuabilidade também migrar para PDO este codigo.

Comment: Esse código é um legado, um sistema novo ou você só está fazendo por aprendizado? Seria muito interessante você reformular sua pergunta.

Comment: Acredito que a parte da segurança refira-se ao uso de prepared statements (que aliás existe também no mysqli, não só no PDO).

Comment: Isso é para um sistema novo.

Comment: o metodo getDB() pode ser chamado via parent::getDB(); normalmente, mais deixar o metodo como publico não deixaria o metodo aberto ? @ÉdipoCostaRebouças

Comment: Do jeito que você implementou já esta bom. O único problema é se você quiser usar a conexão sem uma classe de tabela. Recomendo também que você leia um pouco sobre quando usar  herança nesse link  http://www.devmedia.com.br/heranca-versus-composicao-qual-utilizar/26145.

Comment: Eu posso estar errado, mas do jeito que você implementou você vai criar uma instancia do PDO por tabela, e acredito que o seu objeto seja fazer um singleton.

Comment: Certo coloquei a forma que vc me passou dentro do meu escopo:
Vc me recomenda desta forma ou da forma que vc me passou ?

Quanto a chamada: `    protected $_table;  

    public function __construct($table)
    {
        $this->_table = $table;
    }`

Seria a contrução da minha tabela vindo do banco certo ?
@ÉdipoCostaRebouças

Comment: Eu recomendaria você fazer por injeção de  dependência, que seria simplesmente passar a instancia do PDO no construtor ou via um método setDb. O parâmetro $table seria o nome da tabela para você fazer as queries select, delete, etc...

Comment: Não estou conseguindo chamar o metodo _table fora da classe.
Por exemplo: em index.php eu faço instância a $tabela = new base();
$tabela->_table = "";//Coloco o nome da tabela do banco para ser feito a insersão dos dados.

Comment: No exemplo que  te passei ele tem que ser configurado no construtor. se você quer acessar fora  da classe, ou você deixa ele publico ou faz um metodos get/set. caso for deixar publico, mude tire o underline do nome do atributo pois isso é uma padronização para atributos não públicos.