# Doctrine DBAL operações do banco DB

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine

Pra fazer as operações de banco e melhor usar(ou qual usar): 
[Manipulação de dados](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html)

[Query-builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Pra trabalhar com a manipulação dos dados ?

e como eu faria pra fazer operações vai banco com ele
por exemplo:

```
#inserção no banco
$sql = INSERT INTO tcorrida(nome_tCorrida, classificacao_tCorrida, ref_tCorrida, meta_tCorrida) VALUES ('?, ?, ?, ?');
$pdo->bindValue(1, $nome_tCorrida); //variavel que vem do formulario
$pdo->bindValue(2, $classificacao_tCorrida);
$pdo->bindValue(3, $ref_tCorrida);
$pdo->bindValue(4, $meta_tCorrida);
$pdo->execute();

#Atualização no banco
UPDATE tcorrida SET nome_tCorrida='?',classificacao_tCorrida='?', ref_tCorrida='?',meta_tCorrida='?' WHERE id_tCorrida='?';
$pdo->bindValue(1, $nome_tCorrida); //variavel que vem do formulario
$pdo->bindValue(2, $classificacao_tCorrida);
$pdo->bindValue(3, $ref_tCorrida);
$pdo->bindValue(4, $meta_tCorrida);
$pdo->execute();

#Seleção de dados do banco
SELECT * FROM tcorrida WHERE id_tCorrida='?';
$pdo->bindValue(1, $id_tCorrida);
$pdo->execute();

#Deletar dados do banco
DELETE FROM tcorrida WHERE id_tCorrida='?';
$pdo->bindValue(1, $id_tCorrida);
$pdo->execute();
```

Estou iniciando no pacote doctrine dbal, estou lendo a documentação,
por exemplo no PDO eu faço a chamada do `$pdo->bindValues` como no exemplo acima,
no pacote doctrine como eu faria estes parâmetros ?

Comment: Eu utilizo o Query-builder caso ele não atenda ... acabo utilizando o DRM ou Manipulação de dados

Comment: Eu não entendi qual a sua dúvida, você quer saber como executar essas queries com Doctrine DBAL ?

Comment: exatamente.
Dei o exemplo acima usando PDO, como eu faço a execução com o doctrine ? Vi na documentação mais não consegui compreender direito.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o QueryBuilder para facilitar o a criação de SQLs, no seu caso ficaria assim:

SELECT

```
$tcorrida = $qb
                ->select('*')
                ->from('tcorrida', 'c')
                ->where($qb->expr()->eq('c.id_tCorrida', ':id'))
                ->setParameter('id', 1)
                ->execute()->fetch()
;
```

INSERT (disponível apenas na dev-master)

```
$result = $qb
        ->insert('tcorrida')
        ->setValue('nome_tCorrida', ':nome_tCorrida')
        ->setParameter('nome_tCorrida', 'Aqui vai o nome da corrida')
        ->execute()
;
```

UPDATE

```
$result = $qb
        ->update('tcorrida', 'c')
        ->set('nome_tCorrida', ':nome_tCorrida')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('c.id_tCorrida', ':id_tCorrida'))
        ->setParameter('nome_tCorrida', 'Outro nome')
        ->setParameter('id_tCorrida', 1)
        ->execute()
;
```

DELETE

```
$result = $qb
        ->delete('tcorrida', 'c')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('c.id_tCorrida', ':id_tCorrida'))
        ->setParameter('id_tCorrida', 1)
        ->execute()
;
```

Comment: Valeu obrigado. @Fábio Lemos Elizandro