# Forma correta de realizar um UPDATE dinâmico com PHP no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Qual a forma correta de realizar `update` dinâmico?

o grande problema é questão de ser dinâmico, se eu passar somente o primeiro parâmetro e outros não forem alterados.

Qual é a melhor forma de deixar esse update somente com o parâmetro que estou alterando sem a necessidade de passar os outros set's.

```
$sqlupdate = " UPDATE eventos ? , ? , ?   WHERE num_codigo_pk = ?";
$sth = $db->prepare($sqlupdate);
$sth->bindValue(1 ,$_POST["nome_evento"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(2 ,$_POST["cod_tipo_evento"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(3 ,$_POST["cod_municipio_evento"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(4 ,$_POST["num_codigo_pk "], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: Dá pra ver aqui no syntax highlight que seu código não compila. Falta fechar as aspas na primeira linha. Um bom [IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ide/info) vai te avisar disso... Vou publicar uma resposta só para você ver a diferença.

Comment: Se você pretende fazer dessa forma, recomendo usar ORM para a construção da QUERY.

Comment: +1 a pergunta por estar utilizando a biblioteca PDO ao invés das depreciadas funções mysql_*

Comment: Você quer saber se dados foram informados ou de *novo.nome* é igual a *antigo.nome*? Se testou minha resposta dê um feedback nela para que eu possa ajustar a resposta - editar sua pergunta pode mudar o sentido das respostas.

Comment: Eu tenho uma [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31163/crud-generico-com-pdo/31292#31292) que pode te ajudar

Comment: @Papa Charlie vou testar sua solução agora.

Comment: @Fábio Lemos Elizandro, coloca ai toda ajuda é bem-vinda

Comment: @DiegoSantos o link para minha resposta está [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31163/crud-generico-com-pdo/31292#31292) para você que já utiliza PDO é uma transição tranquila. Se trata de um mini tutorial para Doctrine DBAL, ele vai te ajudar muito a realizar updates dinâmicos

Answer (score 6):

Você somente pode indicar valores e nunca comandos SQL, oque inclui campos;
Exemplo de como você poderia fazer sua query:

```
$sqlupdate = " UPDATE eventos SET nome = ? , cod_tipo_evento = ? , cod_municipio_evento = ? WHERE num_codigo_pk = ?";
$sth = $db->prepare($sqlupdate);
$sth->bindValue(1 ,$_POST["nome_evento"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(2 ,$_POST["cod_tipo_evento"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(3 ,$_POST["cod_municipio_evento"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(4 , $_POST["num_codigo_pk "], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Recomendo ainda fazer alguma validação sobre os dandos antes de inseri-los diretamente; Por exemplo:

```
$codEvento = intval($_POST["cod_tipo_evento"]);
// Ou validar algo para ver se nao esta vazio
$nomEvento = isset($_POST["nome_evento"]) ? $_POST["nome_evento"] : '';
```

Para ter todos os campos dinamicamente:

```
$campos = array();
if (isset($_POST["nome_evento"])) {
  $campos[] = 'nome';
}

if (isset($_POST["cod_tipo_evento"])){
  $campos[] = 'cod_tipo_evento';
}


if (isset($_POST["cod_municipio_evento"])){
  $campos[] = 'cod_municipio_evento';
}

if(count($campos) == 0) {
  die('Nao foi selecionado nenhum campo para atualizar!');
}

$sql = 'UPDATE eventos SET ';
$sql .= implode(" = ?,", $campos);

$sql .= ' = ? WHERE num_codigo_pk = ?';
```

Deste modo vocẽ gera o UPDATE somente dos campos que vieram pelo POST;

Comment: Legal, entendi que bindValue só pode ser usado para valores, mas o grande problema é questão de ser dinâmico, se eu passar somente o primeiro parâmetro e outros não form alterados, qual é a melhor forma de deixar esse update somente com o parametro que estou alterando sem a necessidade de passar os outros set's.

Comment: Editei minha resposta e adicionei uma forma de deixar os campos dinamicos. Para mim está solução não é mais a ideal e eu lhe sugiro a adoção de um ORM que faz boa parte deste trabalho por você.

Answer (score 3):

*Antes de mais nada, garanta sempre a validação dos dados*. Fiz um exemplo simples que pode servir para você montar um mini ORM próprio.

Basicamente vai combinar os dados recebidos com os tipos definidos para montar a instrução SQL, combinando os dados recebidos com a tipagem: `nome = str`, `cod_tipo_evento = int`...

*QUERY*: `UPDATE table SET nome = ?, cod_tipo_evento = ?, cod_municipio_evento = ?, num_codigo_pk = ? WHERE num_codigo_pk = ?`

O loop posterior monta o *bindValue* com os tipos de cada campo e executa.

---

```
// data: valores recebidos via form
// type: definindo os tipos
$data = array( 'nome' => 'Papa' , 'cod_tipo_evento' => '1234' , 'cod_municipio_evento' => '4321' , 'num_codigo_pk' => '1' );
$type = array( PDO::PARAM_STR , PDO::PARAM_INT , PDO::PARAM_INT , PDO::PARAM_INT , PDO::PARAM_INT );

foreach( $data as $key => $val )
{
    $cols[] = "$key = ?";
    $vals[] = "$val";
}

// instrução update
$sth = $db->prepare('UPDATE `table` SET ' . implode(', ', $cols) . ' WHERE num_codigo_pk = ?');

// loop nos valores para combinar os tipos
foreach( $vals as $i => $val )
    $sth->bindValue( ($i+1) , $val , $type[$i] );

$sth->execute();
```