# Aplicação do padrão Singleton para projeto de pequeno/grande porte

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo, design-pattern, singleton

Estou  a construir classes para um projeto antigo onde utilizava apenas funções em diferentes arquivos. O objetivo é claro, criar um padrão de código reutilizável para projetos de pequena escala, com funcionalidades não muito distintas, e com a condição de poder ser melhorado/modificado futuramente sem grandes esforços.

Atualmente o projeto age como um mini-blog, que é algo realmente simples, descartei também a possibilidade de usar algum tipo de *framework*.

#### Área Pública:

- Ler conteúdo.
- Comentar.
- Reproduzir vídeo.
- Navegar entre categorias.

#### Área Administrativa:

- Editar/Remover conteúdo.
- Editar/Remover comentários.
- Adicionar/Remover/Editar administradores.
- Adicionar/Remover/Editar categorias.
- Entrar/Sair.

Acontece que sempre programei usando o estilo procedural, e nisso baseio quase toda a minha experiência em programação web, eu programo também utilizando o estilo orientado, mas não com a mesma frequência que venho desenvolvendo à maneira procedural, assim sendo, digamos que tenho pouca experiência com *POO* pelo simples facto de desconhecer boa parte das suas aplicações e dos seus problemas no mundo real.

Uma vez que tracei um esquema para essa aplicação que estou a desenvolver, concluí que não teria problema em usar o padrão **Singleton**. Acontece que até agora não encontrei um caso específico onde se afirma que este padrão pode ser usado sem problemas, uma vez que na maior parte das pesquisas, foram relatados mais **baixos** do que **altos**.

Tenho comigo esta classe de conexão:

```
class Database {
    static $_instancia,$_erro=false;
    private $_pdo,$_resultado,$_query;
    
    private function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.Padrao::get('mysql@host').';dbname='.Padrao::get('mysql@dbname').';charset='.Padrao::get('mysql@charset').';', Padrao::get('mysql@usuario'), Padrao::get('mysql@password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    // Singleton
    static function getInstance(){
        if(is_null(self::$_instancia)){
            self::$_instancia = new Database();
        }
        return self::$_instancia;
    }    
    // Select (também auxiliar às restantes acções - CRUD)
    public function query($tabela, $where){
        $campo = $where[0];
        $operador = $where[1];
        $valor = $where[2];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$tabela} WHERE {$campo} {$operador} ?";
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            if($this->_query->bindParam(1, $valor)){
                if($this->_query->execute()){
                    $this->_resultado = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    return $this;
                } else {
                    self::$_erro = $this->_query->errorInfo()[2];
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    // Resultados
    public function resultado(){
        return $this->_resultado;
    }
    // Erro na consulta
    public static function erro(){
        return self::$_erro;
    }
    
    mais métodos...
}
```

Ela possui um CRUD e a própria instância, a classe em si é complexa, editei esta que aí está e removi alguns dos métodos, ainda assim mantive nela o essencial.

À seguir tenho a classe `Config` também responsável pela maior parte das configurações, nas diversas classes, e alguns métodos úteis:

```
// Classe para configurações
class Padrao {
    static function get($path = null, $config=null){
        if(!empty($path)){
            $path = explode('@',$path);
            // Parte do ficheiro de configuração (adaptado para o exemplo)
            $array = array('mysql'=>array
('host'=>'127.0.0.1','dbname'=>'exemplo','charset'=>'utf8','usuario'=>'root','password'=>''),'outros'=>array());
            //Padrao para o caso de não serem especificados dados externos
            $config = !isset($config) && empty($config) ? $array : $config;
            foreach($path as $part){
                if(isset($config[$part])){
                    $config = $config[$part];
                }
            }
            return $config;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /*
    static function path(){...}
    ...
    */
    
}
```

No primeiro método desta classe, criei a variável `$array` como valores padrão para esse método, apenas para este exemplo, por norma elas praticamente nem existem nesse método, porque são trazidas à partir do ficheiro de configuração, onde armazeno as **constantes** e outros valores **pré-definidos**.

Por último, tenho está parte, onde crio uma instância dessa conexão, e retorno todas as entradas existentes no banco de dados, como são normalmente feitas em páginas principais.

```
$database = Database::getInstance()->query('exemplo',array('id','>','40'));

if(!Database::erro()){
    foreach($database->resultado() as $object){
    print $object->id . " - " . $object->titulo . "<br/>";
}
} else {
    echo Database::erro();
}
```

O método `erro()` foi definido como `static` porque precisei de acesso ao valor de `$_erro` pelo lado de fora dessa classe.

#### Dúvida:

Com base no tipo de projeto que pretendo construir e nas funcionalidades que pretendo para esse projeto, o padrão **Singleton** é mesmo o ideal?

Quais erros terei eu cometido ainda neste pequeno desenvolvimento?

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que não devemos usar Singleton?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/91) e [Como fazer uma conexão com banco de dados utilizando o padrão de projeto Singleton](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28244/91)

Comment: Tipo, já li estes respostas várias vezes, e neste momento preocupo-me mais com a compatibilidade, e se estarei a programar da forma correta, tendo em conta o tipo de projeto, ainda mais pelas _"críticas"_ que esse padrão recebeu.

Comment: Relaxa, use singleton onde precisar e não use onde não precisar e você ficará bem. Alguns exemplos clássicos onde você pode precisar: gerenciador de conexões de banco de dados e gerenciador de filas de mensagens.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica, de qualquer das formas já estou quase a terminar as classes gerais, não tarda estarei a renovar o _layout_. Ainda assim ficarei à espera de uma possível resposta fundamentada em exemplos práticos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## OOP

Você escolheu usar o PHP porque provavelmente está fazendo uma aplicação que não é muito complexa. [Linguagens dinâmicas não são muito adequadas para aplicações complexas](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/221615/389), com tipagem fraca fica pior. OOP também é um paradigma ótimo quando ele realmente traz vantagens reais e isto ocorre muito em aplicações complexas desenvolvidas por equipes grandes. OOP no PHP veio ajudar muito a criação dos *frameworks* hoje existentes. OOP em PHP é mais importante para a maioria dos desenvolvedores poderem consumir do que poderem criar.

Nós estamos falando de uma **linguagem de *script*** interpretada e que ficará gerando instâncias de execução em cada chamada. Estamos falando de aplicações que rodam por poucos segundos (ou menos) e morrem. São códigos que podem ser executados (ao extremo) de formas diferentes a cada execução.

Linguagens dinâmicas exigem muitos testes, em comparação com as estáticas. Quantas aplicações PHP são testadas corretamente? Estou falando de um método formal de testes. Falo de testes de unidade, no mínimo. Em geral quem escolhe PHP não quer cerimônia, não quer gastar tempo com esse tipo de coisa. Por isso, essas linguagens são chamadas de *script*. Elas não são chamadas de *enterprise languages*.

Será que criar uma classe que criará uma instância que será usada em um contexto de execução e vai morrer logo em seguida, sem precisar ser reaproveitada, é realmente necessário? Será que o jeito antigo de fazer essas coisas em PHP dando um `include` simples (que precisaria também se optar pelo jeito complexo) pegando o código básico que estabelecerá a conexão não é suficiente?

O que eu vejo é que os **desenvolvedores perderam a perspectiva do que o PHP é bom**. Talvez por marketing, talvez para não ficar pra traz, a linguagem hoje se vende como adequada para grandes projetos. E de fato eles podem ser feitos na linguagem, mas estes projetos são executados de forma fragmentada em uma forma semelhante ao que se fazia na década de 60, em *jobs* curtos.

## Singleton

[*Design patterns*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101), como o Singleton, no fundo foram criados para resolver complexidades onde elas são necessárias, não onde foram criadas artificialmente. E na maioria dos casos dos *scripts* PHP a complexidade é artificial, este parece ser o caso.

Eu fico pensando: e se você precisar ter mais de uma conexão de banco de dados? O Singleton já enroscou, certo? Aí você vai falar: "mas é algo simples, não vou precisar de mais de uma conexão". Exato. E você já [começou perceber isso com a nova pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98223/101). Não precisa de instância alguma porque vai executar rapidinho e morrer.

Eu fiz uma [pergunta sobre isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/101).

Um excelente motivo para **não** usar o Singleton (implementado certo) é poder ter mais de uma instância daquele objeto. Mas se você sabe que isso não ocorrerá (em *scripts* é quase garantido que nunca será preciso), pode usar. Se pode usar o Singleton pode usar algo estático, ou algo até mais simples que uma classe. Algo estático pode parecer que é Singleton, mas não é.

Na minha opinião o uso de OOP em *scripts* web não faz muito sentido, pelo menos não na aplicação em si. Faz menos sentido ficar complicando o que poderia ser simples.

Algumas pessoas podem dizer que usar o Singleton dificulta o teste. É um bom motivo para não utilizá-lo, mas **só se o teste for realizado**. Mesmo que seja o PHP é flexível o suficiente para permitir o teste de forma simples até mesmo sem uma classe. Deve existir, mas na prática eu nunca vi um código PHP onde a pessoa substituísse a conexão com um banco de dados por um *mock* que facilita o teste. Eu acho que nunca vi alguém fazer teste do jeito que deve ser feito em aplicações PHP. Vi em *frameworks*, só.

## *Design pattern*

*Design patterns* como os do Gang of Four são ótimos para aplicações *enterprise*, não para *scripts*. Mesmo [este site que não é tão simples, foi desenvolvido em linguagem estática (por performance e manutibilidade) mas usando técnicas de *script*, não OOP e DP](https://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/a-arquitetura-peculiar-do-stack-overflow). Ali tem engenheiros que sabem o que estão fazendo. Não estão usando soluções *enterprise* para *scripts*, como é muito comum, principalmente no mundo Java. **Esta cultura está sendo forçada no PHP**. O PHP está perdendo sua melhor característica.

**Se** vários outros erros foram cometidos (escolha errada da linguagem, do paradigma, da exclusão de testes, da metodologia de desenvolvimento, etc.) usar Singleton ou não, não fará diferença. Singleton não é tão problemático assim outras coisas são bem piores, e ele existe porque é útil. Só alguns radicais dizem que é para usar nunca. Pode usar sim.

## O projeto

Provavelmente já chegou em um ponto do desenvolvimento que não poderá mudar tudo. Mas principalmente já se convenceu que OOP é a salvação, a cura para o câncer, mesmo em PHP. Então use o padrão, ele não é o ideal para este tipo de projeto. Mas como quase todo programador de PHP acha que é não serei eu que vou dizer para não usar. O marketing irá vencer os critérios científicos, principalmente em época de *fake news* tão prevalente..

O erro cometido é fazer algo complexo em um projeto que deveria ser simples. Mas não é um erro capital, você vai se virar bem com ele.

Dito tudo isto, a implementação está errada porque ela está se responsabilizando por fazer a *query* (de forma muito limitada), o que fere o [princípio da responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101). Vai causar algum problema? Provavelmente não. O que confirma o que eu falei acima. É muita solução para pouco problema.

Embora violasse o SRP faria até algum sentido (em um *script*) encapsular a conexão na classe de configuração (que precisar ser um pouco diferente do que foi usado). Faria tanto sentido quanto não "organizar" isto tudo desta forma e fazer algo mais simples.

Mas para qualquer metodologia que se adote é preciso entender bem o que está fazendo. E quanto menos entende todos os aspectos do desenvolvimento menos deve se optar por soluções mais complexas, ainda que elas caibam. O que não é o caso de *scripts* web em sites "pequenos".

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado pela excelente explicação, e o tempo. Quando disseste _"não usar o Singleton (implementado certo)"_, dizias que é correto **re**escrever o padrão de modo a aceitar mais de uma instância ? E  quando disseste _" não poderá mudar tudo"_, é bem provável que eu me tenha explicado mal na pergunta, mas isto tudo não passa de um teste ao vivo, de modo demonstração ao vivo dos problemas pontos críticos que pode o projeto apresentar num ambiente produtivo.

Comment: _"já se convenceu que OOP é a salvação"_ - Aparentemente é outro mal entendido, talvez e já muitas vezes me viste dizer que "raramente" uso _OOP/POO_ para escrever aplicações web, mas uma coisa é saber usar a ferramenta certa para o trabalho certo _(usar uma prensa hidráulica quando se pode usar as mãos)_ que não é o que acontece aqui. Partindo do princípio, o significado base, e o uso das classes é bem claro, e falar de classes é basicamente falar de _OOP_.

Comment: Não posso dizer que discordo com uma boa parte da tua resposta, mas é também imprudente dizer que concordo, por haver demasiadas incógnitas até hoje remanescentes.

Comment: No fundo, se fores analisar a minha pergunta, ela é bem objetiva, contudo imagino que cometi alguns percalços na parte explicativa, onde pareço omitido boa parte dos meus objetivos com essa implementação, e o projeto em si.

Comment: O que eu realmente queria com a implementação deste(s) padrão(ões), era realizar testes para saber como se comportariam num ambiente produtivo nesta mesma aplicação. Isso atendendo alguns princípios de manutenibilidade para com o sistema a ser integrado. Organizar e centralizar as tarefas,**e** evidente acréscimo das funcionalidades.

Comment: Ao citar imensos pros e contras na tua resposta, em parte foi rude da minha parte, mas negar a verdade é ainda pior, e acima de tudo, não estou a ser ingrato, pelo contrário, estou realmente **agradecido** pela tua resposta. É bom saber que algumas pessoas ainda se importam.

Comment: Seria melhor permitir outras instâncias se precisasse tê-las. Tem situações que isto é necessário. Mas como eu disse no todo, isto é exagero para *scripts*. Eu acho que você está usando prensa hidráulica para fazer macarrão :) Ou OOP p/ fazer *scripts*. Mas tem um monte de gente que discorda de mim e faz o mesmo. É um erro comum as pessoas acharem que usando classes, estão usando OOP. É muito difícil você simular situações de manutenção sem estar fazer real. E é difícil experimentar em situação real. Não foi rude.

Comment: O código original é cerca de 8 vezes menor que este que estou a escrever, e é escrito de forma procedural, baseado em funções e funciona normalmente, e posso aplicar modificações sem esforço mínimo. Creio saber exatamente do que estás a falar, mas é como se fosse um mal necessário para a situação atual, se é que me entendes.

Comment: É disto que estou falando mesmo :) Se todo mundo tivesse essa percepção.

Comment: Antes de mais, "desculpa", pois a resposta foi bem fundamentada, contudo continua a não haver resposta se é que me entendes, concerteza escreveste com a melhor das intenções, mas não era o que eu esperava como resposta, para além do facto de que eu provavelmente seria o único a beneficiar dessa pergunta/resposta, infelizmente terei de fechar a pergunta.