# Existe algum padrão semelhante ao Singleton?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, singleton

É realmente frustrante, um pouco interessante talvez, mas frustrante acima de tudo, ainda ontem descobri como e porquê usar o padrão **Singleton**, e hoje, quando ia terminar uma pequena melhoria à um projecto, vi a verdadeira face do padrão. Digamos que estou um bocado perdido neste momento, por ter feito o sistema com base nesse padrão, sendo que são cerca de 10 classes, cada uma contendo uma média de 6~7 métodos, sem contar com as propriedades. Desconheço os restantes padrões pois nunca tive a chance de os experimentar e ver como funcionam, ou até onde vão.

Digamos que eu tenho este *script*:

```
# instancia para retornar todos os valores no banco de dados
$database = Database::getInstance()->get(false,array('nickname','like','',true));

# teste, para a mensagem da sessão
if(Session::exists('sucesso')):
    print Session::pop('sucesso');
    print "<br/>";
endif;

# teste, para a sessão
if(Session::exists(Config::get('session@session_name'))){
    //print Session::get(Config::get('session@session_name')) . "<br/>";
    print Hash::decode(Session::get(Config::get('session@session_name'))) . "<br/>";
}

# teste, para o login
# classe faz o uso de Database::getInstance()
$usuario = new User();
if($usuario->logado()){
    print "Logado";
} else {
    print "Logue primeiro";
}

# Iterar o objecto e imprimir os respectivos valores
if($database){
    print "<p><b>(".$database->count().") Resultados Encontrados</b></p>";
    $campo_s = Config::get('mysql_fetch@campo_s');
    $campo_n = Config::get('mysql_fetch@campo_n');
    foreach($database->results() as $key=>$object){
        print $object->$campo_s . ' - ' . $object->$campo_n. "<br/>";
    }
} else {
    print Database::error();
    print "Consulta não efetuada";
}

# teste, para a hora
print "<p>Data:\r<b>".Config::dateTime()."</b></p>";
```

Bem na primeira linha de código deste *script*, tenho uma instância da minha conexão, e nela passei também alguns parâmetros para efetuar uma consulta, por hora está tudo bem.

Algures pela metade do *script*, crio uma instância da classe `User` que por ventura, também faz uso da classe de conexão, e define parâmetros para uma busca de autenticação.

No *loop* `foreach` era suposto, eu conseguir imprimir todos os valores correspondentes à minha primeira consulta no banco de dados, mas não é o que acontece, recebo apenas 1 único resultado, que é referente ao usuário autenticado. Logo pus-me a pensar, o que estarei eu a fazer de errado, passados 35~40s apercebi-me que era do padrão que estou atualmente a usar, ou seja, se for definido uma base de operação bem no cimo, e de repente surgir outra instrução ainda no meio, o resto do bloco age de acordo com essas instruções, mesmo que isto implique reescrever a busca.

No fundo não passa de uma operação linear, onde todas as instruções são processadas em linha, como se fosse um tubo de canalização fino.

Eis o padrão, utilizado:

```
private function __construct(){

}
// Singleton initialization
public static function getInstance(){
    if(is_null(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new Database();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
    # Desta forma funciona, mas viola o principio do padrão aplicado
    # Procurar possível solução (encontrada).
    /*
    self::$_instance = new Database();
    return self::$_instance;
    */
}
```

À principio fiz testes para ver se era realmente por causa do padrão, assim sendo, comecei pelo núcleo desse padrão, onde removi a condição responsável pela criação de instâncias únicas, e fiz o seguinte:

```
self::$_instance = new Database();
return self::$_instance;
```

Passei para o teste e funcinou, logo tive que devolver o método tal e qual como estava, porque desta forma estaria a violar o padrão, e fazer *"sei lá oquê"*, que de alguma forma me tinha resolvido o problema.

Depois, veio-me a cabeça, que, por se tratarem de instruções lineares e processadas uma à uma, porquê não mover a primeira instância para o final do primeiro bloco? Então, foi o que fiz.

```
$database = Database::getInstance()->get(false,array('nickname','like','',true));
```

Movi esta instância para depois da primeira, fiz o teste e funcionou normalmente.

Posso dizer que de momento não encontrei problemas em usar o padrão neste projecto, mas o que eu realmente gostaria de saber é:

Qual é o padrão com mais semelhança com o **Singleton**, que me permita usar métodos públicos sem prévia instância?

Ou ainda, qual é o método alternativo e que pode ser facilmente implementado num projecto à metade, ou quase no fim? Tendo em conta que reescreveria apenas a instância de conexão na clase de conexão, mantendo a estrutura nos scripts ou clases que fazem o uso dela.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu não vou responder nada do início que não é muito relevante porque iria tomar muito tempo e no fundo você não vai querer a solução que tenho, mas está tudo errado. Não é um problema do padrão, é da falta dele como ele foi concebido. Isto não aconteceria se tivesse desenvolvido de forma simples usando técnicas que domina.

Não tem padrão parecido. Na verdade o mais parecido é não usar este padrão. Ou usa uma classe totalmente estática, sem precisar criar instância ou nem a classe cria, faz tudo "procedural". Ou deixa do jeito que está porque o problema é outro. Isto seria o melhor, já que começou fazer assim. Seria difícil mudar sem repensar todo o projeto.

Eu acho que você caiu na síndrome do [*design pattern*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101). O que é muito comum. Ouviu falar tanto do tal do DP que achou que tinha que usá-lo em algum lugar. Você consegue dizer alguma vantagem real para seu código obtida pelo uso dele? Seja comparado com uma classe estática, ou sem classe alguma.

Eu sinto que você só queria fazer uma viagem e teve que aprender mecânica e montar o motor para conseguir o que queria. Óbvio que as primeiras montagens vão sair erradas, quando começar montar certo vai perceber que não precisava fazer isto.

Programadores experientes - e não teimosos - aprenderam (ou por ter errado, ou por ter lido boas publicações, ou por percepção própria) que é mais fácil só fazer a viagem.

Comment: Em parte tens razão, por dizer que talvez esteja tudo errado, e que me deixei levar pelo síndrome, e por outro lado devo dizer que estás errado, porque ainda antes de começar a _melhorar/atualizar_ esse projeto eu já sabia, e ainda pus-me a pensar por qual das vias deveria prosseguir, sabendo que às vezes fazer as coisas utilizando as técnicas que melhor dominamos é melhor do que experimentar técnicas novas com que não temos prática ...

Comment: E eu simplesmente decidi implementar o padrão com o objetivo de padronizar ou parametrizar a conexão utilizando técnicas digamos _"recomendadas"_, porque deves saber também que às vezes é preferível fazer o uso de métodos testados e aprovados por uma comunidade, por já terem passado nos testes de _"pros/cons"_, mas não é isso o que se pretendia de todo, digamos que eu queria fazer uma melhoria, ao mesmo tempo que fazia testes, testes estes baseados em padrões ...

Comment: Ainda em uma das minhas perguntas eu disse que não sou provido de muito conhecimento em _POO_, por isso tento aprender as mais diversas práticas existentes para esse tipo de programação. Acima de tudo agradeço a tua construtiva e sincera resposta. Posso ver qual é a solução que tens ?

Comment: Experimentação não se faz em código que vai pra produção. Essas "recomendações" são problemáticas, porque elas não contextualizam e as pessoas acham que vale pra tudo. Então você faz uso de algo aprovado para outra coisa. Mudou uma vírgula pode não estar aprovado mais. A solução você tem que dar, a não ser que eu faça tudo por você. Na outra resposta que dei sobre o assunto eu falo mais sobre a inadequação deste tipo de solução. Mas cada um faz o que achar melhor, até porque é cada um que vai arcar com as consequências de suas escolhas.

Comment: A própria produção é um teste, é basicamente isto. Eu estou neste momento a ler a outra resposta, depois analiso melhor o conteúdo nela existente.

Comment: se puderes editar a tua resposta, deixando apenas o segundo parágrafo seria bem mais direto e gratificante.