# Padrão singleton em conexões simultânea

Tags: php, transações, singleton

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e fiz uma classe no padrão `Singleton` para conectar no banco de dados:

```
<?
    class Conexao extends PDO {

        private static $instancia;

        public function __construct($dsn, $username = "", $password = ""){
            parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
            ));
        }

        public function prepare($statement, $options = NULL){
            if (!isset($options))
                $options = array();
            $options += array(
                PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS => array('Query')
            );

            return parent::prepare($statement, $options);
        }

        public static function getInstance(){
            if (!isset(self::$instancia)){
                try{
                    self::$instancia = new Conexao("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=meu_banco",
                        "meu_usuario", "minha_senha");
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    throw new Exception("Ocorreu um erro ao conectar!<br />".$e->getMessage());
                }
            }

            return self::$instancia;
        }
    }

    class Query extends PDOStatement{
        function execute($bound_input_params = NULL): bool{
            try{
                return parent::execute($bound_input_params);
            } catch (PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception("
                    Query: ".$this->queryString."<br />
                    (".$e->getCode().") ".$e->getMessage()."<br />
                ");
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

Em um certo momento precisei fazer uma transação para garantir a execução de múltiplos `scripts`, então fiz da seguinte forma:

```
<?
    function salvar(){
        $this->validar();

        $conn = null;
        try{
            $conn = Conexao::getInstance();

            $conn->beginTransaction();

            $sql = "";
            if ($this->id == 0){
                $sql = "
                    INSERT INTO `PedidoCompra` (`idFormaPagamento`, `idFornecedor`, `dataPedido`)
                    VALUES (:idFormaPagamento, :idFornecedor, NOW())
                "; 
            } else{
                $sql = "
                    UPDATE `PedidoCompra` SET
                    `idFormaPagamento` = :idFormaPagamento, `idFornecedor` = :idFornecedor
                    WHERE `idPedidoCompra` = :id
                ";
            }

            $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
            if ($this->id != 0)
                 $query->bindValue(":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindValue(":idFormaPagamento", $this->formaPagamento->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindValue(":idFornecedor", $this->fornecedor->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();

            if ($this->id == 0)
                $this->id = $conn->lastInsertId();

            foreach($this->transacoes as $transacao){
                $transacao->setIdPedidoCompra($this->id);
                $transacao->salvar();
            }

            foreach($this->itens as $item){
                $item->setIdPedido($this->id);
                $item->salvar();
            }

            $conn->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e){
            if ($conn != null)
                $conn->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
?>
```

O padrão `Singleton` evita que eu crie diversas instâncias de um objeto, mas e se duas pessoas estiverem conectadas simultaneamente, será utilizada a mesma instância para as duas conexões?

> Minha preocupação é que eu dê um `rollBack` nos `scripts` do
>   `usuario1` e ele também afete os `scripts` do `usuario2`.

**A Dúvida**

Comment: Só vai conseguir usar `singleton` em PHP quando o script estiver em execução (ou ao menos que você tenha realizado alguma configuração diferenciada, mas por padrão é isso), no momento em que o script parar de rodar, todas as instâncias abertas são excluídas. Quando há 2 usuários no mesmo script ainda retorna 2 instâncias, uma para cada sessão.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28172/57801