# É possível usar $this com métodos estáticos?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

> Antes que se levantem questões ou críticas, sobre não ser possível fazer isto, pelo simples facto de os métodos **estáticos** não terem acesso às variáveis e métodos públicos, privados e protegidos, por serem acessíveis mesmo sem uma instância da classe, digo apenas que, isto eu já sei.

Acontece que de momento já me começa a incomodar um bocado o simples facto de ter sempre que instanciar uma nova classe usando a *"keyword"* **new** à toda hora, porque às vezes sou forçado a funcionar assim.

Vejamos, neste por exemplo:

```
<?php

class Teste {
    const EU = "<b>Disse ele:</b>\n";

    public function eu(){
        return self::EU . $this->ele();
    }
    private function ele(){
        return 'Pertenço a 3º pessoa';
    }
}

$teste = new Teste();
print $teste->eu();

?>
```

O primeiro método é apenas publico, e possui acesso tanto às propriedades e métodos públicos, privados, e protegidos da classe, sem quaisquer problemas.

À seguir temos isto:

```
class Teste1 {
    const EU = "<b>Disse ele:</b>\n";

    public static function eu(){
        return self::EU . $this->ele();
    }
    private function ele(){
        return 'Pertenço à 3º pessoa';
    }
}

print Teste1::eu();
```

O que isto vai retornar já é óbvio:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ...

Fazendo isto:

```
<?php

class Teste1 {
    static $instance;
    const EU = "<b>Disse ele:</b>\n";

    public static function get(){
        if(empty(self::$instance)):
            self::$instance = new Teste1();
        endif;
            return self::$instance; 
    }

    public static function eu(){
        return self::EU . self::$instance->ele();
    }
    private function ele(){
        return 'Pertenço à 3º pessoa';
    }
}

print Teste1::get()->eu();

?>
```

Pode-se contornar a situação, ou seja, não é propriamente contornar, uma vez que se cria uma instância utilizando a *"keyword"* `new`, mas funciona, e automatiza o resto. Os exemplos que acabei de passar talvez não expliquem ao certo o porque da minha necessidade em evitar usar o `new`, mas talvez estes dois exemplos aqui expliquem.

A única razão que me faz querer isto, é que nas minhas classes, nem todos os métodos são/devem ser acessíveis mesmo com uma instância dessa classe, por serem apenas métodos complementares/articulações à métodos estáticos que vou criando, sendo que numa classe com cerca de 10 métodos, apenas 3 deles são acessíveis, e o tipo de acesso que pretendo para esta média de 3 métodos, é acesso direto, sem qualquer instância prévia.

**1º Exemplo - O esperado:**

```
<?php

class Hash {

    static $hash;
    const COST = "$2y$10$";

    public static function hash_create($password){
        return crypt($password, $this->salt(self::COST)); # <--- $this
    }
    public static function hash_verify($password, $db_hash){
        $hash = crypt($password, $db_hash);
        return $this->are_equal($hash, $db_hash); # <--- $this
    }

    // métodos projectados apenas para uso interno
    private function random(){
        return md5(uniqid(), true);
    }
    private function fix_random($random){
        $encode = base64_encode($random);
        return str_replace("+", ".", $encode);
    }
    private function half_salt($size=null){
        $size = empty($size) ? 22 : $size;
        return substr($this->fix_random($this->random()), 0, $size);
    }
    private function salt($cost){
        return $cost.$this->half_salt();
    }
    private function are_equal($x, $y){
        if($x === $y):
            return true;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;      
    }

}

##   3º Método - PRETENDIDO (nada será executado)  ##

print Hash::hash_create('password');

print "<br/>";

$db_hash = Hash::hash_create('password');
var_dump(Hash::hash_verify('password', $db_hash)); # (null);


?>
```

**2º Exemplo - A trilha (forçado):**

```
<?php

class Hash {

    static $hash;
    const COST = "$2y$10$";

    # 1º notação
    public function create($password){
        return crypt($password, $this->salt(self::COST));
    }
    public function verify($password, $db_hash){
        $hash = crypt($password, $db_hash);
        return $this->are_equal($hash, $db_hash);
    }

    // métodos projectados apenas para uso interno
    private function random(){
        return md5(uniqid(), true);
    }
    private function fix_random($random){
        $encode = base64_encode($random);
        return str_replace("+", ".", $encode);
    }
    private function half_salt($size=null){
        $size = empty($size) ? 22 : $size;
        return substr($this->fix_random($this->random()), 0, $size);
    }
    private function salt($cost){
        return $cost.$this->half_salt();
    }
    private function are_equal($x, $y){
        if($x === $y):
            return true;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;      
    }

}

##   1º Método - NORMAL  ##
$hash = new Hash(); # <---
print $hash->create('password');

print "<br/>";

$db_hash = $hash->create('password');
var_dump($hash->verify('password', $db_hash)); # (true);


?>
```

Este acima, apesar de funcionar, faz exatamente aquilo que eu quero evitar, ainda assim é o caminho certo.

**3º Exemplo - HACK (A solução que encontrei)**

```
<?php

class Hash {

    static $hash;
    const COST = "$2y$10$";

    public static function instance(){
        if(empty(self::$hash)){
            self::$hash = $self = new Hash();
        }
        return self::$hash;
    }

    # 2º notação
    public static function hash_create($password){
        return crypt($password, self::$hash->salt(self::COST));
    }

    public static function hash_verify($password, $db_hash){
        $hash = crypt($password, $db_hash);
        return self::$hash->are_equal($hash, $db_hash);
    }

    // métodos projectados apenas para uso interno
    private function random(){
        return md5(uniqid(), true);
    }
    private function fix_random($random){
        $encode = base64_encode($random);
        return str_replace("+", ".", $encode);
    }
    private function half_salt($size=null){
        $size = empty($size) ? 22 : $size;
        return substr($this->fix_random($this->random()), 0, $size);
    }
    private function salt($cost){
        return $cost.$this->half_salt();
    }
    private function are_equal($x, $y){
        if($x === $y):
            return true;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;      
    }

}

##   2º Método - HACK  ##

print Hash::instance()->hash_create('password');

print "<br/>";

$db_hash = Hash::hash_create('password');
var_dump(Hash::hash_verify('password', $db_hash)); # (true);


?>
```

Apesar de funcionar, e basicamente dar-me o que eu quero, **hacks** não são propriamente o meu forte, e preocupo-me demasiado com as boas práticas. Uma vez adoptada essa solução, de quais males estarei eu esquecer? É realmente aceitável ? Digo, porque às vezes, ao criarmos uma solução criamos também novos problemas.

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que percebo, a operação do método `ele` está sendo uma operação comum de um método estático. Não há uma iteração real com a classe.

Então, nesses casos, você também poderia definia como `static`.

Sendo assim, você poderia acessá-la da seguinte forma:

```
class Teste {
    const EU = "<b>Disse ele:</b>\n";

    public static function eu() {
        return self::EU . static::ele();
    }
    private static function ele(){
        return 'Pertenço a 3º pessoa';
    }
}
```

O uso seria:

```
Teste::eu();
```

Também há uma maneira que é utlizada pelo framework `Laravel`, chamada `Facade`.

Veja:

```
class Usuario
{
    public funciton setNome($nome) { $this->nome = $nome; return $this; }
    public function getNome(){ return $this->nome; }
}


class UsuarioFacade{
    public static function __callStatic($method, $arguments)
    {
       return call_user_func_array(array(new Usuario, $method), $arguments);
    }

}
```

O uso seria:

```
UsuarioFacade::setNome('wallace')->getNome(); // Imprime: wallace
```

Isso geralmente se usa para facilitar o encadeamento de métodos e evitar a utilização de `new`, já que em versões anteriores ao `PHP 5.4`, não é possível instanciar e ao mesmo tempo aplicar o encadeamento.

Comment: Opa laravel :D +1

Comment: Okay, obrigado pelo retorno, mas numa primeira impressão, não é propriamente o pretendido, eu não só quero evitar o uso do **new** como também quero extinguir qualquer acesso através dele, com isso evitando  também métodos públicos.

Comment: Outra breve explicação, é que eu nunca trabalhei com _frameworks_, por isso não conheço vasta parte dos termos usados neles, posso entender o tipo de construção e métodos, mas tenho problemas com termos, farei ,aos buscas a ver se consigo clarear algumas dependências.

Comment: @Edilson, `Facade` é fachada. Algo falso. É uma classe de fachada para ter facil acesso de outra

Comment: Ah, eu ontem fiz isso, enquanto criava os exemplos, preferi não adicionar àquele por achar  irrelevante à principal situação, de qualquer das formas dispensei o uso dele por criar mais métodos, **e** pelo simples facto de criar acesso público em métodos privados e protegidos, através de **new**. Contudo o exemplo que mostraste parece ter uma abordagem diferente. Farei testes, e **agradeço a explicação**.

Answer (score 2):

O que você chama de *hack* na verdade é um padrão de projeto (*design pattern*) chamado [Singleton](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton):

> Este padrão garante a existência de apenas uma instância de uma classe, mantendo um ponto global de acesso ao seu objeto.

Nesse padrão existe um método estático público (`getInstance()` é o nome comum usado) que retorna sempre a mesma instância do objeto.

A unica coisa que faltou para o seu código atender ao padrão de projeto foi criar uns construtor privado, de forma que não é possível que o objeto seja instanciado em outro lugar fora da própria classe.

Segue um exemplo do padrão Singleton em PHP:

```php
class Singleton {
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {
    }

    public static function getInstance() { 
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) { 
            self::$instance = new self; 
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

A sintaxe usada no último bloco de código da sua pergunta é uma boa prática e está correta para esse padrão:

```php
Hash::instance()->hash_create('password');
```

---

Resposta relacionada: [Por que não devemos usar Singleton?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18863/13561)

Comment: O padrão _Singleton_, pelo que sei, permite apenas uma instância de classe. Existe ainda uma terceira segunda forma de _"passar pelo problema"_, que achei ainda mais inconveniente, por isso preferi não colocar nos exemplos. Seja, o meu objetivo não é obter uma instância única da classe, é mais _"escrever o código em linha"_ para manter as coisas no lugar, em parte pretendo restringir qualquer acesso a métodos em 3º plano.

Comment: Colocando tudo à parte, é meio irônico, dizeres - _é uma boa prática e está correta para esse padrão_ - porque ainda esta semana  desconhecia o porque do uso desse padrão, e tinha muito receio de o usar para a classe de conexão. Quanto à parte do construtor talvez tenha sido porque o real objetivo não seja obter uma única instância, contudo farei mais testes a ver  se consigo parametrizar o restante, e ficarei a espera de outras possíveis respostas/sugestões - **Obrigado pela resposta**.

Comment: E, quando eu disse **Hack**, falei isso pensando num dos possíveis significados da palavra que significa - _"melhoria rápida de um problema,  ou ainda remendo"_ - talvez devesse ter usado outra palavra para descrever a situação, mas foi a primeira coisa que me veio à cabeça.