# sealed class com construtor privado, versus static class

Tags: c#, .net, classes, característica-linguagem, construtor

Ao "estudar" a [classe `Interaction`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/blob/master/src/BehaviorsSDKManaged/Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity/Interaction.cs), verifiquei que é `sealed` e tem o construtor privado:

```
public sealed class Interaction
{
    /// <remarks>
    /// CA1053: Static holder types should not have public constructors
    /// </remarks>
    private Interaction()
    {

    }

    //Vários métodos estáticos públicos e privados
    ...
    ...
}
```

Declará-la `static` e "remover" o construtor

```
public static class Interaction
{

    //Vários métodos estáticos públicos e privados
    ...
    ...
}
```

altera em algum aspecto a forma em como ela pode ser utilizada/consumida?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A principal diferença é que a classe estática não pode ser instanciada mesmo. Uma classe normal com construtor privado apenas não deixa algum código fora da classe instanciá-la, mas ela pode ser instanciada internamente, afinal os métodos estáticos dela podem acessar esse construtor.

Isto funciona:

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var instancia = Instancia.Factory();
        WriteLine(instancia.GetType());
    }
}

public class Instancia {
    private Instancia() {}
    public static Instancia Factory() => new Instancia();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rlNPlA). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZUzuCo).  Também [coloquei no Github para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/PrivateConstructor.cs).

Essa instância interna pode ficar só internamente ou pode ser disponibilizada externamente para quem quiser usar, aí depende de como foi codificado.

É até possível chamar publicamente esse construtor privado de maneiras menos ortodoxas, com reflexão, por exemplo.

Outra diferença é que a classe normal pode ter membros não estáticos. E isso pode até fazer sentido sabendo que ela pode ser instanciada.

Só lembrando que se existir um construtor estático em qualquer uma das classes, ele será chamado em algum momento antes do seu uso. O construtor normal da classe só será chamado por código. É possível até um construtor estático da classe normal ser usado para criar uma instância interna.

Um detalhes técnico é que classes estáticas são ao mesmo tempo `sealed` e `abstract`, pode conferir isto no CIL.

## Porque preferir classe estática onde faz sentido

Se as pessoas envolvidas no código não tiverem que fazer algo maluco, a classe normal com construtor privado pode funcionar como a classe estática, mas depende de seguir a convenção. Seria bem melhor garantir isso via código. E convenhamos que se disser que ela é estática passa a mensagem correta de qual é a sua intenção.

Acredito que as pessoas usem essa técnica aqui e ali porque o C# 1 não tinha classe estática, assim como o Java. Não tem mais porque fazer isso, a não ser que tenha um bom motivo ou queira usar algum truque que consiga justificar a existência.

Esse "truque" é muito usado para criar o [Singleton](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/101).

Comment: A documentação para *CA1053*, no parágrafo [When to Suppress Warnings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182169.aspx#When%20to%20Suppress%20Warnings), diz: *"(...)The presence of the constructor suggests that the type is not a static type."*. Parece-me então que foi intencional não torná-la *static*, encontra alguma razão para isso(nesta classe em concreto)?

Comment: @ramaral não, mas pode ser exigência de algum *framework*, ou ter algum motivo que eu não vi, então posso estar enganado. Me parece que deveria ser classe estática. Não estou dizendo que é o caso, mas tem gente que lê "não use classe estática" em algum lugar e faz isso mesmo, até quando é o que deveria fazer :) Idealmente essas coisas deveriam ser comentadas. Decisões que fogem do normal é o que deve estar em comentários.

Comment: Pensei que fosse por ela ser usada no XAML. Fiz um teste com uma classe com propósito idêntico, prover uma *Attached Property*, que funcionou sendo declara *static*.

Comment: @ramaral seria bom achar uma informação autoritativa.