# Qual a vantagem de se ter uma instância única quando se usa o padrão singleton no desenvolvimento web?

Tags: php, singleton

Pesquisando um pouco mais sobre singleton achei alguns comentários a favor e contra o uso dessa abordagem.

Porém continuo na dúvida da utilidade de se instanciar uma única instância de uma classe (e fazê-la global) num cenário de desenvolvimento web, onde devería-mos carregar esse objeto entre as sessões.

Em resumo a minha pergunta seria, qual a vantagem ou o que faria um programador escolher o singleton num cenário de desenvolvimento web, já que não tem como criar objetos globais entre sessões. Uma outra abordagem seria instanciar uma classe no início da sessão e carregá-la nas variáveis globais entre as páginas.

Aqui neste cenário específico me refiro a desenvolvimento web usando php por exemplo.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/57801

Answer (score 0):

O padrão singleton ajuda a aumentar desempenho do sistema em uma aplicação web, principalmente em conexões com Banco de Dados ou fontes externas.

Ao invés de criar uma conexão cada vez com o Banco de dados, será criada uma única vez para toda instância web (enquanto não voltar para tela), reduzindo o tempo de consulta e o número de conexões.